# Move Favourite Tags above the Community Bulletin & Careers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, design

With the expansion of Community Bulletin items and Careers on SO, the Favourite Tags section in the right hand pane of the [main questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) has been pushed down the pecking order somewhat and on my display it's generally always off the page.

I use them quite heavily to aid navigation to my favourite tags. I see it as important content (might just be my opinion), but from a UI perspective, users shouldn't have to scroll to see important content.

Could we just move the Favourite Tags above the Community Bulletin like so:

[image: Screenshot]

When accessing Questions Tagged, the currently selected tag is displayed where I'm proposing, so it's not really consistent with that.

[image: Screenshot]

Favourite Tags isn't displayed at all when you're reading a question, which again I feel would aid navigation to questions I want to read/answer. If Favourite Tags could consistently be displayed above the Community Bulletin it would definitely create a smoother navigation experience.

**Feature Request Summary:**

1. Display the favourite tags consistently either above/below the community bulletin so it is visible without scrolling on every page.
2. Display the favourite tags when reading questions.

**UPDATE**

[Status Complete!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251763/move-favourite-tags-above-the-community-bulletin-careers#comment159572_251825)

Comment: Ha - this question is now on the community bulletin so it has more prominence on my screen than my favourite tags... grrrr!!

Comment: I dislike it more that the favorite tags are always seemingly placed on a different place, especially when other parts of the site (Community Bulletin, Careers) are lazily loaded.

Comment: I also dislike that I have to scroll to get to my favorite tags, because it's basically the only thing that I use to find questions that I want to answer, the homepage is basically useless to me in that regard. **However**, consider this: if the Community Bulletin were placed below the fold, I'm less likely to have noticed this very question, and participate in important matters concerning [main] in general on Meta. **Also**, who knows, maybe you'll find your perfect job listed in the Careers 2.0 box, but only if it's constantly shoved in your face so that you'll notice `:P`

Comment: @Cupcake completely agree on the use of tags to find questions you want to answer and having to scroll to see them. This would hopefully change that. Either above or below the community bulletin would remove the need to scroll.

Comment: I miss the favorite tags when you're viewing a question.

Comment: Hmm... so, is this gonna be applied to the site at some point?

Comment: @Neeku your guess is as good as mine. No mod (or SO bod) has been in touch to say if this will be looked at or disregarded.

Comment: Ah! That's a shame @Tanner. It's really annoying and more annoying is that they haven't been in touch to respond something about it...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have been half-listened: the favorite tags block is now between Community Bulletins and SO Careers :

[image]

This solution isn't bad, since tags and community bulletin are both visible at the beginning of the page (at least for me, on my little 16")

Comment: When you navigate to http://stackoverflow.com/ this is the case, with the "interesting" tab highlighted, but if you click "questions" here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions you see it's still in it's lowly position.

Comment: @Tanner favorite tags should now appear below the community bulletin (but above any ads) on all pages.

Comment: @JarrodDixon, can we also get tags to appear on individual question pages. See my question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387949/5166387).

Comment: @AAA I'll forward your request to the appropriate team!  Also, my comment all those years about "on all pages" was probably in reference to just the pages the tags currently appear on - sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @JarrodDixon, thank you so much. I appreciate your attitude. God bless you.

Answer (score 4):

Don't down vote me as not being an answer, I can't put image in comment.

It's great that SE listens to us. But better yet, why don't we have the "Favorite Tags" as drop down menu next to **Achievements**?

This will be the most efficient way to view list and go to Favorite Tags.

[image: TagsGoesHereBetter]

I am not sure how many times you guys want to jump to a different Favorite Tag when you are viewing a question, but I do a lot.

There isn't a quick way to open any other Favorite Tag (that section is not showing when you are viewing a question):
[image: FavTagNotHere]

Comment: If the problem is that it's not available when viewing a question, why not just have it show in its current position when viewing a question? Seems like that would be easier both in terms of development and usability than adding an extra dropdown to the top of the page.