# The Stack Overflow homepage is over-emphasizing bad questions (and a proposed solution)

Tags: discussion, question-quality

We [made a change](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) quite a while ago to the homepage of Stack Overflow which was well-intentioned, but I'm starting to think may have been a mistake.

The change was to switch Stack Overflow away from showing **all** recent activity to showing **a slice** of recent activity. So far so good: there's too much stuff happening to show it all (the homepage of the site was spanning all of about 3 minutes at the time), so each user gets their own personalized slice. It emphasizes your tags, so you see more of the stuff you like.

However, as part of the same change we decided to emphasize unanswered questions. You can read the exact algorithm in [the original post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) but the upshot is this: **good, answered questions fall off the homepage really fast**, if they ever show up at all.

I decided to do some informal comparisons of other sites that still use the old algorithm. Mostly I don't have any activity on those sites, so I'm seeing what a new or anonymous user would see:

```
Stack Overflow (logged in)     81% 0 score or 0 answers    19% upvoted & answered
Stack Overflow (logged out)    91%                          9%
Super User                     65%                         35%
Server Fault                   69%                         31%
Ask Ubuntu                     65%                         35%
Mathematics                    58%                         42%
Gaming                         31%                         69%
```

Significantly, on every one of those other sites I usually saw at least 3 or 4 *highly* upvoted & viewed posts, and on Stack Overflow rarely saw even 1. Here's a comparison of the top 10 questions on the logged-out Ask Ubuntu homepage vs. Stack Overflow. Ask Ubuntu has 4 top questions in the list, SO has 0 (click for bigger version):[image]

The other sites use a simple algorithm: show the most recently touched stuff. It ends up working out like this:

- Crappy questions get one pass through the homepage and fall off fairly quickly
- Good questions get multiple passes through the homepage, bumping back up every time they're edited or answered

The end result is that **Stack Overflow is highlighting the junk instead of the good posts**. It's doing it for a good reason, to try to get these questions answered, but it creates:

1. A "broken window" effect where all new users see on SO are crappy questions, which seems to justify their crappy question.
2. A reinforcement cycle, where poor questions get *more* time on the homepage because they aren't getting answered
3. An overall impression that Stack Overflow is drowning in junk.

Now, to be clear, Stack Overflow quality *is* slowly declining as the site gets bigger. The answer rate has dropped to 77% now. But Ask Ubuntu's answer rate is an even worse **67%** and you'd still come away from its homepage with an idea of why the site is good.

So here's my proposal:

1. By default, show a mix of hot & unanswered questions on the homepage, more in line with other sites (35% / 65% or so).
2. Add quick filter options to narrow down to *just unanswered* or *just hot*, for people looking only for one or the other.
3. In line with [my other proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253351/allow-users-to-optionally-filter-out-low-quality-questions), give some extra filter options for power users to control what they see.

Something like this (WARNING: UNPOLISHED MOCKUP AHEAD):

[image]

At first, this'd just be an alternative to the "interesting" tab, but when it's ready it'd replace it as the homepage.

**Obviously this doesn't really *solve* the quality problems**, but it'd at least be a start towards highlighting the better content while at the same time making it even easier to find something to answer. It's one small step, with many more to come.

Comment: Yesh, yesh! The home page algorithm is worse than flipping coins. If every question on the homepage isn't downvoted and closed, there's still work for me to do :)

Comment: I don't find questions in the home page though, I find them in tags I watch, or in the unanswered list. I'd love to be able to prioritize the unanswered list.

Comment: @Benjamin if this kind of filtering interface turns out to be useful, we can expand it to other pages. I was just trying to keep the scope of the change small so we can try it out.

Comment: @DavidFullerton Now I'm curious. Are there any statistics on the referral pages of authors of answers? How many got there from the main page?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is one of a bunch of things we're working on to improve and detect average quality.  In addition to the idea in David's linked post, we've got a group analyzing a bunch of other ideas on the question screen, smarter quality analysis, toothier q-bans, etc.

Comment: Can we please define a metric (and if necessary add collection of statistics for it) that we can measure its success by?

Comment: Can you add a "hit me with the firehose" button? I want to see it all, the stream. Right in the face. I can take it.

Comment: I cannot tell you how refreshing it is to read a post from a Stack Exchange team member that is *honest* about the current state of Stack Overflow. The denial gets old and frustrating. We appreciate all that you're doing to try and fix the problems.

Comment: @Chris: Wouldn't that just be [/questions sorted newest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest)?

Comment: I don't understand what answer rate has to do with quality. Low-quality questions have way more answers than high-quality ones. Or I fully misunderstand that sentence :). Btw, the idea is good.

Comment: Can other SE sites ask for this?

Comment: Just give me a way to filter questions BY UPDOWN/VOTE,by close point v;n rate(if a question is about to be closed,I dont want to see it),or even by users,I know some users will post always post poor quality questions,I dont want to see them.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I don't know... is it? Or is it filtered and customized to some magic algorithm? Who can tell?

Comment: Making changes for the common good but admitting they might have been mistakes is no basis for a system of government. I suggest going back to fanciful aquatic ceremonies.

Comment: No, that's the raw pipeline as it comes in, @Chris.

Comment: Is this algorithm in effect only on the main home page stackoverflow.co,m or is it also taking place when you click a specific tag, i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/my_tag? If it is only present on the the main home page, I think you might be exaggerating the effect. The flood of poop given to you on the main home page has always been useless: nobody is interested in "anything and everything somewhat programming-related". Most people likely only look at the specific tags they are interested in.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I use tags for navigation too and I asked this question to give them more prominence http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251763/move-favourite-tags-above-the-community-bulletin-careers

Comment: About your last comment: "Obviously this doesn't really solve the quality problems" - I'd argue that it *does* solve it if all the bad questions get ignored and auto-deleted. Clearly we lack the manpower to do it manually. So let the automation take over.

Comment: @Mysticial Pretty close to the lines we're thinking along. Shog9 is taking a closer look at our auto-delete criteria on the theory that the right solution might be to just pick out the good stuff, get it answered, and let the rest get autodeleted after a few weeks of no response.

Comment: What is the algorithm for determining the crappiness factor of a question, though?

Comment: I prefer the StackOverflow's current algorithm. I asked some questions on AskUbuntu, but I just don't get enough views to get an answer.

Comment: @DavidFullerton I absolutely agree with timed automatic deletation. Joel himself, I believe, wrote that you should periodically delete all bugs in your database to clean it up: **if they are important, they will come back.** The same concept is valid here as well: if the question is useful, someone will ask it eventually.

Comment: @jcz for the record, we already automatically delete stuff based on some criteria, but the final, least restrictive purge (0 score, 0 answers, low views) doesn't happen for **365 days** which seems like a really long time. We're looking at tightening that up.

Comment: I'd noticed questions with (-)downvotes were on top, probably because such questions were left unanswered, and algorithm was pushing these to the top.

Comment: @DavidFullerton Yes, I supposed it was something like that. I definitely agree that tightening the time window would aid in clearing the site up.

Comment: "A reinforcement cycle, where poor questions get more time on the homepage because they aren't getting answered" In my opinion, you need to emphasize and elaborate on this point. If only upvoted questions are shown on the homepage and are likely to get answers, users have an actual motive to write good questions. In my mind, that makes this much more than just a "small step" to improving question quality.

Answer (score 219):

I completely agree, and I would go even further.

It IS important to cater to the experts who give answers, since they (we) are the lifeblood of the site.  But nearly all the experts have logins, and most have defined interesting tags, etc.  There is no reason whatsoever for the view shown to a guest user to be optimized for finding answerable questions.  New users, or even existing users hitting the site without logging in, do so because they're looking for answers.

So show top questions by default.  Require users to login or click a tab to reach unanswered questions.  And give the user a larger free-form search field where they can type a few things about their problem and the site automatically shows links to relevant questions.  The algorithm for the "relevant" sidebar is pretty good, make that available that on the homepage.

And whatever the user types in can also be kept as a draft, until they choose to clear it and start another search.

---

But we can do even better.  For logged-in users, don't just use the interesting tags, but analyze the user's activity<sup>1</sup>.  I answer a lot of questions, so show me unanswered questions, both in tags I've marked interesting, and in ones I answer a lot but haven't bothered to mark.

For a user who has lot more questions than answers, not only is seeing unanswered questions not what *they* want, it is not what we want to do either.  [Showing them questions (in their marked or auto-detected tags) with highly voted answers will help them help themselves](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258263/does-the-broken-window-theory-apply-to-closing-questions?lq=1#comment35862_258293), because they'll get sucked into spending their free time learning their tools by reading answers to other peoples' problems, and then they're less likely to spew the same haven't-made-any-effort garbage that we complain about.

Of course, tabs should remain available for users to view the site from a perspective that goes against their typical activity.

---

<sup>1</sup> Not on each page view, that'd be way too expensive.  Doing reanalysis daily should be plenty responsive to changes in habits.

Comment: `It IS important to cater to the experts who give answers, since they (we) are the lifeblood of the site` => +1000000000; some people just do not get that.

Comment: *"For logged-in users, don't just use the interesting tags, but analyze the user's activity"* I believe that [they already do this](http://kevinmontrose.com/2013/05/22/your-future-on-stack-overflow/). Your report would look like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/103167). Mine is creepily accurate.

Comment: I particularly like that by "cater to" you mean "create out-of-the-way tools that they can choose to go to and use to get what they want". Too often (and I don't mean just on this site, in all walks of UX), "cater to" is used to mean "screw up the experience of everyone else in favour of".

Comment: @Cody Thanks for the link, quite interesting the study. And I agree with you it is a bit creepy...

Comment: @Steve: Well, the purpose is to figure out what users need what views, so they are neither out of the way nor screwing up the experience of others.

Comment: @Cody: Mine said "updated Jan".  So while it may have been something they considered/toyed with, it doesn't seem to be something they're doing.  Also, auto-selection of interesting tags was only part of what I suggested, answerer vs asker is very important too.

Comment: I don't think this is the answer @BenVoigt. Although you are right that experts should have a good experience, this isn't what the suggestion achieves. Nor do I think that you can encourage askers of crappy questions to ask better questions by showing them good ones. (As people have pointed out, those people probably don't start at the front page anyway.) The point is to 'nudge' less expert answerers away from trying to 'level up' by spoonfeeding solutions to bad questions, and more towards writing and improving useful answers to good questions (by showing them more of the latter).

Comment: @jwg: I say this is the best thing we can do *with the front page*, which is the topic of *this* discussion.  Not that it will solve *all* the problems.  If you have ideas to stop solutions to bad questions, start a discussion about those.  But don't hijack the one about the homepage.

Comment: I *am* talking about the homepage. You seem to have missed the point somewhat.

Comment: @jwg: If you meant to talk about the homepage, you failed to communicate your suggestion.  Why don't you write it up, clearly, as an answer?

Comment: Since you're the only person who has had trouble understanding my comment (so far), why don't we move this to chat instead?

Comment: @jwg: I really have no idea what your disagreement with this answer is.  You said it's not doing enough to stop solutions to bad questions, but you didn't say what would.  Are you saying my suggestion would *increase* solutions to bad questions?  Or just saying it won't be very effective at my stated purpose?  Well, whether very effective or only a little effective, it's better than any alternate use of the front page I've heard.

Comment: *"There is no reason whatsoever for the view shown to a guest user to be optimized for finding answerable questions."* Except if we want new experts to be drawn into the community.  Giving them a bunch of softball questions they can sink their teeth into will go a long way to bringing them back.  Let's not assume that new users have no interest in answering questions - or that those who aren't interested in answering questions won't be tempted to do so and thus become valuable contributors.

Comment: @AdamDavis: You still want them to read a bunch of good answers first, so they decide SO is a community worth being part of.  Afterward, finding questions to answer is as easy as clicking the "Unanswered" tab.

Comment: I like this answer but I disagree with one of your opinions. But I can see how it would be the case for many. I have more questions under my profile than answers, but I really do want good questions to come along as often as possible. It's just that I don't like writing short answers. I like to go into detail and even a bit further, and 95% of the time there are already 5 new answers by the time I've half-finished mine. So I just become unmotivated and leave, since usually more than one of those other answers are correct.

Answer (score 24):

Unregistered user come here looking for a solution. You may show categories, to let the people navigate to the topic they are looking for.
I think you need to show good answers to common problems to help the new user to find their answers.

People that are not logged in don't care too much about unanswered questions.

On the other hand, for registered users, you may show unanswered questions in their prefered topics.

Just my [two cents](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/two_cents#Noun).

Comment: I'm not sure that many unregistered users, who come here looking for solutions, are entering through the home page. They are entering through Google results, i.e. going to the question page directly.

Comment: @MrLister The stats on that are presumably collected. Are they available for mere mortals like me to view?

Comment: Even if they didn't use Google, they would use the search feature. Surely no one just *browses* for an answer to their question. This is for people looking to find questions to *answer*.

Comment: @CodyGray Shows little research :)  Who knows what people will do.  Browsing the tags/questions maybe useful if you don't know a concept/keyword to search for.  So, they may not look for a specific answer, but for general concepts/keywords that might find the answer.  In fact, many new posters often lack some concept.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to formalize an answer that @MrLister raised in one of the comments to an answer: is this really a problem?

To elaborate: Hopefully there are some statistics about what people *do* after they hit the home page. Do they then ask a question (generally indicating they are searching for an answer)? Do they log in (indicating they want to help?)? Do they look at one or more (or how many?) of the questions there (indicating what?)? Do they do something else?

My informal, totally unscientific survey (of about 3 people working with the SO site) is that the only time they go to the home page is by accident. If they're searching for answers - they come here via a Google search. If they're answering questions, they come here based on filter results notifications.

I'm not sure the home page needs changing, but I would need a better understanding of how it is actually used.

Comment: Personally, I use the home page to find questions to answer. (If I'm looking for answers, I use Google.) I like how it shows primarily questions from my favorite tags and recent activity, without having to fuss with tag filters or anything else. A question was asked a while back that is similar to your informal survey, but larger in scope: [How do active answerers find questions to answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254592)

Comment: I think it is an issue - I like to read good questions and answers to them too, so I can learn and get general community suggestions on topics. I feel like I have to give a lot more on StackOverflow, while previously I also used to learn a lot browsing at other good questions.

Answer (score 2):

From the perspective of a user, that can seem confusing because it requires understanding the difference between:

```
- recommended questions
- interesting questions
- featured questions  
- hot questions
```

What do these mean? And then there are `advanced filters`, a `textbox` for tags, more options with `recent/needs answer/hot.`

Just seems like a lot of stuff. Honestly, how many of you have clicked and used these options? I think in terms of the question list, the system should just figure it out for each user (which I imagine it's already doing). I think there should just be the time filter, the tag filter and a button or link with "advanced" and only then would all these options appear in a popup.

[image]

Answer (score -7):

**I would prefer a 'view by rating' filter that can be set by the user, so those who would like to answer the highly popular questions can get them through the filter, those who want to answer the unpopular or downvoted questions (in other words, help the novice) they can get such questions, another category which shows unvoted or netural questions, so that users can help categorize them. Another category in which one can get a mix of all types of questions...**

This system helps in the way that novice or newbies are not neglected as well as professionals will not be annoyed by questions which are not of their standard.

I would also like to say another thing.

**There should be an option for guest users to vote**. Something like a separate button or guests to vote. It can be titled 'guest votes' and display their votes. So that two types of votes exists-those by login users and those by guest users. The reason why I suggest this is that a lot of guests come to this community through Google and other searche engines. If they find the question and answer useful, they don't get the oppertunity to appreciate the answer.

And most of them will not sign up in this community just to vote (those votes are lost and those are lots of votes!!). You can observe this; there are many users with reputation about 50 ever after years of joining. That means they came for a specific purpose and then left. They came either to ask a question(probably) or answer a question.

Comment: It sounds like one of your proposed options is "find help vampires to feed" masquerading under a different name :(  Your overall concept is good, but some more thought needs to go into this to avoid enabling destructive behavior.

Comment: What about those questions long left untouched? Will they just get decayed?

Comment: @DanielCheung it once more with open eyes..."those who want to answer the unpopular or down voted questions"----I don't know whether you will upvote an unanswered question...definitly I won't.

Comment: @NidhinDavid Look, you system gathers the best voted question and the worst voted questions, which are 2 extremes. What about the questions without votes and no one knows how to solve the worst bug in a program? They could be useful, but your system will ignore them. Your system is styled like a magazine, but someone needs to answer questions, not just reading interesting ones.

Comment: @DanielCheung yes you are correct.I forgot to mention them.

Answer (score -8):

Get Google itself involved:

Stack Overflow is the premier Q&A site for programmers. However, I have to admit I access it via Google. I will skip over 1 or 2 Google ranked answers if I see a Stack Exchange answer. When Google's top answer is not on Stack Overflow, I already feel like it's going to waste my time going there.

I use a plugin to specifically kill all [Ask.com](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ask.com) and other negative-quality spam sites.

So really, I think the underlying issue is more about helping Google serve up the better answers. Duplicates help because they link to the better answers? The home page specifically does not help, because it looks like a lame Ask.com. If Google linked there it would be useless.

Can you guys cooperate with Google to improve the way they rank inside Stack Overflow? They may already do that, but it would not hurt to ask since they likely already love this site. Google linking to the highest Stack Overflow ranked page would be way better than Google linking to an inferior, but more referenced answer...

Comment: You find questions to answer by searching on Google? "Hmm, let's see, I want to answer a question about closures in C#..."

Comment: @Cody Gray, no, there is no Google search for unanswered questions. How is that germane to this answer? David Fullerton is asking for comments on how to improve the home page because he feels an old change led to an overall drop quality. This answer has nothing to do with unanswered SO questions and everything to do with integrating better with Google search, probably the main way most people search here (not the main page). Each time someone is sent to ask.com for a programmer question is a Google & SO fail. Google + SO cooperating to take votes into account is a search relevance win.

Comment: @CodyGray is right, you have missed the point. The OP's theory is that the home page led to a drop in quality, *because* of people who use that page to look for unanswered questions. Rather than seeing mainly good questions with decent answers, which they could contribute to and improve, they started seeing mainly crappy questions. This led to some good answerers answering fewer questions, and some other answerers spending a lot of time answering poor quality questions. This lowered the quality of responses on the site, and encouraged lazy questioners to post more questions.

Comment: @jwg, look I fully understand that this answer is off topic regarding the home page changes. I am adding a suggestion for the underlying problem of quality. Others have already more than handled improving the algorithm the home page uses.

Comment: If you're consciously not responding to this question, I'd suggest either posting your proposal as its own discussion (best) or finding another discussion to which it's a more direct reply.

Comment: The best way to ensure Google ranks you highly is to have the answer that is most useful to the searcher. (We *do* obviously keep an eye on anything they say helps them, or that makes them suspicious, but we generally assume that other than the most obvious stuff, our best SEO is just trying to make the system help the community provide the best, most readable answer.)

Comment: @Josh Caswell. Good point and done: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260006/can-there-be-a-quality-gain-by-closer-cooperation-with-google

Comment: Genuinely, when I want an answer in programming, **I search on Google**, mostly, useful results from StackOverflow returns, but when I search the same keywords in this site, I can **never (maybe rarely) can find them**.  **///**

I **don't see a good reason** to get Google involved in this site. **1 Search Engine VS 2 Search Engine, which is better** **///** P.S. Google: [ MyKeywords site:stackoverflow.com/ ]