# Can there be a quality gain by closer cooperation with Google

Tags: discussion

I posted an off topic idea here
[The Stack Overflow homepage is over-emphasizing bad questions (and a proposed solution)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258699/the-stack-overflow-homepage-is-over-emphasizing-bad-questions-and-a-proposed-so)

and it was suggested I move it here to its own Question.

The problem I think is similar: for a large number of users that use SO via a Google search, is there a way to tweak that process to result in better overall quality.

So the main question is, how does Google rank into SO? If it uses the SO voting system then all is well because it would value a highly rated QA pair over a low rated one. If instead it rates a poorer choice higher because it has been in existence longer / has more links to it then it is bad. We would need someone on the Google search team to actually weigh in on what the case is.

I think it would be in both SO and Google's interest to cooperate on the answers chosen. Searchers will get higher quality answers. This would have the subtle effect of exposing users to better answers as speculated in the linked topic above.

From Google's point of view it would hopefully cut down on the amount of useless links to link spammers like about or ask etc., and increase the number of programmer relevant links to SO.

Comment: I don't see this happening at any time in the near future. You're asking Google to alter their search algorithms ***just for Stack Overflow***, when their current algorithms already return pretty good results (if you know how to use Google well). The degree of collaboration between Stack Exchange and Google teams that you're asking for is far-fetched.

Comment: [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) works for Google - so it is taken care of correctly :)

Comment: @Cupcake This doesn't need to be so Stack Overflow specific. Google pulls in metadata such as ratings and activity levels from lots of sites. I wouldn't be surprised if, for example, they use average user rating as a factor in ordering results from Yelp. All of the data they need would already be available in the web page; they wouldn't need any extra support from SEI. (Although Google may be more likely to do something like this if the team suggests/endorses it to them.)

Comment: As @Jeremy Banks mentions, the goal is not SO specific stuff. It would apply equally to other worthwhile ranking sites like Yelp. I see two current problems 1) the Google results sometimes yield inferior SO answers and then you click on the Related link(s) to do better. 2) Google sometimes ranks some really crap sites above SO when your search clearly is designed to come to SO or somewhere similarly technical. Instead you end up on some "answer" spam site that gives you a list of bogus results across their crappy site with 0 relevance to programming. Sounds like Jon Skeet is on the job!