# Do newly posted questions that get a single downvote become less visible in the 'Latest questions' list?

Tags: support

I'm asking about how the system works, specifically how the 'ranking' in the latest questions listings works when a question is new.

Let's say you post a new question. Within minutes, someone is kind enough to have a look, but for some (any) reason downvotes it.

Will that cause it to be less visible after only a few minutes, so that others looking for new questions will have a much lower chance of seeing it?

Comment: Right now, negatively voted questions don't have less visibility unless they drop to -4 or lower. At that point, they fall off the homepage. But [the latest podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/podcast-59-hes-one-of-those-science-ists/) suggests that this is probably going to change in a way that votes will "buy more visibility".

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258699/the-stack-overflow-homepage-is-over-emphasizing-bad-questions-and-a-proposed-so