# Non favorite tag questions displayed in interesting tab

Tags: support

When the [interesting tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) is viewed, some questions are displayed while they do not contain one of the favorite tags. Why does this happen?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The interesting tab is based on your history and tag preference, so some questions might be there based on questions you've asked and answered, not just tags you've explicitly added to your favorites.  For example, the question pictured might be included because [you asked a question tagged HTML once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24466451/1288).

Comment: Is the algorithm public?

Comment: @bjb568 Not that I'm aware of. You can mouse over the tab to see that it's based on your history and favorite tags, which is really all I know.

Comment: @bjb568 here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258699/792066