# Automatically capitalize i

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-interface

I am not sure if I am the only person really bothered by the lowercase `i` used in place of `I` but when I am improving a post 99% of the time I can't just leave without fixing the lowercase `i`s. It takes that extra few seconds but IMHO it's worth it. If you are not bothered by it then I think you should not really notice a difference anyway if such an feature existed.

There is a [similar future-request on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105180/can-u-and-i-part-ways-with-stack-exchange) which has been declined because it requested to block the posts from coming through and force users to fix it themselfs. While I agree with [Shog's points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168294/263469) that the quality of the post is also indicated by how the post has been written and can possibly affect the score - if someone cared enough to capitalize their `i`s I don't really find anyone downvoting questions because of it. *I've also looked up comments on the Data Explorer which contained "~fix your `i`s" and haven't really found anything.*

Therefore, I would like to request a feature that automatically capitalizes `i`s if they are outside the code and quote blocks.

Comment: A lower-case `i` could be a variable name (*why is i negative?*) or the [imaginary unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit), for instance. I don't know if automatic capitalization is worth the effort and the false positives.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi maybe you have missed it so here it goes again *"feature that automatically capitalizes is if they are outside the code and quote blocks."*

Comment: The examples I provided could very well occur outside of code blocks (especially the second one). Making inline code blocks mandatory to avoid automatic capitalization does not really strike me as going in the right direction.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi the number of false positives would be really negligible compared to the number of `i have`, `i did/try/etc` I've seen in edits/questions/answers.

Comment: Oh god, @Frédéric. You're right. That is *exactly* what would happen, and it would ruin everything. Damn those inline code blocks around things that aren't code.

Comment: @Cody, yup, I still remember the flak I took last time I said inline code blocks could be used for quotes ;)

Comment: I would prefer this feature to actually need the writer to click a button, like a `Correct my answer/question` but I also understand that auto-correction already exists in many other forms, doubt even a button would be implemented.

Comment: Leaving aside the possibility of false positives etc, I still don't think anybody should spend time to implememt such a feature. I have no problem with someone who does not use _any_ capitalization in a question, as long as the question is well-researched, clear, on-topic and reasonably specific. I do however have a huge problem with questions that have none of these qualities, but use proper capitalization. SO currently has a problem with the latter questions, the former are at worst an annoyance. Please get your priorities straight.

Comment: @Jonathan, but would a user who does not care about capitalizing their "I"s really notice and use a "Correct my post" button?

Comment: What we really need is a "Correct that user" button. Man, I'd use the heck out of that.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I don't think so but possibly some people which English not being their first language might use it. As I said, auto-correction exists in many other forms.

Comment: so we don't allow the word: `problem` in the title but lowercase `i` is just fine... um I don't understand that logic

Comment: You didn't ask about disallowing the word "problem" in the title. My opinion on that is rather different than the current state of affairs… I, like the citizens of Scunthorpe, happen to believe that word filters are broken out of the gate.

Comment: @mehow there is no logic to understand. The `problem` block was implemented because too many noobs wrote extremely unspecific question titles like "I can has problem". It was a specific response to a specific situation, and it's not entirely uncontroversial either as it causes problems with edits of old questions etc. We don't have a problem with lowercase `i`s currently; and we already have low-quality filters in place that detect things like zero capitalization in posts. Simply fixing all `i`s is not improving anything of value.

Comment: Well, I don't know... but I don't see any lowercase `i`s within [this query](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+score%3A500-50000+i)

Comment: We are still waiting for [this feature](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258699/the-stack-overflow-homepage-is-over-emphasizing-bad-questions-and-a-proposed-so) with little hope for it showing up anytime soon.  As long as we have to filter ourselves, lets not get rid of such *excellent* quality indicators.  Cynical, yes, but very pragmatic.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is a ***client-side*** feature, not a server-side one. If you want automatic text correction, then you should find a browser that supports it natively or install a plug-in that does this.

That is best because it gives the user choices. They can choose not to use anything, they can choose to use something that eagerly automatically reformats their text, or they can choose to use something that simply warns them of possible errors.

I, for one, would *hate* this. I know how to type and write the English language. If I do not capitalize the letter "i", it is done intentionally.

Even if we *could* implement this client-side in JavaScript or something, and make it opt-in, it would be a very inferior clone of the many excellent spelling/grammar checkers and/or text autocorrection utilities. I see no reason why this should be a feature provided by a website. Stack Exchange should concentrate on the things that they do *better* than other people—i.e., Q&A.

Besides, the inability to master (or be attentive to) basic grammar and punctuation skills serves as an *excellent* heuristic for low-quality posts. If we automatically fixed all of these things up server-side, detecting these types of submissions would become vastly more difficult.

Comment: really? an `i` as an indication or warning for a low quality post? wow.

Comment: Yes. Not a single lowercase i, of course, but a post where there are *no* capital letters, teh iz mispelled, there is no punctuation, etc. You know the type.

Comment: Not everyone first language is English @CodyGray, that heuristic would be a poor one since I see that kind of simple errors numerous times in suggested edits. (and too many times editors forgetting to fix them)

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I'm not sure what you're trying to say. That questions with poor English shouldn't be picked up for review, or...?

Comment: @Michelle `excellent heuristic for low-quality posts. ` but I think that it would be a very poor one. A lot of people first language isn't English and those errors are common on SO.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau But why does that mean those posts shouldn't be reviewed by people who could correct those common errors, even if all questions with poor English were fundamentally good questions? (Even if you disregard the fact that, apparently, there *is* a significant overlap between poor English and poor questions.)

Comment: I'm not saying anything about reviewing them. If I see a post with that kind of errors in low-quality queue but the question/answer is actually good, I won't flag it as low-quality solely cause of that and making a heuristic flagging them as low-quality based on punctuation/capitalization is bad.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Okay, so for the questions that have poor English but are fundamentally good questions, you edit them for spelling and grammar or click "Looks good". I don't see what's inherently bad about automatically bringing them to someone's attention, though.

Comment: @Michelle It's a waste of reviewer's time. Punctuation is not a sign of low-quality. I will often not even correct the spelling, not worth the time. Looks good and move on, the real low-quality are to be dealt with.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau And how many poor questions with poor grammar, etc., do you see compared to stellar questions that have poor grammar, etc., and no other problems? Obviously it's been implemented (and described as "*excellent*") for a reason, and I'm sure the people who did so have far more in-depth knowledge about the overlap between poor English and poor questions than you do.

Comment: Plenty in the suggested edit queue for good question with poor grammar. Just one in the last 3 I reviewed in the last 5 mins.