# i think we need a way to stop u using bad spelling. what do u think?

Tags: feature-request

There are already a couple of pre-check filters on submissions regarding content and **i** think a new one would be in order.

A simple check of `\b[iu]\b` outside of the context of a code block would help improve the quality of questions.

Seeing a question where a user has typed

> i think i have done every thing i can, what do u think i should do now?

is annoying, and such a trivial thing to have to fix up to improve the state of the question.

Would a simple check on the question, and a gentle reminder regarding the use of good grammar and spelling be out of the question?

Comment: Just as long as you fix the 2,200+ instances of "bare with me" while we're talking about annoyances.

Comment: @j08691 Being a nudist is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: To solve the difficulties of working out if things have been misspelled, a post with suspected problems could go to a click-through page, where the user is given a chance to improve it. If they believe it is OK they can just confirm - and people may respond with a few more DV if it still does have problems.

Comment: Personally I'd quite like to see a trigger [on this kind of noise](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sorry+for+my+english), which I noticed recently. It's nice and polite, but like salutations and best wishes, it just creates editing work.

Answer (score 8):

The best solution that I know of: Edit and correct the question, and then leave a comment. I sometimes use a comment like this one:

> Programming is an exercise in precision since the Java compiler and JVM are strict and non-forgiving, so when asking a programming question, you will want your communication to be as clear as possible to avoid any chance for ambiguity. Also, for many here English is not their first language, and it may be hard for them to understand posts especially if they contain obscure and non-standard abbreviations. I'd say more than half the comments on this site are requests for clarification. Let's avoid these.

---

If you're looking for an automatic software-based solution, yes I can see potential problems. For example if someone is showing a variable `i` as text (not knowing about the inline code functionality) or using it as some sort of outline heading index, then the site's software could potentially mangle it, and so I don't think that it can be always done automatically. But for me **i** is the minor issue, and the other issues of misuse of grammar/spelling/usage are much more egregious, especially the over-use of improper abbreviations.

Also please look at this similar question: [Automatically capitalize i](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269300/automatically-capitalize-i).

Comment: But *why*? Can you come up with a case where this automated check would fail? If not, why don't we save everybody a lot of editing time? We know that **i** never needs to appear as a single lowercase letter by itself outside a codeblock, so why not coach users to either capitalize it, or wrap it in back-ticks?

Comment: @meagar: See edit.

Comment: @meagar What should the automatic tool have done with "We know that **i** never". Should it have capitalized "i" or enclosed it in back ticks?

Comment: No, neither. It should have stopped the submission and prompted the user to fix it. As I said: **..so why not coach users to either capitalize it, or wrap it in back-ticks?**

Comment: When the site converts markdown to html, look for all instances of "i" in the root element. These will be "i" outside of backticks, codeblocks or whatever. In every instance, everytime, this will be either un-backticked variable or bad spelling - both cases are bad formatting.

Comment: @meagar So you have been coached. What are you doing to do with that top level **i**?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I don't know what you're asking for here. Is your point  that your fragment of text has an ambiguous "i"? That's irrelevant. Real users wouldn't have that ambiguity because  they'd be typing out actual thoughts, not random fragments with no meaning. I really have no idea what argument you think you're making.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan You don't do *anything* with it. You show a warning to the user saying please check your question for formatting issues. That seems straight forward as its an easily identified issue.

Comment: The point I'm making is that there are perfectly valid uses of a freestanding "i" other than code or first person singular pronoun.

Comment: Tempting to fix the spelling of "grammer", but I figure that was deliberate, and you're just waiting for somebody to miss the joke, and actually edit it? :)

Comment: @RetoKoradi: sigh, an ironic mistake, that I should have knew would slip in there. I have to laugh or cry.... :(

Comment: @meagar "It should have stopped the submission and prompted the user to fix it" - yes, because there's absolutely no possible case in which  anybody needs to include a lowercase "i" in a post. Including cases like asking about the construction of a spell checker which fixes things like lowercase "i"s. Or pasting a mathematical formula which uses _i_ as a variable. Or talking about rendering issues with the small letter i in a design or font context (not as applicable for SO but you would intend this filter for the whole network, right?). TL;DR your idea is worse than faulty profanity filters.

Comment: @l4mpi It's not my idea, and it would be trivially easy and *more correct* to put the **i** in quotation marks, or bold it, or otherwise indicate that it is some kind of token. In the vanishingly small number of cases where its use is legitimate, I think we can handle some overhead to solve the **huge** number of posts misusing it

Comment: @meagar there's nothing to _solve_. See a lowercase i in a context where it should be capitalized? Edit the post to capitalize it. Downvote it as well if you like. But it's simply overkill to introduce a content filter for an extremely minor quality issue like this. And the fact that there are legitimate cases means you're just going to annoy everyone using it legitimately.

Answer (score 4):

Do you also have a suggestion to prevent the so-called "[scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem)"?

Examples of contexts where "i" and "u" may be valid:

- My variable i is 44, but I expect it to be 42; (could perhaps be prevented with ``, but do we really want to confuse new users that much?)
- I am trying to get a list of artists, but for the band "r u cool" it doesn't work.

Well, and so forth...

Answer (score 2):

What you talk of isn't necessarily spelling, it's grammar and laziness. As you can see from the picture there is already a built in spelling checker in the modern browser:

[image]

> When we can't even force users to correct their spelling even though it's got squiggly red underlines, should we try to force users to submit to the automated lazy grammar checker robot thingy?

No - because the users of this site are from many different cultures and backgrounds. Many of them are not native English speakers. It's a collaboratively edited site where users are paid in magical rep points and shiny badges for fixing posts. And if a post is sufficiently atrocious then you can simply down vote it and post a comment suggesting that the author should tidy it up.

**Disclaimer:** once upon a time in the distant past I also used 'i' instead of 'I'. I tried to kid myself that it was because *i'm a programmer dammit and i'll use i if i want to* but the reality was that I was just being lazy.... eventually I corrected my ways and I even fix my old posts if I ever revisit them.

Comment: "As you can see from the picture there is already a built in spelling checker" - you _are_ aware that this is a browser functionality and can be turned off, right? Mine is permanently turned off as it's highly annoying when you're regularily writing text in multiple different languages, as the spell checker only recognizes one language; and it's not too good with technical terms either.

Comment: @l4mpi You know what? Might sound dumb, but I actually didn't realize it was part of the browser - it's been a few years since I've done web dev so I assumed it was yet another js library. I'll correct my answer. Thanks :)