# Better questions appearing lately?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, triage

Has there been any recent initiative activated on the main Stack Overflow site (ie not beta) behind the scenes to improve the quality of questions that appear on the default questions page?

For example, has triage started having a concrete effect on the quality of visible questions on the Questions page?

---

**My observations that have lead me to ask this question:**

It *seems* that I am seeing a better quality of questions lately on the default Questions page - and fewer "help me with my assignment" or "give me the codez" rubbish.

Is this just my perception playing tricks on me, or is it a direct consequence of triage, some *other* Stack Overflow initiative, or is it some previously observed seasonal variation such as a time of year there are fewer students doing assignments?

---

I presume some data-guru might be able to use the query tools to compare whether the month of January featured higher voted, fewer closed, less downvoted or "better" questions than other months, or whether *this* January is particularly good or bad, or whether there is no statistically significant improvement in the quality of displayed questions - but I wouldn't know where to start!

I also don't know if the Stack Overflow data query tools are able to search in a meaningful way for the content that gets *displayed* to average users  (ie the filtered content) as opposed to the content that gets *posted* (of which some presumably is rapidly closed or hidden from view). Any enlightenment would be welcome.

---

I've only been an active member for 8 months so I have no recollection of what the Stack Overflow site was like in January last year, so I have no point of reference for whether January 2014 featured slightly better question quality than other months.

Comment: You should have been here in January last year. Every... single... question... during that month was like ambrosia delivered straight from heaven, by cherubs.

Comment: I also wasn't here in January of last year, but I haven't seen less poor posts than usual. It is mostly Java that comes up for me, and still just as many "give me code to make a triangle out of stars" questions

Comment: @Louis So you reckon any perceived improvement in Question quality at the moment is just due to fewer students in Jan, or are you being ironic?

Comment: I don't see a signal, but don't spend that much time in tags where a lot of students ask help.  They come and go, the second semester just started.

Comment: I don't see any change personally, and [php] is still full of rubbish.

Comment: I've seen a fair number of student questions in the tags I look at, but they have generally been better written, with relevant code examples, than I'm used to seeing.  Maybe you're right and the triage is working.  :-)

Comment: Wonder if it has anything to do with the work that's being done behind-the-scenes in response to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258699/the-stack-overflow-homepage-is-over-emphasizing-bad-questions-and-a-proposed-so).

Comment: [lol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)

Comment: Better questions? Wow, I must have blinked and missed **it**.

Comment: @AlexK I've seen hundreds of them in the python section. There seriously needs to be a script to question ban those users.

Answer (score 2):

There are few new students preparing for classes or finals around this time of year.

And businesses might be reorganizing their programmers after the end-of-year meeting, which leads to professionals needing help with their new jobs.

The second point may also be supported by the fact that [zombo.com](http://zombo.com/) exceeded its bandwidth limit.

Comment: These seem like reasonable assumptions, but I was hoping for more concrete evidence than mere speculation - for example if your suggestions were correct, then one might also expect there to be a quality improvement at this time of year *every year* - which might be able to be supported or discredited by looking at historical data.

Comment: I haven't noticed an improvement, but I don't check new questions much.