# Stack Overflow MechTurk Pattern Matching Engine - users to highlight key words in question to recommend duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers, recommendation-questions

### A solution for the Googily ungifted

I'd love to present statistics on how many times people went to ask a new question, typed in a title and saw the full-text search recommendation goodness and found the solution without polluting the system:

[image]

<sub>There was a great web browser plugin I used years ago that showed the suggested answers based on the title to people answering the question. Sorry, I couldn't find it; I did want to reference it.</sub>

Anyway, the idea here is for *trusted* users to highlight keywords in question content **to be used as a pattern** to bring up a list of "Answers to this type of question that have solutions".

I'm suggesting with the help of users (sick of seeing the same old questions) to build up a pattern matching system for an even more intelligent list of recommendations than the existing "Questions that may already have your answer". Based on question content (and manually done) rather than on the title.

**Pattern matching screen for duplicate questions:**

[image]

**Pattern matching screen for original/master questions:**

[image]

It  would be *awesome* if/when people in the future type out their question for Stack Overflow to run a function that scans for *patterns* in the question that have been previously asked and answered and brings up a list of solutions for OPs to check out before posting!!

[image]

I don't want to get into the politics. One idea is to change the caption of the post button to "Proof read and spell check" which scans for spelling mistakes and brings up the Stack Overflow Awesome MechTurk Matching list. Then changes the post buttons' caption to "Post your question" *with the option of confirming spelling mistakes and checking out the list of patterned matched solutions*.

[image]

I'm not trying to solve the worlds problems here. It's just an idea that's been playing out in my head a lot recently :) Discussion welcome, criticism ok, but please let’s keep it all constructive. Cheers!

Comment: Related to your last part about the _Proofread_ button: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289144/establish-a-two-stage-question-commit-process

Comment: Comment from a random commentator (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32333874/php-how-to-replace-whitespaces-in-a-string) -  Hang on, isn't that questions content the same as the duplicates Title? Perhaps if it was such a strong match, then...

Comment: Out of curiosity, are there statistics on how many people don't read _anything_ on the asking screen before hitting the post button?

Comment: Nelson Research do studies into this kind of thing and many DEV LABS have camera's for (UAT) to scan eye movements for improved usability. However for SO, the proof is in the pudding: duplicates. Plus us core 10,000 people who answer on an 95/5 ratio would know the OP had skipped past trying to help themselves. I take your point but they cant hit the post button - they have to see what comes next after proof reading (ie saving @PeterMortense a lot of time) and that there are no other similar solutions.

Comment: At the first glance seemed like a joke question.

Comment: After reading the first sentence "*I'd love to present statistics…*" I thought you were an SO employee and I'd get to read some figures. But you are asking for statistics?

Comment: @Bergi by *present statistics* this is sort of what I meant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160629/156316

Comment: Quite frankly, this is something I expect(ed) Stack Exchange to be doing automatically via machine learning. They can detect what posts get closed as duplicates of which, and *should* be able to build up patterns to automatically detect duplicates. I know they ran a [machine learning contest](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-machine-learning-contest/) a few years ago; but no results were ever published as to how it went. Either way, that contest was for the broader problem of question closure, not duplicates.

Comment: I like your thinking @Matt - maybe Microsoft Exec's will look at this thread and appreciate by making [VS IDE's debugger extensible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816556/visual-studio-extend-ide-the-exception-assistant) to use machine learning by detecting [errors like this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10004664/495455) using the new Roslyn compiler they can further monopolize the IDE Industry (their army) and open it up so anyone can add an SO answer as solution into Intellisense tips with new patterns into the solution (done in a OSS project on github as part of .Net Foundation)

Answer (score 4):

One fairly simple solution *forgetting machine learning* could be **better search**.

This is an interesting article with **[CTO Jeff Atwood talking about google dominating search](http://www.itworld.com/article/2731146/cloud-computing/stackoverflow-cto-jeff-atwood-says-google-completely-dominates-search.html)**

> StackOverflow gets 83 percent of their traffic from search engines. Google delivers 350 times more traffic than the number two search site, Yahoo.

The point is **people aren't even searching on here** *they "google it"*. Forget MechTurk or Machine Learning.

There are some interesting comments at the end of the article:

> It's not a monopoly, they are just the best search engine out there. That's it. Or they are the best in the public's eye.
>   Lord_Illidan on reddit.com
>
> Google *IS* the best. We dont use the others because they are not as good.
>   VoiceLessHeard on codinghorror.com

So then, **can SO build a better search engine than Google?**

Imagine if the SO Dev crew showed Google up with a better search and display engine!! Google is just an index page for me, its simplicity is nice but its missing a lot...

Even if the Search textbox and Tags were in a better place (ie where the non-functional title is) that would help to encourage people do research before posting and reduce duplicates:

[image]

And other simple things like:

- the googled query to be populated in the search textbox
- "tags buttons" to go into the search box (as image)
- suggested tags to include some of the advanced search tips, with tag combos (eg answer:1) that yield results like 'Solutions Only' &\or with 'Correct Answer Only' to show people how to use them
- and if search results were expandable in-page

Then I would prefer to use SO as an index page and search more on the site with better tools than google and this would help to recommend and reduce duplicates:

[image]