# Stack Overflow Mentorship Research Project

Tags: discussion, new-users, mentoring

I’m Kristina, the first (and so far, only) User Experience Researcher here at Stack Overflow. As you probably know, on SO we have a bit of a problem with our new user experience. People new to SO (or maybe even new to programming!) come to us to find an answer to a programming issue, and that means that sometimes they ask a question themselves. When they ask a question, we show them a long page of rules for how to ask a question, and then throw them into it. (In case you forget what that looks like, here it is below.)

[image: screenshot of ask a question rules]

From here, one of several things happens:

1. They are too intimidated by the wall of text (or get distracted or any number of things) and they just don’t ask it
2. They ask a question, but it’s badly formed and it gets downvoted or
   deleted or snarked at
3. They ask a question, but it’s a duplicate and gets closed right away
   (which is good for SO overall, but probably doesn’t feel great
   in-the-moment)
4. They ask an appropriately-formed question and get a useful response

What we’re working on is reducing the instances of scenarios #1-3. We’re working with Denae Ford, a CS PhD student at NCSU (you might recognize her from her wonderful research work on [gender-based barriers to Stack Overflow usage](https://blog.denaeford.me/2016/07/20/paradise-unplugged-barriers-to-stack-overflow-use/)). Our first attempt to resolve this problem and make Stack Overflow friendlier to new folks (and hopefully also write a paper about it!), is to test a lightweight mentorship program.

Here’s how we envision this test working (about a month long, starting hopefully within the next month):

1. When we see a first-time asker in the Ask a Question page, we show
   them a link to a chatroom in the sidebar
2. We have a specially-created, moderated chatroom for people from the
   Ask a Question page and for people who volunteer to mentor (there are no rep minimums for this room)
3. The mentors help with question formation, strategies for searching
   for existing questions, or with tagging. **Mentors don’t actually
   answer programming questions in chat.**

We hope that this or something like it will give new users a better first-time experience, thus increasing their likelihood of participating in the future, and generally make them better-equipped members of the Stack Overflow community. We also hope that the ratio of useful questions on the site will increase.

So, here’s what I’m asking from y’all:

- **What do you think about this idea?** We’re just starting to put this
  test together and would love your feedback and thoughts - we want to
  give it as much likelihood to succeed as we can.
- **What concerns do you have with how we’re deciding to implement this
  initially?** We’re trying to go as light on the technical requirements
  as possible, but we want to make sure we haven’t missed anything
  glaring.
- **And most importantly: are you interested in volunteering to be a
  mentor?** A project like this would never work without knowledgeable
  and experienced Stack Overflow users to actually do some mentoring. As this is
  a test, we’d probably also want to talk to you about your experience
  afterwards.

If you want to be a mentor, [sign up here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdqXGxNk9YqRcvwIIfHsPd2_sL7a8IDs_DRUoXaaz6muPMTXA/viewform?usp=sf_link).

Comment: _When we see a first-time asker in the Ask a Question page, we show them a link to a chatroom in the sidebar_ I think this link would have to stand out more, it should be placed above the title of the question, that way it's less likely someone will miss it. The problem is mainly people haven't even gone to the How To Ask page before asking a question. Great idea to fix this issue btw, I hope this works!

Comment: I think this is a good idea generally. I would also love to volunteer (although I have very limited free time). Though I have doubts regarding the amount of new users that will actually notice this link and actually click on it. On the other hand, if there will be too many users at the same time in the chat, that could become very chaotic as you won't be able to have a proper conversation with a certain new user because of tens of messages posted from other users in between.

Comment: Good idea generally. Worth trying out and seeing whether it's viable.

Comment: @KristinaLustig Brilliant - just checking. Sounds like [this request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257949/room-owners-should-be-allowed-to-accept-20-rep-users-to-talk-in-a-room) shouldn't be more than another 6-8 if a room can be completely accessible to everyone... :)

Comment: It's funny - only two days ago I thought about writing up a Meta suggestion on creating a new class of moderators, with the role of social workers where our current moderators have the role of cops - putting out fires but not having the time to help individual users much. A bit like the old [SWAT team of nice suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336264/a-swat-team-of-nice). I wasn't sure whether it would be a good idea, but in this context and equipped with special chat rooms, it *might* make sense. It also *might* be a complete disaster - but it's certainly worth trying out!

Comment: 'Mentors don’t actually answer programming questions in chat' - how long  will it take before someone attempts to get round that by expicitly asking a programming question, or by attempting to 'turn' an existing thread, (answers to the nearest 10ms, please).

Comment: Still, an attempt/trial to reduce the number of bad questions sounds good:)

Comment: Can all new posters' posts not placed under review first, then anyone can fix them and provide what changed and why, peer reviewed, or this is not an option?

Comment: I love this idea, I believe it will help to reduce low quality posts and question-bans for new users, and maybe will get to see less of those "Why is SO unwelcoming community to beginning" questions/complains on Meta

Comment: Is there going to be any tag filtering?  I could help people ask a C++ question or try and find a dupe for the, but I would be pretty limited in the help I could offer someone with PHP.

Comment: Off topic, I still think showing annotated examples of good and bad questions is *the* way to go teaching new users what works and what doesn't on Stack Overflow (To the extent that there is any rhyme and reason to what works around here and what doesn't.) Simple, understandable to ESL folks, relatively cheap to build.

Comment: Can this be extended to support translation issues as well?  I FR'd this a while ago (pre meta split?) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212385/translation-help-review-queue

Comment: @Will I wounder how that would fit with current faq, [Please do not translate posts for the OP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content/297680#297680)

Comment: @PetterFriberg I'll alter the faq. Pray I don't alter it any further.

Comment: It should be trialed. If it turns into a massive disaster, it will still have value as a shield when disgruntled users fire off  the all-too-common 'SO does not help new users' posts.  We can link it and say 'we tried harder, and it just didn't work'.

Comment: @Will you bald-headed .... :D, but ok, lets keep a 24/7 translation service

Comment: How will you determine success/failure? Are you prepared to let it die if it does fail?

Comment: @PaulCrovella Oh, yes. We're killing it after about a month in any case - it's meant to be a short-term experiment where we gather data about the kinds of things people need help with, the way that people interact with each other in this setting, and how much getting personal help with asking a question actually helps people feel more welcome. So there really is no success/failure criteria here, because knowledge gained is a success - even if we learn that this is a horrible idea. :)

Comment: A really good idea, worth a try. Signed up.

Comment: @PaulCrovella eww... the horrible chat flags.  Didn't think of that!

Comment: @NathanOliver ideally, you don't need the knownledge to ask a good question. Ideally, you could identify obvious pitfalls for most questions (topicness, clarity, opionated).

Comment: When you say that "there are no rep minimums for this room", that just applies to the new members asking for help to get their question in shape, right? Surely the _mentors_ need site experience, and probably also domain-specific experience too. I suggest that mentors should have _at least_ a bronze badge in some language tag.

Comment: @PM2Ring yup - just for new members. Mentors do need experience with SO.

Comment: @KristinaLustig Excellent! I am much relieved. :)

Comment: @KristinaLustig IMHO this idea has a lot more promise https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303964/stack-overflow-mechturk-pattern-matching-engine-users-to-highlight-key-words-i/

Comment: The form asks for my username. Should I put in my display name or the e-mail address with which I sign in?

Comment: How about connecting every new asker with a single volunteer?

Comment: Let the first time user type the question and allow mentors to see what is being typed and allow them to make suggestions on how to improve the question. Mentors could be replaced by AI because this will be a kind of horrible job but I think it is the only way that allows the first time user to ask a question without being redirected and being forced to read walls of text. I will not be such a mentor, I have got a job and things to do. The stack overflow questions of late are more at a please-help-me-debug or please-write-my-code level than aiming for fundamental understanding. I miss that.

Comment: (1/2) I know there are mixed feelings here about this. I'm wondering if, regardless of the success of the test on Stack Overflow, variants of this could be tested on smaller sites on the network - not the tiniest beta sites, but ones with a decent amount of questions and plenty of new users. It would be especially helpful on sites that have problems on specific types of questions (e.g. homework, ID questions, resource recommendations, etc.). I've spoken with a few mods on a couple other sites, and they think it might be worth a shot.

Comment: (2/2) The same technical problems would be present, as well as some of the others mention here, but you might see less help vampirism, because I'd bet that a small percentage of new users there are looking for a quick fix to a problem. Most sites have communities smaller than SO, but it can still be intimidating to join them. Using a mentoring program there could lower this barrier and increase question quality in different crucial areas on different sites.

Comment: what about moderators forming 'mentorship' groups in general? so whenever a new user creates an account on SO they are shown a list of mentors for the group the new user falls in (0 - 100 experience, 100 - 200 experience, etc). this would make 'mentors' a more friendly concept. These mentors would do what you suggest

Comment: Your google docs link appears to be down at the moment. Could be the firewall I'm behind of course.

Comment: I think it's a great idea and would love to be a mentor. At the same time, I think most SO users would prefer it if you instead researched ways to make new users' computers shock them with electricity for being lazy when writing questions.

Comment: @KristinaLustig  Quick reality check.  How many new SO users per day?  How many questions from beginning users per day?

Comment: @empty you should not try to inject reality into this experiment at this stage.  The vamps will do that later:)

Comment: Many users are ready to help new users but that is impossible since new users ask a question and leave. Make them stay put for a few minutes and the comments to help them will come: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156761/add-a-hint-to-stay-put-after-posting-a-question

Comment: Amazing Idea. I know so many programmers that were turned off from the trolling and bias against first timers

Comment: @juergend I respectfully disagree, new users stay for their question, but don't ask again after the bias and disgusting behavior towards their first question.

Comment: @Hack-R Based on what you said, I hope your not a mentor :). But in all seriousness, new users mean know harm, its just they need a answer to a question fast. I think teaching them through mentorship is great.

Comment: @SteelToe: That happens too, but  my experience tells me that 80 percent of the users leave. And I view(ed) a lot of questions.

Comment: @juergend I agree with that part, I just disagree that even if you make them stay for the comments, they still will leave when they see their question being treated like garbage etc

Comment: @Hack-R just my observation.

Comment: @SteelToe 'new users mean know harm, its just they need a answer to a question fast.'  That's exactly the approach that gets them down and close-voted:(

Comment: @SteelToe 'I know so many programmers that were turned off from the trolling and bias against first timers' do you have any evidence of trolling and bias against first timers, as distinct from bias against bad questions? No, you don't.  How do I know?  I have asked for evidence in many meta posts that claim thsi happens, and not one link has ever been posted.  Now who is trolling, exactly?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I cannot access the Google Docs (from work) either.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing where it was noted, somewhere on this page, but will the expectation/implementation be that a user posts their question, and then gets advice on what to improve, if they use the mentoring process? Or, are they expected to provide their question content in the chat itself (which would be awful, given how chat handles code blocks)? Or some other option that I've missed the few times I've read through this question and it's answers?

Comment: @KristinaLustig, [a] _Where can I download this program?_ [b] _Where can I find a tutorial?_ [c] _Which program is the best?_ All those are **off-topic** questions, and the Mentors will be telling the newcomers **"don't post this question here!"**, and they will be asking **"so where do I ask my question then?"**

Comment: @Cœur in the " How to ask in the 'How to ask' room "  chatroom, of course, (sorry, could not resist that).  It's chatrooms all the way down:)

Comment: Personally I don't think this will work, for a bunch of reasons, which others have posted. I've made [some](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting) [suggestions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly) in the past that aim to act more interactively with users that are new.

Comment: @Pekka웃 something like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly) referring to [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353845/stack-overflow-mentorship-research-project#comment497234_353845) of yours.

Comment: If you want to create a mentor system, you _need_ a way to create a 1-on-1 chat room for the mentor and the mentee to discuss the question.

Comment: Am I wrong for thinking that the most question refining structure already exists. Specifically, the fact that more than 3/4 of all poorly formatted questions are almost instantly mediated with a critique in the comments sections. "Please show desired output," "what have you tried?", etc. Dedicated askers simply edit their question and, from what I see, get results. Mentor yes, no to a new structure within the site that teaches requisite question formatting techniques.

Comment: @Kristina Lustig: Down-voting is also one of the thing that puts people off answering or raising a question. I guess you will have to dig into the huge data of SO and then come up with statistics such as what are the types of questions people ask or answer, understand the frustration shown in the comments etc. It will be a good data mining problem. You will be able to come up with lots of answer to improve SO. I still think my answer is good, which because of downvoting, I guess nobody reads it.

Comment: *"One thing is sure. We have to do something. We have to do the best we know how at the moment... If it doesn't turn out right, we can modify it as we go along."* (FDR) I do agree with the concerns voiced in comments / answers, but at least SO is trying to something to address poor new user experience. So, let's do this, but be ready to move on if it does not work.

Comment: The curent way of doing things culls the lazy and the help vampires. Your proposal would instead bring them in.

Comment: I believe a friendly explanatory short video will resolve all 3 problems.

Comment: I loath chat.  If that was my first experience here, I would have left immediately.  I have no idea how common or rare my feelings are on this matter, but please consider that one size does not fit all.

Comment: I'm skeptical about the true usefulness, but I'd be willing to try it out.

Comment: Sounds great if actually implemented well. Exactly what would new users be asking in this chat? Why not just add a "your first couple questions will be peer-reviewed for quality" feature and have these altruistic people that would be sitting in a chat room instead monitor this new queue?

Comment: I would much rather see the 'mentorship efforts' directed at helping people improve their questions. So the idea is to let users post their first question as best ad they can and then have a mentor offer to help the user to improve the question. That reduces friction and encourages new users while also hopefully teaching them the skills they need to ask better questions in the future.

Comment: Linkedin beat you to the punch!  https://twitter.com/modestproposal1/status/893466881578979328

Comment: I have an idea: let's just show newcomers an overwhelmingly large list of down-voted and up-voted questions side by side to encourage them to write quality questions! — Jokes aside, a few example questions (actual or artificial) might help!

Comment: A long time ago, in a ga... No, wait, it was this Galaxy... Anyway, there was a community known as "CyberArmy" (not sure if it still exists) where you had to perform a series of tests which gave you your "rank" in the community. Now the thing was the very first test was *fun*. Do you think we could make a *fun* interactive test to help them find an existing answer, or write a Question? Gamification is a great tool to validate and encourage learning.

Comment: Okay. So this is really late and an insanely bad idea (and probably really impractical too), but: I'd have a chat open as like a sidebar on the post body once the user clicks the button to post a question (even better would be once the question reaches a decent length), and a mentor would be able to see a live preview (or at least a preview :P), which I *think* would make it a bit more interactive. (Yes this is a lot like Servy's answer)

Comment: Okay, I've read a few of these answers, and it seems like the most important part isn't mentoring, it's SmokeDetector integration. I'm sure with Stack Exchange's help (and computing power) it would be possible to use the data on all the deleted/closed etc. questions to modify SmokeDetector to warn users of bad questions *before they are even asked*, and give them an overview of the points where they need to improve

Comment: Not sure why I'm still using comments :/ I think quite a few people use Stack Overflow for rubber duck debugging, and I think this would be a big help to a majority of the users posting the bad questions described below. I think as a sort of tutorial the process of asking a question could be broken up? e.g. each of the multiple inputs would be used for part of the question e.g. a short description, what they've tried, and code (if any). I'd also say to ask the users to Google/DDG etc. the question (which I think would solve the problem in most cases) but it doesn't seem possible to automate

Comment: So yeah, I'd personally prefer a kind of error message based on SmokeDetector-esque analytics.

Comment: How about creating a good quality `Markdown Basics + Writing Good SO Questions 101` video. It's amazing the improvement in quality of questions and answers once you know `backticks`, [links](https://www.stackoverflow.com), and    code blocks

Comment: _What do you think about this idea?_ I like it

Answer (score 257):

I don't believe this is a good idea.

The main reason to me is that a new user will see a chat room and ask his question there. Then people in there will have to explain to him/her that they are not here to answer his/her question, but to help him/her ask the first question properly...

If he/she has the time it takes to ask a proper question, fine. Maybe he'll accept to be mentored that way. But I honestly do not think it will be the case for most users.

**How do modern video games get new users into action as quickly as possible?** With an undercovered tutorial. The first missions are the tutorials, but the story has started already, and information comes byte by byte, not all at once.

So why not do so here? [Cody Gray started a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page) and I liked [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327082/5897829).

The main idea is to guide the users step by step. A chat room will not solve the basic problem that a user has an immediate need of help and will find the fastest possible way to get help, even if it doesn't cope with the standards in place. Because he/she (wrongly) assumes that reading the whole tutorial to ask just one question is a loss of time.

So ask him, question by question, what is his problem. Then you can direct him easily towards a new question that can be asked, a question that already exists or a chat room that would help him solve his problem.

From some comments I receive for this answer, a new idea just came out. That if you want to aim at some undercover tutorial, make this chat-room, then make it monitored by learning bots. At the beginning they will need help from real mentors, but I'm pretty sure after a while they will be able to help 90% of the new users...

Comment: Yeah, this is a really interesting idea. We're starting this project on the assumption that throwing users a huge wall of text and expecting them to read that, process it, and use it, is inherently a flawed way of introducing them to a new platform. A step-by-step wizard-like solution - what you're describing - is another potential way of doing it. We decided to first try a kind of "get only the support that you need from other real humans" approach, but it definitely might be the wrong one. In that case, we'll go back to the drawing board, and the option you've presented is a solid alternate.

Comment: One reason I really like this is that it's an experiment. Even if it doesn't work how it's expected to, we'll gain a better understanding of the types of questions and thoughts that new users struggle with. If we were to build an undercover tutorial in the future, this would be a low-cost way to research what should go into it, and what are all the human nuances of helping people get acclimated to this community.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers You can get *that* by looking at the times people post on meta asking for help crafting a question.  It's similar enough to this feature, except most people aren't told they can do it, and like this proposed feature, won't possibly scale up if it *is* used by a sizable portion of those that would benefit from using it.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is the way this is pitched is that it isn't a proposed feature, but an experiment. It's OK if experiments fail or succeed, b/c they give valuable qualitative data either way. I also like the idea of the tutorial. It's totally possible the best solution is both or even something that hasn't been fully considered yet.

Comment: @KristinaLustig 'throwing users a huge wall of text and expecting them to read that, process it, and use it, is inherently a flawed way of introducing them to a new platform' in general, I tend to agree.  In the case of software development, however, is should be noted that reading, processing and using whole user manuals of text is just an project norm, and therefore it's not unreasonable to expect professional and/or enthusiast programmers to be able to handle one page of advice and follow a few links.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers as an experiment to acquire data, I can see the value of, at least, trying..   OK, I've decided, I'm upvoting the proposal:)

Comment: @MartinJames unfortunately I must disagree. People tend to read less and go straight to (what they believe is) the point. This is sad but true in every domain. With the ease now to build a small application from a short video tutorial (thinking about IoT), why would some people bother reading ? How many people have read MSDN docs for building a winforms ? Just add a button, double click on it and you can make some stuff...

Comment: @MartinVerjans yes, but then they have to fill in the event-handlers with 'real' code, and when it behaves badly, then will need MSDN.

Comment: @MartinJames "reading, processing and using whole user manuals of text is just an project norm" This is also a learned skill which most new users have not learned yet. (Otherwise they would not be "new".)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice well, new users of SO should be professional/enthusiastic programmers.  They will have seen some documentation before.

Comment: @MartinJames I do not think that is a safe assumption. Even as a highly motivated beginner programmer, I had seen no technical documentation before my first day in a college level class. I gradually learned how to read docs over my entire college experience as a CS major. There are also many students in CS classes who are taking it as a "general elective" or as an alternative to a math requirement. These types of students are neither professional nor enthusaists. They just want to get a decent grade. These are the kinds of "new SO users" who I see this experiment targeting.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice OK, then I hope that the targeting is accurate:)   Students, (well, at least the consciencious ones), are another class(!) whom I would expect to understand the value of documentation.

Comment: @MartinJames Even these idealized students who understand the value of documentation may not have the skills to find what they need for their current programming problem nor to apply what they read to it. This is a learned skill just as much as learning syntax.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice "There are also many students in CS classes who are taking it as a 'general elective' or as an alternative to a math requirement." Then, as you say yourself in your next sentence, they "are neither professional nor enthusaists", and they have no business posting here. This site [is explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for people who are [serious about programming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlWnl.jpg).

Comment: @JoshCaswell The very first sentence on that page is "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional ***and enthusiast*** programmers." I think limiting participation here to only "professional" or "serious" programmers would seriously degrade the value of this site. There's already a fair belief that "new" or "casual" questioners aren't welcome here. And sadly, that belief is way too often reinforced by people who seem to have forgotten what it's like to be in a position to need to ask a question.

Comment: @Shawn: _"The very first sentence on that page is 'Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional **and enthusiast**...'"_ Uh huh, and [that's what we're talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yKVa.png).

Comment: @JoshCaswell I strongly disagree that casual students of our art have no place here. Some of those casual students can potentially decide to switch careers, or not, based on there interactions with professionals and enthusiasts.

Comment: If they're actually _students of the art_, then I'm happy to consider them under the "enthusiast" rubric. It's the "They just want to get a decent grade." that I object to. (I wasn't a professional when I started using the site.)

Comment: The very definition of "want to get a decent grade" makes them "students of the art" who will likely eventually become "professionals", or at the very least "enthusiasts". I also object to people trying to answer homework on SO, but the extreme negativity that some of these people are shown pretty well guarantees that when they do have something positive to contribute to others, they won't be doing it on SO. That's where mentors could be helpful. Many of these people don't ask questions to be jerks, they do so because this is a Q&A site. They may not know they shouldn't ask those questions.

Comment: Anyone who has a question should be more than welcome here. And if they don't know how to ask, then they should be helped to do so correctly.

Comment: @Shawn Ok, we disagree, but that's fine:)  I'm surprised by your view, however, and have only admiration for anyone who would take that burden on.  How may we direct those questions that are outside the class of 'professional and enthusiast'  to yourself so that you can provide the help?  Do you want links emailed to you directly, or are you going to set up your own site?

Comment: For some background, before I was a coder, I was a flight instructor. I was an educator in technical field. I take the view that the only bad question is the one not asked. People don't learn if they can't get good information, and new people have plenty of questions that seem trivial to more experienced people. The same holds true for asking a question here. A new user is usually primarily concerned with getting an answer, so may ask an improper question. It's up to these proposed mentors to help them use this site properly. I've always thought SO was supposed to be a place to come to ...

Comment: ... get answers. If it's only meant for smart people to talk to other smart people, it's not what I thought it's been. I don't think that's what it was initially created for. The primary focus should not be high quality answers (though it should still be a focus). We should primarily be focused on helping people learn what they come here to learn.

Comment: That said, for the people who do come here just trying to get a quick answer and don't have any urge to use the site properly or who are unwilling to learn to do so, then no, I don't think their questions have a place here nor do they deserve to have other people help to answer them.

Comment: The site is about smart people asking questions and, hopefully, getting good answers.  It depends on your definition of 'smart'.  I like to think of the 'smart' askers as those who provide as much info in their questions as they reasonably can:inputs, outputs, error-messages, how testing was done, what was found during debugging.  I think that 'smart' answerers are street-smart as well as skilled and experienced in software development, and recognise when they are being abused by those who will not help the helpers by making some effort first.

Comment: _"The primary focus should not be high quality answers"_ That absolutely has been, and continues to be, the primary focus. [Optimizing for Pearls, Not Sand](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/). The vast majority of this site's traffic, and usefulness (to _everyone_, no matter their skill), comes from Googling, and the reason for that is that the **answers** are high quality. We already have forums for pages of back-and-forth working out what the problem is before getting to a solution. When you come to SO, you should get a solution, the end.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Full version of my statement is "The primary focus should not be high quality answers ***(though it should still be a focus)***. _We should primarily be focused on helping people learn what they come here to learn._" Now, it's hard to argue with Jeff Atwood about what SO should be, but I don't really think my statement disagrees with him. Yes, we should have good Answers, but those good Answerers _will_ be sitting around twiddling their thumbs if Questioners deem SO as hostile and choose to learn elsewhere.

Comment: @MartinJames I think we're talking around each other. Not many new users will know how to ask a smart question if they aren't shown what a smart question looks like. Neither a Student nor a Teacher can do what they need to do without the other. And someone trying to explain the difference between null and an empty string will see a lot less enlightenment from me than from a new developer. That's not a question I would ask, but is still a question with some value to someone.

Comment: here's my version of the [turorial](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly) based no the audit review system.

Comment: I have a feeling the experiment - as outlined in the question - is inevitably going to fail in the manner described above. There's no point in wasting resources on an experiment that you can reasonably predict the outcome of.

Comment: I think it's a great idea. SO doesn't do the best job of explaining how to interact with it for new users, consequently new users are often a target of what feels to them like pretty intense abuse for not following 'rules' they don't know about or don't really understand.

Comment: @AgentZebra I think that statement hits the nail right on the head. Way too many "smart" users run people off before they even get a chance to become better users.

Comment: 'Way too many "smart" users run people off'.. do you have any evidence of that, (as distinct from users closing bad questions irrespective of the status of the poster)?  No, you don't, because it doesn't happen often enough to notice.  Anyway, I have upvoted this proposal and, if it goes ahead, we will see what happens with the new users who turn up in the room...

Comment: @MartinJames I certainly noticed :D I've seen it with others too. I always give them an extra like just because :) empathy rocks.

Comment: @AgentZebra empathy may rock, but compilers/linkers don't understand that:)

Comment: @MartinJames With the advent of AI, it's imperative they start to :)

Comment: @AgentZebra I hope it happens.  Maybe then they will realize that it's just annoying to issue three pages of error-messages for one missing semicolon:)

Answer (score 143):

> What concerns do you have with how we’re deciding to implement this initially?

Even though you explicitly mention that the mentors won't be answering programming questions, the biggest concern I see is that new users coming for help will see these volunteer users as people to directly answer their questions, not provide guidance on how to ask. This may be compounded when you have multiple new users in a [single chatroom](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353845/stack-overflow-mentorship-research-project#comment497176_353846) with multiple volunteers, since you'll have the potential for a lot of noise and crosstalk in the room itself.

Other than a written description of the role of these volunteers, do you have any other plans on how to enforce this idea? Are there any ideas on preemptively protecting the chat room from turning into a "can you answer my question?" chatroom, and protecting the volunteers from getting harassed into answering the question either directly in chat or under the final question?

Or are you going to wait and see if this scenario becomes a real problem?

Comment: Hey - you make a good point. Right now our plan is to make it very clear in the chat and with the mentors that this isn't for answering programming questions, it's for help with creating them (for a lot of reasons, including the greater good!). If we see this becoming a problem right away, there are a few avenues we have: continue as-is (with reinforcement of the rules), more active moderation by people from SO (like me!), or, if it's very bad, we might have to pause the program to think of a different implementation. I hope it doesn't come to that, but the only way to find out is to try.

Comment: Evidence supporting the concern - my [blog post on asking good questions](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) starts (after a tinyurl) with "Please note: this blog post is not a suitable place to post a development question." I very regularly get comments asking questions. Some people just won't read what's in front of them...

Comment: @JonSkeet at first I read "I very rarely get comments [...]" And was very confused. How difficult would it be to check, automatically, if a comment is a question? SE has some things that do it (the word "problem" can't be in the title), but they are not generic/dynamic. They're hard-coded. It'd be interesting to explore automated answer demands from new users.

Comment: @ItamarG3: Given that this is mentoring *about* a question, it would be reasonable to be quoting bits from the question within the chat, I'd say.

Comment: @JonSkeet true. But it might be worth investing time in a system that can detect repetitions of "so what's the answer to my question" and variations. It might also be good to see if a user is cooperative. If they're not, them that's the end of it: they shouldn't be mentored (not that they can't, but they shouldn't be. The latter often implies the former). (I'm slightly freaking out in the good way because Jon Skeet is answering my comment #.#)

Comment: @ItamarG3: I suspect it's the kind of thing that's most easily written after we've seen what actually happens, but it would probably be worth the SO team thinking about *possibilities* beforehand, yes. And yes, uncooperative users are very annoying. (The number of people who've flatly told me that a code sample is complete, despite only consisting of a method on its own...)

Comment: @KristinaLustig Waiting for it to become a problem is simply going to de-incentivize people willing to help. We *know* it's going to be a problem, based on the rest of the site. This will only succeed if mentors are not driven away. There's already a huge amount of rubbish to wade through on the main site, let's not create another avenue of it. Why not liberally provide mentors with the ability to delete messages and/or timeout users - optionally with a popup explaining *why* the action was performed?

Comment: Totally agree with this, it was my first though as I have seen it happen in plenty of channels across the web for a variety of reasons - poor understanding of the language used to describe the channels purpose being a large one, often (but not always) due to being non-English speaking. Liberal controls for mentors, with automatic notification of reason for deletion (rather than an implied "you're not good enough") would be a baseline requirement IMO.

Answer (score 94):

So if someone is using this feature to get help improving their draft of a question, how are they intended to share that draft with the mentors? It's important that they *do* share the draft, so the mentors can see what they have so far and what they're missing or need to fix, but I can't imagine that putting the entire draft question in chat is possible/feasible. They're going to need some place to put the question and link to it in chat.

If this is rolled out just as described I suspect this is going to result in lots of people asking a question and then linking their existing questions in the chatroom, but at that point it's no longer serving its purpose, as the question will be getting downvotes/close votes/critique as appropriate, which is the thing this is trying to avoid.  If people start hosting their drafts off site then mentors end up needing to click tons of possibly shady links to do their job, and moderators would need to let people constantly be posting links all over the place, providing tons of camouflage for spam or trolling (particularly given that there isn't going to be any rep requirement here).

If rolled out just as described it's also going to result in lots of people not providing enough information about the question they're considering asking to even get help crafting their question.  If people start having problems just figuring out how to get help figuring out how to ask their actual question, well, if you think the *current* new user experience can leave a bad taste in people's mouth...

So for this to work you'd more or less need some way of letting people post their questions, but in a state where it doesn't show up in the question list/search/review queues/user profile, cannot be answered/voted on/closed (probably still want it to be editable and have comments enabled though), and could then be linked to in chat, and with the author having the ability to finalize it as a real question when they felt ready.  Is this a feature you're planning to roll out with this?

Comment: Maybe some kind of "draft" status for questions? This would allow sharing of the question, but not full "question" status. Might not be a bad feature/solution overall, if users, say with >100 or >250 rep could 'approve' new questions, but they could all be seen, while allowing browsers/searchers to excl\ude 'drafts' from their browsing?

Comment: @toonarmycaptain See the last paragraph of the answer...

Comment: I saw - I'm just saying it could be put with the varioius 'normal, flagged, on hold, etc statuses, and optionally included in the question list, which would draw the rest of the SO community beyond those mentors into helping handle them.

Comment: The only feasible solution during this research stage probably would be to *force* OP to have a github account, *wondering how many perfect OP we will have that post on github, listen to suggestion, improve question and then post on SO*, but ok anything for science.

Comment: I'd really like to have a sharable draft feature similar to what we have on Docs. Not being able to share draft posts really is a problem if this becomes a long-term solution. For the actual research effort, I think it won't hurt much to have people post their questions and ask mentors for input after the fact.

Comment: This is definitely a potential issue. There are a lot of possible solutions, but in order to figure out how to prioritize them, we need to understand the kinds of questions that people will even ask in this kind of scenario. If it becomes really important to share large blocks of text or code (it probably will!) then we'll either need to settle on a standard or implement a draft feature, or something else. Overall we just want to make sure that the changes and decisions we're making are research-backed. Thanks for elaborating on this issue, though. It'll definitely be a big one.

Comment: Maybe mentor could edit in a notice in question if posted on SO, that then is removed, to avoid some downvotes, close vote and comments while still in mentoring phase, they would just need a nice template. This in the future could be developed to an automatic question lock with notice, than then is removed.

Comment: @JonEricson But the intended workflow as laid out in the question is to link people to the chat from the ask question page, so they're going there *before they've asked their question*, and then they won't have a link to the question *after* they've posted their question.  If the goal is to give people help improving their questions after they're asked (and the question doesn't lead me to believe that's actually the case) the link would need to be provided *after* they ask their question.

Comment: @KristinaLustig So you're just going to throw everyone in a chatroom without anything in place? That's simply *going* to end badly. I mentioned several major problems that you're going to have in my answer, and those types of problems aren't just going to be *possible*, they're going to be more or less *mandatory*.  There won't *be* any "good" way for people to give the mentors enough information for them to be helpful in a productive way.

Comment: @PetterFriberg If people are asking bad questions on the site we don't *want* to discourage downvotes/close votes/comments on those questions.  Those forms of feedback are all vital for the site to function.  It's a *bad thing* if they aren't provided on the questions that need them.  That would result in this feature doing more harm than good.

Comment: Providing the link to chat after the question is asked might be something we can try in the future. We don't want the chatroom to _replace_ comments however. The ideal situation is for mentors to get involved as early in the process as possible. I suspect most people will have the chat in one tab as they work on their question in another. Sharable drafts would make this work out better, but I don't think they are strictly necessary. (And certainly not necessary for us to learn a thing or two from trying.)

Comment: @JonEricson If the whole thing is designed, from the ground up, as a way for people to get feedback on questions *they've already asked*, then sure, that's a line that can be followed, I'm just saying that, as is, the feature is described as being designed as asking for help on how to ask a question *before it is asked*.

Comment: @JonEricson As for drafts being necessary, it may not be necessary for SO to have a heavily integrated and supported sharable draft feature (at first), but users need *some* way of sharing drafts with mentors, or mentors simply can't do their job, full stop.  It might be enough for this experiment to just have people host their question on some random third party hosting site (perhaps a specific one that SO suggests they use) but if the mentors can't see what the draft question is, they can't critique it, or give advice as to what to do next.

Comment: The mentors **definitely** need to be able to see the draft of the question, and it _has_ to be in the same form as it will eventually appear when the question goes live on the main site. Using 3rd party sites simply won't work, because Stack Exchange markup doesn't behave quite like anywhere else, and poor formatting is a significant issue for new askers (and as we all know, formatting in the chat rooms sucks). It's not just a matter of making the question look neat & pretty, in Python, incorrect indentation of the code alters control flow or is a syntax error.

Comment: @PM2Ring just for information, github (3rd party) has fairly similar formatting example of [github](https://github.com/SOBotics/SOCVFinder/blob/master/SOCVDBService/dev/metaPlagarsim.md) and final [meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345217/when-is-an-answer-plagiarism-and-should-be-flagged-for-moderator-attention)

Comment: @Servy: You aren't wrong. Perhaps this research will be just the thing to propel us to implement shareable drafts.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Sure, Markup on Github is very similar to Stack Exchange's, but it's not identical, and that could lead to confusion. But I guess that for most things, it's close enough. Even so, I doubt that making newbies create a Github account in order to join this mentoring chat room would be very practical.

Comment: FWIW, we occasionally get people in the Python Chat room attempting to use use GitHub-style triple backticks to format code that they post, which obviously doesn't work here. One of our ROs recently created [An Illustrated Guide To Formatting Code In Chat](https://sopython.com/wiki/An_Illustrated_Guide_To_Formatting_Code_In_Chat) which is pinned to our star board, but we still generally need to shove it into people's faces before they actually look at it...

Comment: Another temporary solution during testing if mentor is >10k is that OP post and then delete it until question is fixed

Comment: @JonEricson Well I mean, we don't really need them *now*.  If SO created sharable drafts they wouldn't have much use because there's no real place to use them.  When this rolls out that would *create* the need for such a draft, and this feature will almost certainly be net harmful if there isn't *some* means of sharing a draft (whether integrated into the site or not).  That doesn't mean that SO needs drafts, it means that *a mentoring service* needs drafts.  If you need to run an experiment to figure out that a mentoring service requires some means of sharing the draft though...

Comment: @Servy: I think better draft support would be useful anyway. But we don't have the resources to do _everything_. So the point of the experiment is that it's something we can do without burning dev time that could be used for more certain wins.

Comment: @JonEricson So you think we should run an experimental mentoring service to see if having an integrated draft feature would be useful to SO even if there isn't a mentoring service?  That makes no sense.  If you want to find out if drafts would be useful for SO even if there *isn't* a mentoring service, then how does this experiment help you figure that out?  And what's the point of running a mentoring service without any way of sharing drafts when we *know, for sure* that the mentors will need to see drafts of posts?  That experiment doesn't tell you what you want to know.

Comment: @Servy: I think you are fundamentally misunderstanding the proposal. It's not for a mentoring service, but research to see if a mentoring service might be used and useful. A valid (and very useful) result would be to find out if it isn't going to work at all. Getting sharable drafts out of the deal would be gravy. (And it might be that we need sharable drafts to even test interest in mentoring. We'll cross that bridge when we come to it.)

Comment: @JonEricson I understand that.  I'm saying that if you are trying to do research into whether or not a mentoring service might be useful, and you're running a small scale test to determine if it is, then *you're going to need to some way of sharing a draft in that test*.  You don't need to run an experiment to figure out that in order for someone to critique a possible question and help someone improve it they need to see what they've done so far.  There's no possible way for them to provide meaningful help otherwise.  Knowing that doesn't take an experiment.

Comment: @JonEricson If you're going to honestly tell me that you need to run a month long experiment involving hundreds of users in order to figure out that in order for users to critique a potential question from a new user that the mentors need to see the prospective question, then that's...pretty absurd.  Now if you said you weren't sure about the specifics of how to implement a native integration (I had a number of open ended questions on the subject in my answer) then sure, but the idea that there needs to be *some* way for the mentors to see a draft of the question doesn't take an experiment.

Comment: @Servy: I respectfully disagree. I think a draft mechanism would be very helpful, but it's not clear to me that it's a necessary requirement. Chat is very useful for abstract discussions and it will still be useful once a question is live on the site. Many sites _already do mentoring in their main chat room_. The point of this test is to focus on mentoring exclusive to the other purposes of chat.

Comment: @JonEricson Do those rooms encourage users to paste large swaths of text/code in chat itself or to use an outside service like gist? Every room with a guideline on it that I'm aware of picks outside services, and it's almost always new users who need it beaten into them to use one.

Comment: @JonEricson While I understand what you're saying, testing out how well received a feature will be - without properly implementing said feature to make it useful - will yield questionable results at best.

Comment: If the aim of the test is to gage interest for possible future work, I don't think it will matter too much if there are a few missing features. In fact, that's more or less the point. If people find this useful and interesting without drafts, that'll be good to know. If people don't bother using chat at all, that's also good to know. (See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product)

Comment: @PaulCrovella: I think this is ought to be a "no beatings" sort of room. ;-) But more to your point, if people actually try to paste lots of code or use gists, that's a good sign we'll need to support drafts. One common solution on other sites is to use a [sandbox meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).

Comment: +1 for draft questions, but I would like to see an associated review queue to handle them, rather than a chatroom.

Comment: A very valid point. There will have to be a mechanism for creating and sharing a draft, and this draft will have to be readable in order to quickly give effective feedback on the structure of the question.

Comment: @Servy what if instead of drafts, there were a few pre-made questions which had a some common mistakes in them that are only available for this purpose? Rather than fix up a completely unique question each time, the mentors could walk the new users through these pre-laid mistakes, and anything left unclear that's specific to the user's question can be asked after. This seems easier to implement than a "draft" mechanism, and there'd only need to be a few of them.

Comment: @LordFarquaad If you're going to do that you don't need live people at all.  Just write up a guide and link people to it.  That scales infinitely, unlike mentorship like this would be.  The point of this answer is that *if you want to have mentors* you need some way of sharing the draft.  My other answer (along with many of the other answers here, that I agree with) covers why I think having mentors in the first place isn't a good idea.

Comment: @toonarmycaptain a draft status question could work somewhat like [Code Golf's question sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges), which is there so that "users can get feedback on prospective challenges they wish to post to the main page"

Answer (score 83):

I signed up.

However, I think this project is doomed to fail.

The problem is that *most* of the people asking questions which fit your criteria simply lack the minimal understanding required to even *formulate* a good SO question with help. I spend a fair bit of time trying to teach programmers to fish in chat on this site, to so speak, and it's hard.

Really hard.

I expect that you will get a few types of people who actually enter these chat rooms:

- 60% help vampires (SO doesn't like this term. You must embrace it - if you want this mentoring project to succeed you MUST understand that a **large** percentage of chat askers 100% fit this definition)
- 30% people who have no idea what types of questions to ask, barely understand their problem, but can have the information drawn out of them with lengthy back/forth and uncovering of the massive XY problem(s) they are facing
- 5% will solve their issue if you get them to write an MVCE
- 5% have a good question which with minimal guidance will post it to SO and it will received well

My percentages are optimistic.

Of these categories, the first category is a writeoff. If you try to help that category without a *ruthlessly rigorous* system to filter your mentors will straight up quit.

The second need teachers/tutorials/books, not mentors.

The third and fourth are where this effort must focus its effort. However I am pretty confident that SO will focus on the first and second and doom the project.

Also, I don't know why [this A/B study to making questions actually not suck by requesting information from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278444/193412) or something similar is not done instead of this. While a mentor might affect a few people, a better question asking experience would likely affect *many* people.

---

Just for kicks, I [looked at the most recent question on Stack Overflow](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/38334700#38334700) and found these:

- [How to get SHA1 fingerprint on Android Studio 2.3.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45334032/1048539)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/45334059/1048539
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/45334065/1048539
- [Can't install Virtualbox on my linux mint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45334101/1048539)
- [Why am I getting an unexpected T_VARIABLE error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45334119/1048539)

4/5 of these are terribad questions from the formatting perspective. I don't know enough about PHP to know if 5 is too, it looks like a really basic syntax error to me, but hey code at least!

In all these cases a "mentor" would be far less effective than say... a preformed box of "what to put in a good question."

Wow, in the few minutes I took to write this up, **two** of the five questions were deleted (!).

Comment: Even though I think this is worth trying, a lot in here echoes my own worries - it *could* be that the couple of obviously capable and friendly newbies who frequently take to Twitter & co. after being treated badly on SO (the cases where most reasonable people are bound to think "SO should have treated this person better, no matter what the rules!") are the exception and there isn't an army of similar people behind them that just don't speak up. But then, maybe it's enough when we reach those couple of people? Even mentors won't be able to help everyone who comes to SO - *but that's okay*.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I think that anyone who has ever been in any of the main site chat rooms for a while will feel similar to me. I hope this is optimizing for pearls, not trying to make sand _into_ pearls...

Comment: that's a fair point. I'm not very familiar with that experience.

Comment: @enderland Changes to the /ask page are on the table along with what Kristina is proposing here. Now that we have a PM for the DAG team (Q&A focused stuff), the /ask page is going to finally get some love and attention.

Comment: @bluefeet it would be even more awesome if users filled out that template and _then_ were directed to mentors. Since I'm going to ask those exact same questions to 99% of "help me formulate a good SO question" people anyways. You could have them fill out a form not on SO directly with that information if you wanted, too, it wouldn't even have to be on SO directly.

Comment: The only way an experiment truly fails is when we fail to learn something from it.

Comment: @JonEricson there are some experiments that are better than others to run and that can teach more even if they do fail, however...

Comment: @JonEricson I think you underestimate how much we already know about the things people struggle with when asking a question, and overestimate how likely this experiment is going to result in us coming up with new (practically implementable) scalable solutions on how to address them.  It's a hard problem, one that all of us (SE itself and the community) have been striving to work on for *years*.  It's simply a hard problem, due to the nature of how hard asking a good question is and how hard it is to get people to do the work to ask a good question when they don't want to.

Comment: Also the entire point of this post is feedback. How many people involved in this project have spent time _mentoring_ people on SE chat who fit their target audience? I am often in [the Python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) and see the types of people you are looking to help here. I would strongly encourage Kristina (and others involved here) to actually go through the process of helping or reading the back/forths which happen with these sorts of users before just throwing blind ideas around. Your comment reads like "eh who cares, we'll try it and see what happens."

Comment: Help vampires _shouldn't_ be much a problem in the mentoring room(s), since we won't actually be answering their technical question. OTOH, any new user entering the room needs to _fully_ understand that the room is for fixing questions, not answering them, so if they persist in trying to get their technical question answered in the room they should be linked to the standard references re help vampires and kicked from the room.

Comment: @PM2Ring sure, but... oftentimes separating a help vampire from the second group is not clear until a long effort.

Comment: @Servy What we're saying is that, in order to make confident product changes and invest resources into a project like this, we need to do research. Anecdotes and even observed patterns are useful, but they may not capture a wide variety of use cases and problems that we don't know about - precisely because this specific functionality doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @enderland I hear you. The feedback we're getting in this post is giving me a lot of insight into a few problems that we either hadn't thought about, or didn't originally consider would be big issues. So all of it is extremely valuable - thank you. We're not throwing blind ideas around - the concept of mentorship has been floating around for a long time, and there's even academic research on mentorship/personalized help in online communities. We have limited eng time and are trying to implement a test as scrappily as possible, in order to start learning.

Comment: @KristinaLustig I would encourage you to stop by many of the SO chat rooms and ask people there, who have dealt with mentoring/helping people on a regular basis for _years_ and ask their input before going too far down this proposal. A day or so of interactions will give you a ton of insight into designing a much better experiment.

Comment: In the Python chat room (where I'm one of several room owners) we have a policy that people can't ask for answers on their fresh SO questions (they need to wait a couple of days first), but they _are_ permitted to ask for this kind of meta-help to fix up their fresh question. But we also get people who are asking questions that are too trivial or a bit too broad for the main site, and it's with those questions that we're prone to HV attacks. And these are all people who have enough rep to talk in chat, not raw 1-reppers, so they should have _some_ knowledge of how to act properly on SO...

Comment: @PM2Ring yeah, that's the scary part. Chat is already flooded with... uh, sand, and that requires you to at least have some positive SO content.

Comment: @enderland: We've looked at those conversations and I have participated in some myself. One issue we've seen is that general chat rooms get overwhelming for new users who just need a little help. (Example: [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11139/lets-talk-about-chat-again).) So the idea here it to focus down on _one task_: mentoring. Part of the reason mentoring on chat is so difficult is that not everyone is focused on the same task.

Comment: 'I signed up' - that's very err. courageous and brave ;)   I may consider signing up if the first week goes OK-ish, else I risk ending up suspended again.  I don't want to be involved in bar fights - I'm the one who ends up in hospital/jail.

Comment: The PHP question indeed is a syntax error, an unescaped quote. The highlighting of the code in the question already gives it away. After (or actually *before*) posting this question, OP should have wondered *"Why the f... is the whole second part of my code red"*, and that would have directed them to the exact point of failure. They do know about escaping, because other quotes are escaped.

Comment: Maybe we should just remove the ability to ask a question at all, and replace it with a banner that says 'We have zero interest in helping you'.  Solves all of the problems.

Comment: @Kik I don't think that 'removing the ability to ask a question at all' is realistic on a Q&A site.  The banner, however, seems more promising, though it lacks detail as described and would be misinterpreted.  I suggest 'We have little interest in helping you except as a side-effect.  Good questions and good answers might be useful to you, but SO is looking to help Fannie and Freddie: those users who look up SO Q&A next week, next year, or next decade '.

Answer (score 49):

The warmth and inherent civility of communicating one-on-one with a live human being is the great feature of this project, but it could also be its downfall.

There's going to be a LOT of unreasonable people asking for a quick answer to their programming question and little interest in anything else.

These are the situations that suck the lifeblood out of the most idealistic mentor.

Avoiding these situations is much more easy on Stack Overflow as it currently works. You only contribute slices of time, every burden is shared, every interaction is somewhat asynchronous and there is no expectation of instant responses, there is strong cultural encouragement *not* to waste your time on too much one-on-one mentoring, et cetera.

How will Stack Overflow be protecting its mentors from the demands of unreasonable askers, given that it is much more difficult to bow out from a one-on-one conversation than from a Stack Overflow question?

Will there be clear-cut rules on what the purpose of mentoring is, and what it isn't, so mentors have something to rely on when a conversation becomes unproductive? "No programming questions" is a good start, but it might need more.

I'm even thinking this might need mods/employees watching over the conversations that go on and stepping in where they get out of control, but not sure whether that is feasible.

Comment: This *isn't* proposed as a one on one interaction.  It's proposed as a chatroom filled with lots of mentors and lots of people looking for help.

Comment: In a shared chat full of people who need mentoring it'll be a lot of them *answering* those unreasonable people. Without very strict moderation that can quickly spiral into incentivising all the wrong behavior.

Comment: @Servy `This isn't proposed as a one on one interaction` right, yeah, I see. Hmmm

Comment: Mentors that persist in actually answering the questions rather than helping fix them will need to get kicked, at least temporarily. Otherwise, chaos will ensue.

Comment: @PM2Ring Not just mentors, *anyone* in the chat.

Comment: @PaulCrovella True, but there won't _be_ anyone in that chat room apart from the selected mentors & the raw newbies, and I'm assuming that the newbies mostly won't have the knowledge to be able to supply answers. OTOH, looking at a lot of the recent answers on SO, lack of knowledge doesn't seem to be much of an impediment for a lot of the people answering. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring There's a lot of blind leading the blind out there, but the problem isn't whether they know the answer or not. The newbies would be in chat because they don't know what's expected of them on the site - prime candidates for screwing up in the chat as well.

Comment: @PaulCrovella I get the impression that Kristina plans on ensuring that everyone entering that chat room is aware of the purpose of the room and its ground rules. I don't disagree with what you're saying, but I still think that there's a greater risk of the mentors answering than of the newbies answering. But I guess only time will tell...

Answer (score 34):

In light of this test plan moving forward, I feel I first have to ask about the assumption I see here:

#### What weight balance does Stack Overflow (the company) give to new user experience?

Do you have the directive to give a great new user experience at the cost of everything else? Or are you looking to provide an equal balance between new user experience and maintaining the high quality of Stack Overflow? There are many users who might suggest that a less-than-optimal or obstacle-laden new user experience is *ideal* because it weeds out people who just want to come here and get a code dump or have their work done for them, etc.

I think we can all guess which rough direction the company is pushing toward, but a response on this would help guide us as users in our recommendations and understanding of your ultimate goal. The balance you want to strike could make some suggestions completely out of the question, or make a hesitant reader think "Oh, then I have the perfect suggestion".

---

With that aside, my question for the Mentorship Project is:

#### How will you handle quality control of the mentors themselves?

Obviously a unified front is ideal, with equal measures of quality from each user, but as has been hinted at in other answers, different users have different ideas of 'how to ask a good question'. There are many users on Stack Overflow with 10,000 or 100,000 reputation who regularly answer duplicates, even when others leave comments asking them not to. Likewise, there are some users who think asking simple questions is the worst possible use of Stack Overflow, despite the Community Team saying "no, simple questions are fine, as long as they're useful, well-crafted, and not duplicates".

Will there be quality standards that mentors must meet, or else they risk being removed as a mentor? Can mentors flag or vote for other mentors to be removed or have a Community Team employee check out their mentoring quality? Or will you just try to discern the good from the bad during the invitation process and then turn a blind eye or have embarrassing break-up moments later on down the road when it turns out a mentor isn't that great after all?

Comment: This is a big issue, and I will not be attempting to mentor in the initial stages of this experiment; I will just lurk.  Raising 'unhelpful' or 'abusive' flags on someone who does not immediately provide an answer to bad homework question dup #535 is not unknown on SO, and I want no part of mentoring until I understand the written, and unwritten, rules of the game.

Comment: I really think your "aside" in the first part is a really key question. It *seems* like SO (the company) cares more about new questions/askers than existing answerers.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Indeed, and if so, then that's fine, but I think we all would like it to be clarified in some concrete terms, because I see it being very easy for a new user UX project to reduce the quality of questions from new users *vis-a-vis* making it easier for new users to ask questions. By the very nature of them being new to the site, they'll be less likely to know what the site considers a 'good' question.

Comment: I'm not sure it is a "seems" at this point. [Recent Meta posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343228#comment444337_343228) have [made it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349255/stack-overflow-now-has-its-own-app-on-ios-and-android#comment474627_349255) abundantly [clear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351751/meet-team-dag-developer-affinity-growth/351792#351792).

Comment: @JoshCaswell it's clear from this question.  It is assumed that all new users arrive to ask questions, and any skilled/experienced engineers who turn up to give free time to answer questions can be ignored.  I expect that the chances of any kind of mentoring system to assist that class of new user to identify vamps, deadbeats, gimmeTehCodez, doAllMywork, doMyDebug, doMytesting etc. is approx. zero.  I wonder how many answer a question or two, have their blood drained, leave and never come back?

Comment: @TylerH RE: your first point about new user experience. The DAG team takes question quality and new user experience seriously. I don't see them as mutually exclusive. We'd like to provide an experience that gives a new user a better chance of success. Mentoring may play a role in that. Or, this experiment may help us better understand how to programmatically help a new user to ask a better question. The ultimate goals are satisfied, engaged members AND quality content.

Comment: @JoeFriend Would the team be at all open to ideas for improving question quality at expense to the new asker experience? Just as an example: a time delay of 24 hours after registering before they're allow to ask a question on the site?

Comment: @PaulCrovella Short answer is yes. However, I think this could be implemented in a way that doesn't come off as "at the expense of the new asker experience." It would be interesting to run an experiment to determine how short of a delay is long enough to discourage the wrong behavior and encourage the right behavior. My hypothesis would be that even 30-60 minutes may be enough.

Comment: @JoeFriend I'd love to see the results of that experiment. I chose 24 hours based just on the number of "member since today" profiles I see asking low quality and off topic questions, so it's somewhat arbitrary. It'd be interesting to see the effect on the question signal to noise ratio for various delays.

Answer (score 30):

My greatest worry over this is that the mentors will need a good grasp of SO policy and rules.  To me, this is mods and/or experienced SO users.  Since the free time of both those sets is a limited resource, the time spend on mentoring new users may be deducted from the time available to actually answer good questions and/or handle bad questions/users :(

Comment: True, but unfortunately most question are currently bad (duplicate or off-topic), I prefer spending my time helping out to avoid these, rather then to close vote review and flag offensive comments on them.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I can understand that, sure.  I have always downvoted meta proposals that move the effort of fixing bad questions from the OP to the skilled and experienced engineers that answer good questions.  My fear is that this proposal falls squarely in that bin, but I'm supporting it anyway as a trial/experiment, though I have that nagging feeling still that 'something must be done, this is something, so this must be done':)

Comment: I mean, it could even be counter-productive.  In a similar fashion to the way parachutes, life-jackets and smoke-hoods would result in more air crash deaths, moderator time may be so diverted from 'normal' SO activities that the number of bad questions actually increases, (at a greater rate than now:).

Comment: For your first comment I don't really have an issue, who cares about where the effort is spent, important for me is that we end up with a useful Q/A for future users. For the experiment I guess it will be a duplicate finder experiment (at least that is my experience with users that ping me in chat), hence they have a question, I pass you a link to a duplicate end of story. However I have signed up, it would be interesting to see how they like to do this experiment and if we end up with a better ask question interface, I'm all in!

Comment: @PetterFriberg I don't have great hopes, but we'll see.   Shoud be interesting, either way;)

Answer (score 29):

When you want to ask a question, you need to follow these steps:

1. Narrow down in one, or at most a couple of sentences, explaining at a high level what you're trying to do and why. Kind of a [user story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_story).
2. Show what code you already have. Even if your question is a *"How do I"*, you need to show a frame of reference for answerers to get them to know about the types and values of the input and output.
3. Show what you have tried. *"I have written this code (see #2) but it doesn't work"* is *not* what you have tried, we want to see what you have tried to *make that code work*.

That's really all there is to it, but it requires a couple of paragraphs of text.

I strongly believe this format will not work in chat form, not in the first place because the "mentors" will get tired pretty quickly of explaining these three steps over and over again to impatient users who just want their problem solved.

Also, because mentors will be required to be somewhat of an expert (at least if we don't want a "blind leading the blind" situation), I'm afraid they won't have the persistence to keep hand-holding newbies into asking a good question and will quickly burn out, while tons of effort have already went in writing [comprehensive pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that [perfectly explain how to do so](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). There is absolutely no need to rehash those pages for everyone who wants to ask a question.

I also believe that the outcome of this initial experiment will be positive. The users who do visit and engage with a mentor in chat are already the ones interested in writing a good question, and the mentors present there will be happy if they helped their mentees - a win-win. That doesn't mean it'll scale up or won't require an extraordinary amount of effort compared to the results gained.

Instead the [Ask a Question page should be redesigned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page).

Comment: You make a good point - there's definitely the danger that those who have signed on to mentor will get burned out - we'll watch out for that, and we'll also be interviewing mentors afterwards to understand their experiences. There's just so much benefit we can get out of running an experiment like this. It will help us to be able to say with certainty that X or Y thing does or does not work, and understand why that is. This is probably not the ideal solution, it's just the first one we're testing.

Comment: @Kristina I'm all for experiments. I'm just not really convinced it'll work, and wanted to share that. Definitely don't let that hold you back.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the input from this project will help us do a better job of redesigning the ask page.

Comment: Having the ask a question page require those steps (with separate inputs) would be really nice. The "show what code you have" section could be auto-formatted, which would resolve a lot of problems with new questions.

Comment: I predict a mentor half-life of two days.

Answer (score 24):

Your chat group would have to be populated by trained monkeys that keep spitting the same code phrases:

- "Please include MCVS"
- "Please specify the desired behavior"
- "Please include the error message"
- "A request for debugging help is not a question"
- "A request for coding service is not a question"
- "Please try to use a debugger"
- "Please refer to the foundational text/reference/language definition"
- "Please consult with your professor to improve your understanding"

If the goal is to reduce the time the community spends filtering out the bad questions, chat is exactly the wrong thing.

Most of the bad questions' OPs do not come here to learn how to ask. They come here to scratch an itch. They are not interesting in learning about questions, they need answers.

Your mentors will have to try to teach the people who are not interested in learning.

Instead, you need to **assist** people in asking questions. As was suggested on Meta before, we need a New Question Wizard.

The "Ask a Question" page for the new OP would have a bunch of links:

- "My program crashes"
- "My program does not compile"
- "My program throws an exception"
- "My program does not do what I tell it to do"
- "How do I write code for my homework?"

The natural inclination of a less-experienced OP is to take the assistance. And then you have him/her! You can structure their questions, you can ask for every relevant element, you can even say "Please don't post your homework assignment here, this is not a homework site".

This will be much less labor-intensive than chat and likely more useful, too.

Comment: That is the essence. Askers should be obligatorily informed  & assisted; there is already mentoring; it is ignored; questions should be close-voted, so askers will edit; not downvoted, it's not nice.

Comment: @philipxy  'Askers should be obligatorily informed & assisted' well, that would have to be an automated system. Suggestions for such an automaton have been suggested before, and resisted as an unwanted barrier to new users:(

Comment: @MartinJames My comment doesn't commit. The obligation can be imposed as closure until improvement per comments. I agree auto is problematic. Certainly info & input could be better structured for those who want to ask good questions.

Comment: @philipxy you may well be right.  I'm gonna open a burner account, and go through the process of asking a question, right up to the point of actually submitting it, and then back out.  I need to see for myself what new users get as advice:)

Answer (score 21):

> What do you think about this idea?

I like *the idea* of this idea. Improving the experience of first-time posters, and their posts themselves, is a worthwhile goal. I know quite a few people who think of Stack Overflow as too pedantic: *"I never post on Stack Overflow because I just get downvoted and criticized for stuff that doesn't actually matter."* Imho, improving this should be one of the core goals of the Stack Overflow team. So it's cool to see that people are actually thinking about the problem.

> What concerns do you have with how we’re deciding to implement this initially?

In a nutshell: **the people who don't read the wall-of-text aren't going to click a link to a chatroom,** let alone spend the time to learn how to format their posts.

> And most importantly: are you interested in volunteering to be a mentor?

Honestly? No. I spend a lot of time in some niche tags, and I consider myself a pretty kumbaya Stack-Overflow-ian. I err on the side of answering questions that are too broad, or not really fully formulated, because I know how overwhelming programming can be to a novice.

That being said, I've been a member (and moderator) of several forums at this point, and the main reason I prefer Stack Overflow is its zero tolerance policy on "code plz" questions. I think this idea of offering a helpful chat room vastly underestimates the number of posts that should simply be deleted immediately, because the OP didn't spend the bare minimum amount of time on it. And again, that type of user is not going to spend the time to click a link, talk about their problem, learn how to format their post, make revisions, get feedback, etc.

If other people are excited about being mentors, more power to them. But I'm afraid that, at best, mentors will spend 99% of their time on basically useless posts that simply should not be posted at all. And that really takes a toll, as evidenced by all of the forums I barely visit anymore.

It might be argued that this feature is not intended to help that type of user, and is instead geared towards users who *want* to spend the time to ask a well-formed question. But in that case, **getting help in a chat room is not less work than reading a wall of text,** so I'm not sure how much this will help those users or Stack Overflow's repuation. *"Stack Overflow is so complicated that they have a chat room just for learning how to post!"*

Answer (score 18):

> - What do you think about this idea?

I think it's a well-intentioned, but misdirected idea. It seems to ignore what is, at least in my opinion, the biggest problem Stack Overflow has, which is a fundamental aspect of human nature. The people who are altruistically-minded, or even have the pairing of being reward-motivated *and* skilled enough to produce high-quality content for the site are *enormously* outnumbered by the people who just don't give a crap, and who rely on the gamification that motivates lower-quality handling of answering.

First and foremost on that question of lower-quality of answering, is people's willingness to write a new answer, generally of low-quality, for a question that is either unclear (so their answer is one of a half-dozen or more *guesses*) or which has already been asked and answered in a much clearer way (so the question should have been closed as a duplicate rather than being answered).

Put another way: this idea appears to focus on helping people that, frankly, are never going to contribute good, useful, high-quality content to the site, and who probably don't really want the help in the first place.

One problem Stack Overflow has always struggled with, as near as I can tell, is the dichotomy between the idea of helping *individuals* and building something that is useful for the community *as a whole*. IMHO, the latter is the real goal of Stack Overflow, and that goal is *not* served by spoon-feeding people who aren't willing or able to sign on to it.

But this mentoring idea does exactly that. It will *greatly* add to the work-load of dealing with low-quality contributors to the site, without appreciably improving the overall quality of the site. The people who find themselves in need of mentoring are still going to ask duplicate questions, will still show up having done little or no research of their own, and will still be asking questions that they should and could have answered for themselves by just reading the documentation.

Opinions vary, and I understand some people, even those answering questions instead of asking them, view Stack Overflow as just a large-scale helpdesk for programmers. But for me, the primary value here is in fact the building of an all-encompassing repository for *good* programming questions and answers, and this goal is at odds with a mentality that every person asking a question deserves an effort at answering their question.

> - What concerns do you have with how we’re deciding to implement this initially?

My biggest concern is the lack of collaboration tools that would help it succeed, first and foremost being a mechanism to pair up mentor and mentee, and to provide a mechanism for the mentor to have immediate access to the mentee's work as they receive help.

My other concern is, of course, as stated above: this idea seems likely to wind up dedicating the most resources to those least deserving of them. That is, the people who view Stack Overflow as just something to serve them, rather than something they can *participate* in and help *improve*.

> - And most importantly: are you interested in volunteering to be a mentor?

No way, no how. I've already seen how a person who is poor at asking questions can become a huge time suck if you let them. I've fallen into that trap more than once, and I work hard these days to avoid it. I pity those who are willing to volunteer for mentor service in this program; to be sure, they will once in a while wind up helping a person who genuinely wants to put their best foot forward and is willing to take constructive criticism to do so. But I'm sure the vast majority of interactions will be with the exact opposite of that. Our mentors are going to need a *lot* of patience to get through that.

In a perfect world, there'd be special training to help people understand how to ask good questions. In terms of research, presentation, and construction. Such training would be provided separately, and would be a prerequisite for asking questions on a site like Stack Overflow. Most importantly, it would have an outcome-testing aspect, ensuring that those who are certified as qualified authors of questions have in fact met the goals of that certification.

In fact, it's why I liked [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/353849) and have myself thought a similar design would be appropriate. The idea of mentoring isn't bad, it's just that it's too costly for the reward when it requires an actual person for each person in need.

I favor instead a question-authoring user interface forced on inexperienced users that would guide them through the composition of a good question. This is by no means a trivial task, but IMHO a much more worthy and potentially fruitful area of research. *Templates* and *automation* together, to constrain how a new user presents their question (say, a form with a questionnaire format for example), and to evaluate in an automated way using, for example, modern language-processing/neural net pattern matching technologies to judge whether a question is coherent, provides adequate details, and a suitable code example.

On that latter point, things like detecting that a user is asking about code that doesn't work or which throws an exception, but has not provided an actual description of the behavior of the code, or any specific details about the exception, such as the type, message, and stack trace. It may even be feasible, in conjunction with a template approach, to know when a question likely requires a full MCVE, and whether that question has in fact included one.

Templates can provide that framework for the user to work within, and may also help simplify the job of the automation, by providing additional context for the pattern-matching. In a manner similar to the game-tutorial concept, there could even be multiple levels of complexity, starting from the most restrictive, and loosening up as the user gains experience and demonstrates competence, until they have full access and can write a post without any constraints at all.

If there's going to be research, I think it best to focus on solutions that *reduce* rather than *increase* the demand on volunteer services. Stack Overflow is already straining under the demand that exists today, so I don't think a new program that significantly adds to that work-load is likely to work out.

Comment: I too have these concerns, especially the time/effort of skilled and experienced developers diverted from answering good questions, and mods diverted from handling bad questions and/or users.  I will lurk on the room to see what is happening and, if it seems to be directly useful, may even volunteer to mentor, (but yes, I can't see that happening, but I'm prepared to be proved wrong).  If it tanks, then I can reference the remains as a shield in future 'SO does not help new users' posts:(

Comment: My thoughts on reading the announcement were along these lines as well. It's not enough that experts provide solutions, now the expectation is to walk through the formulation of the problems, too? The only saving grace here is that the program is explicitly time-limited.

Answer (score 15):

Is it a single chatroom for all new users and mentors, or are new chatrooms created for more one-on-one interactions?

I don't know if you'll get enough mentors for true one-on-one coverage, but chatrooms can get too busy and too hectic if there is more than one conversation going on.  Perhaps there could be a single room that then breaks up into smaller rooms after mentors interact with new users?

Comment: Yeah, right now we're planning it as a single chatroom for exactly the reason you mentioned - we don't think we'll have enough for 1:1 coverage. That single chatroom model might not be sustainable or scalable, but it'll be the easiest to implement. If we have a need for more infrastructure and smaller chats, then we'll definitely want to explore that, too, once we have the results from this experiment.

Comment: I think it'll need to be a hybrid: start off in a joint chatroom (or possibly have a few, based on tags?) but then "pair up" users and mentors quickly.

Comment: You could probably do something similar to how loads for sites can be split between servers, maybe have a pair of mentors to a room, and split the new users between these rooms?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yup - if this works well and we want to implement this more formally/permanently, we'll need to invest more resources in figuring out how to scale it properly.

Comment: I agree that it will probably get too hectic and confusing if it's all confined to a single room. IME it can get a bit bewildering if there are more than 3 or 4 conversations going on in the chat rooms I frequent.  OTOH, these mentoring conversations _should_ be fairly short, unlike actual problem-solving conversations that can go on and on. And I guess there is a benefit to having the core experience focused in a single room.

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm not so sure they'll always be short.  You can look to plenty of meta examples on this one; people sometimes link to a question and ask how it can be improved, which is more or less what's going on in this proposal (but in chat).  These posts end up in lengthy discussions often enough.

Comment: @KristinaLustig maybe spin up a new room for each case (like how each post can have its own associated chat room), *and* have a way to alert the pool of active mentors?  For example, when a new room is created, can it be automatically linked into the single "mentors" room so whoever's there can click through?  (There's probably a better way to do it; this is off the top of my head.)

Comment: Right @MonicaCellio.  I had a similar idea, but didn't know how well it would play with the notification system.  And that would need better coverage else a new user could just be sitting in a room by themself for a while.

Comment: @ryanyuyu transient notification is hard.  You don't want to fill up the inboxes of mentors who aren't online at the moment (like plain old chat pings would do), but you do want a way for them to passively find out someone's waiting for help.  We don't have something like "@here" to ping just the mentors currently in chat, so a feed into a dedicated room is the next-best thing I could come up with.

Answer (score 15):

Here's my summary of my experiences dealing with those asking "bad" questions:

- 95%+ of them clearly didn't even bother typing their question into Google (often I can just type the title of their own question into Google to get the answer).
- 95%+ will ignore (or disregard) every single comment that attempts to get them to improve their question, no matter how polite those comments are.

Based on this, I assume the vast majority of users will do one of three things:

- Try to ask their question there, expecting an answer, since it's less effort, or because why not.

  If they don't get an answer there, they'll just ask their question as usual.
- Actively ignore it.
- Be entirely oblivious to their own wrong-doing, or think this will just consist of the "mean" users from Stack Overflow, and just ask their question as usual.

The rest of the users (probably a fraction of a percent of the total) will:

- Want to try it, but they'd be intimidated by having to figure out what exactly they're supposed to ask that's not their question and revert back to asking the question as usual.
- Ask their question there (expecting meta feedback), be hit with a long list of requirements or consider the constructive feedback to be "mean" (consider that we generally expect users to do extensive research and basically rewrite their code before posting it here), give up and just ask their question as usual.

  Also, if they just ask their question there... shouldn't we just spend some effort "fixing" review and send it there instead? Isn't the First Posts queue essentially made for this very purpose?

  Aren't comments also made for this purpose? Why does this **need** to happen in chat? Why is this happening in chat better than it happening in comments? Because comments will be ignored and answers will come either way?

  If you want to prevent answers while resolving this, can't we just **show the question in review, but hide it from public view** (upon it being posted), preventing answers (and votes?) and let comments do what they were made for? Wouldn't that basically be an improved version of what's suggested here - less effort required by the asker, the asker can't really just ignore the feedback and ask anyway, it can (selectively) happen automatically instead of (or in addition to) being opt-in and it's using the existing review system. [Comments probably also need some improvements](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4587/comments-are-not-for-extended-discussion-long-term-solution-discussion), but I digress.

Also, not answering questions where we're not supposed to answer questions is hard, like really hard. Have you looked at the comments on just about every question? I can't imagine many people would manage to completely refrain from just answering the question sometimes in chat, which would entirely defeat the purpose.

**In summary:**

I don't know which users you're targeting here, but it sounds like we have **very** different views of what the average user on Stack Overflow looks like, and I'm not sure why you want to build an entire new system instead of just spending some time experimenting with what you already have.

Comment: @davidism What is your point vis a vis this answer? The answer says that being in chat *is* just another queue, waiting for people to address the very same points made in comments already, but don't.

Comment: If the "under review" thing rolls out, I certainly want a way to opt out of seeing questions I can't vote on. Oh, and how is borderline spam going to be handled?

Comment: @JohnDvorak I don't know if preventing votes is a good idea (it's also an optional part of it), but my suggestion (if implemented well) seems better in every way to the whole mentorship project thing. The question should only show in review, which would make it trivially easy to avoid. What's borderline spam? Sounds like something that should be flagged instead of just downvoted. Borderline spam would probably also be easier to handle with my suggestion as opposed to the original suggestion (because there's an entire mature and extensive flagging, moderation and review system already there).

Answer (score 13):

I see two possible outcomes of this:

1. Very, very few people actually use the feature, because they're just here to ask their question, not to chat with people about how to ask their question.  If this happens, the feature hasn't actually accomplished much of anything, even if those few people actually get good feedback.  The problems you laid out will still be happening about as frequently as they're happening now.
2. Lots of people use it; a significant enough portion of the people asking questions actually use this to help them ask better question.  The end result, the chat room is unusable because there are too many people talking over each other, and nobody can follow what's being said, and also there will be so many more people asking for help than there will be people willing/able to help them that only a very small portion of the people asking questions actually get help, and those that do get help will tend to get more superficial help, and not get significant amounts of feedback, because the people helping them will be in such a hurry to get to the other people looking to get help.

Now that doesn't mean that the feature will be net harmful as a result of this, so it doesn't mean that this alone is reason to not do it, but I'd say it has a very low ceiling as far as possible benefits.

Honestly this feature seems about as useful as people just asking on meta when they want help critiquing a question they have (either one already posted, or one not yet posted), which is to say that it works great in very small numbers, but just doesn't scale up.

This might be more likely to be a useful feature on smaller sites, rather than sites like SO, where the ratio of regular users to questions is much lower, and it's actually practical to critique the quesitons of everyone asking for it.  If this does happen though you'd need to be sure to not show the link to new users if the chatroom has no mentors in it, because in a smaller site there might not be mentors there 24/7.

Comment: Kind of a loose-loose situation...

Comment: What about the third option, where we have juuuust the right number of mentors and new question askers and everything is perfect? :D (But really, your point is really valid and something we're worried about, but we think we need to learn a lot more about this approach via experimenting in order to find out.)

Comment: @KristinaLustig The third option results in you waking up from your dream and finding that you actually ended up with option 1 (or you ended up in option 2 for a few days and then people stopped using it because it didn't help, and the mentors got overworked and the novelty wore off, and you ended up with option 1).

Comment: All prospective mentors should stock up on beer, just in case @Servy is right.

Comment: @MartinJames alcohol intake by mentors is possibly a good success / failure metric.

Comment: The sensible way to address #2 is to have the link shown to a percentage of askers, and adjust that % according to the number of mentors available (with some hard cap). Obviously if this works we'll need a more robust system than a chatroom, but no sense in building it without testing first.

Comment: @Shog9 Sure, that's just forcing yourself into option 1.  There are lots of ways to do that, you suggested one (you could also go by some metrics, rather than choosing randomly, similar to what the first post/late answer/VLQ queues do).  My point here is simply to say that of all of the possible options, there's a ceiling on how much good this can possibly do, even if it works perfectly, and the ceiling is fairly low.  Even if you create a test that is effective a small scale, you won't be able to scale it up later.

Comment: or make multiple chat rooms and have people round robin sent to one of them?

Comment: @enderland That wouldn't remove the problems I've addressed in the post or the comments here.  It would remove some of the general chaos, but it won't solve the problem that there's way more people looking to get help than there are people to help them.  Splitting them up into multiple rooms won't magically create more mentors.

Comment: You said #1 was folks not using it because they don't care, @Servy. That's on them; removing the option because there aren't folks available to help is on us, and seems a reasonable approach to scale - certainly there are many thousands of unanswered questions *on Stack Overflow itself* for the same reason; ignorance on the part of one person does not create a responsibility for anyone else.

Comment: @Shog9 But that's just it.  Either the people asking questions don't want to use the feature, so it doesn't help, and it's their fault, or those people *do* ask for help in large numbers, and then we can't handle it, and that's our fault.  If we actually run the experiment we'll be able to figure out who's "fault" it is that the system can't work, but *my* point in this answer is that *there is no situation in which this works*.  We might be able to figure out *why it doesn't work*, but we already know, before we start, that it won't work.

Comment: Servy argues that there aren't enough potential mentors out there to make a difference. I tend to agree. Even for smaller sites, there might be less askers but also less experts/mentors, so even there the ratio might be too low.

Comment: Some might say that volunteering as a mentor is like volunteering for point duty in a combat hot zone, and will surely get you used/abused/suspended/banned.  I could not possibly comment myself...

Comment: @Trilarion Personally I think some of the smaller sites at least have a shot.  I'm not super active on any, but my interactions with some, and second hand knowledge of others, would tell me that there's at least enough of a possibility to run an experiment for some of the smaller sites.  I don't think SO has any chance at all, so such an experiment is just a waste of time and resources.

Answer (score 12):

I think it's positive that you're thinking about how to address the problem of new members not knowing the ropes.

My concern is that it assumes a reasonable majority of new members are open to being coached in how to ask a question, and will respond positively when invited into a chatroom where others refuse to answer their particular question, and instead give pointers on how to ask a better question.

In my experience, there is a high prevalence among new members of one of more of the following

- Not bothering to take time to learn the ropes;
- Skipping without reading through pages that provide guidance on the rules or expectations of the site;
- Skipping guidance on how to ask questions in a way more likely to elicit a useful response;
- Signing up with the hope of finding a free homework service;
- Diving straight in with a question, without doing any search or otherwise checking that a similar question has been asked before.
- If advised that they need to ask questions better, simply deeming that advice a waste of time.

The list goes on.   But, in most cases, the behaviours are consistent with wanting a quick answer to questions they have asked, rather than guidance on how to contribute more useful questions to the site.

Not only SO is affected by this - it is quite common among forum sites that are open to questions from beginners as well.

More conventionally, mentoring programs often work better if the mentee (if that is a word) voluntarily seeking out a mentor for advice, rather than being taken aside (into a chatroom in this case) for a round of mentoring.

Answer (score 11):

I suspect you'll need a serious contingent of users with room owner or moderator powers to keep that room in line. Users will ask programming questions in there, probably a lot of them. If you can't keep the noise level down in the room, it'll be horribly confusing.

I don't think anybody knows what will happen if we give a lot of 1 rep users access to chat. There is some potential for abuse there, but maybe the spammers are too slow to adapt to this.

One big concern for me would be simply whether this can scale. With thousands of new questions per day, this will require a very large number of mentors if it were to run at full scale, and not a test for a small percentage of users. I don't see that many users signing up for a potentially very frustrating job.

Comment: Yeah - we're prepared to throttle the % of users that the chat link is displayed to depending on adoption. We're not anticipating that there'll be an extremely high rate of people clicking into a sidebar link, but you're right - we'll need to be prepared for that.

Comment: I like the chat room as a very low-effort step toward a more robust mentoring system. (I proposed [one idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254205/opt-in-mentor-privilege-at-7-5k/262292#262292) a few years ago.) A single chat room won't scale, but it will give us more evidence for whether a mentoring system would even work and what we'd need to do to maximize success. I can see an end state with many chat room to scale this up. I can also see an end state that isn't chat centric at all. This project is very much a trial balloon.

Comment: @davidism Oh, yup! The chat link will only show up the first time you ask a question.

Comment: @KristinaLustig no, I mean the mentors will need a system to know if this is a return user. Nothing stops users from bookmarking and re-joining chat just to keep getting help with their low effort drafts. As an owner of the Python room, we have a whole backend system outside of SO that tracks what users we've seen and whether they're vampires, so that all ROs are on the same page. I know mods have annotations, but that's not available to ROs.

Comment: @davidism interesting. Our current approach is to only let certain users (the ones who are flagged as mentors or who arrive at the chat directly from the ask-a-question page) participate in the chat - others are observers. There may still be holes for abuse there - I appreciate the flag. We'll keep an eye out. We many need some kind of timing mechanism or gate.

Comment: @davidism Maybe I'm confused - does what I explained not address the issue of re-joining mentees?

Comment: @KristinaLustig Of course that just incentivises those people to create new accounts so that they can get access to the room again.

Answer (score 10):

> 1. They are too intimidated by the wall of text (or get distracted or any number of things) and they just don’t ask it
> 2. They ask a question, but it’s badly formed and it gets downvoted or deleted or snarked at
> 3. They ask a question, but it’s a duplicate and gets closed right away (which is good for SO overall, but probably doesn’t feel great in-the-moment)
> 4. They ask an appropriately-formed question and get a useful response

I'm a big proponent of the idea of giving people a nice wide open space to type in to start with, and not giving them a wall of text they'll just skip as if it were a software licensing agreement.  *(I'm still mad I clicked that thing about [not using iTunes for nuclear weapons](https://www.cnet.com/news/apple-dont-make-nuclear-weapons-using-itunes/), I should have read more carefully.)*

The better time to hit them is probably *after* they've finished writing the question (or during), but before it's posted, to give them a chance to go back.  And that also means you've got some data on what they put into the box to drive a guidance engine.  I am a broken record on this one, but could you at least *try* this idea?:

[Pre-flight screening checklist for first/early posts--adaptively pick three items, tune with metrics](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265671/pre-flight-screening-checklist-for-first-early-posts-adaptively-pick-three-item)

Figure out what works and doesn't, based on how people's questions who are shown the varied prompts wind up being received.  Maybe notice things like some screening questions are most effective on short questions, or perhaps they should depend on the tag, or whatever.  Short and punchy--no wall.

> What do you think about this idea?

Throwing people into chat just means they'll ask their questions in chat.  But as with what I said above, the time to get involved in mentoring is after the question is composed...if they look at the situation and go "help!"  Maybe a button so that if they're getting downvoted it can go *"looks like you're downvoted, want to put your question on hold for a bit and ask for some assistance?"*

Comment: *"Looks like you're downvoted, want to put your question on hold for a bit and ask for some assistance?"* Copyright  Ⓒ 1996-2003 Microsoft Word. Clippit is a registered trademark of Microsoft Office Word 2003. All rights reserved.

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer I worked at Microsoft when they were doing research on how much people hated the paperclip.  At first it was interpreted as saying the office assistant was a failed idea.  But they found that many people who hated the paperclip liked the dog.  There's something particularly condescending about the paperclip, in particular.  Anyway, I think other automated assistive stuff (your question may be a duplicate, these words in the title may get it closed) are good, as long as they're just *advice*...if I mechanically can't post something because of a word in the title, that's bad.

Comment: I understand, but I was just making a comedic reference. In all realness, that pattern of Clippy has now become somewhat cliché that is all too informal: "It looks like you're trying to [...]; would you like some help with that?"

Comment: I'd have to imagine that, because of the way our brain associates objects, the paper clip is probably associated with negative emotions: the stressful workplace that no one wants to think of—even at work itself; school; mundane tasks; etc. The dog is usually associated with positive emotions: playfulness, affections, etc.

Comment: The bots in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics which flag low-quality posts would be wonderful to integrate. They already have multiple heuristics for poor quality and anti-social behavior.

Answer (score 9):

I like that Stack Overflow is attempting to increase its already overwhelmingly inclusive approach to solving problems.

> ***The mentors help with question formation***

This is the only issue in my opinion, and it is certainly non trivial.

How? In the current framework how can mentors help with question formation?

If you can make this open to everyone in the community through improving the overall workflow that would be the ideal solution. Perhaps this would be in the form of sharing drafts and a new review queue.

In general, users at Stack Overflow *do* help with the formation of questions, through edits and comments. *The main problem with the workflow for questions of a questionable nature is that many question askers are not attentive*. It is a fire-and-forget process that is being used.

Getting a question asker (especially new ones) to realize that they need to be *immediately* attentive to their question, and also remain so for at least the next hour is very important. If creating a chat room that facilitates that interaction is the solution, then let's do it. But why should that singular chat room be any different than any other?

The approach of introducing a middle ground between question formation and question posting represents a barrier to asking. [We have had a discussion on this topic before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252061/1026459). The overall response was that a minor barrier would be ideal, but that there is a balance to strike between too invasive and too simple. I think that having a mentorship definitely falls on the invasive end as it essentially would imply to new users that if they did not take the mentor path and instead asked a question straight away then that was why their question was poorly received. I know that is more than likely not the reason, low quality content is never well received here, however perception is very important to new users.

From experience in chat, this could also quickly become a place where users simply ask their questions and attempt to get answers without posting - or worse get users to create their solutions. In other words, a haven for question banned users attempting to bypass their question restriction. These users would circumvent the intent of the mentorship as they are generally less interested in the process so much as simply having someone else do their work.

**Stack Drafts**

Similar to the creation of StackSnippets, there could be a StackDrafts. This could facilitate the sharing of drafts, allow a place for one-boxing, and get past the notion of a private area in order to allow the community at large to work on this. As well as a captch, anything at StackDrafts older than 60 days could be roomba'd - this would help to prevent abuse. It should also not be exposed to web crawling.

*What it could look like from the asker*

At any point during the ask question process, the asker may select a button that enters into mentor mode. **"Get Help From A Mentor"**. Clicking this button enters the question into a Mentor Review Queue (where the request is populated by a text input similar to the flag for moderator UI), enters the asker into a chat room for that question specifically, and also replaces the button area with some feedback about the current mentor status of the post.

**Overall layout with button:**

[image: Get Help From A Mentor]

**Modal for entering into mentor mode:**

[image]

**Status feedback for mentor mode**

[image: mentor mode status feedback]

*What it could look like from the mentor*

The mentor sees the request in the queue and then clicks to mentor the post. Clicking the request has two actions. 1) It enters the user into a post specific chat, 2) It navigates the user to a rendered view of the draft. The post looks similar to a deleted post, except with many features not present - essentially it is a raw view of the render of the saved draft. Editing is explicitly not here, as the user should be the one responsible for creating such content to avoid abuse and encourage learning.

[image: mentor POV]

*Who can mentor?*

Anyone. The mentor review queue will simply be a queue where a user can either "Mentor" which will then take the action noted above, or skip, in which case they may view another. This will also allow multiple users to mentor one post, which may be desirable depending on the technology involved. It may also make sense to instead go the route of requiring at least one tag be used, and then limit the mentors to users having at least a bronze badge in said tag.

This would be one way I could envision making this work without greatly influencing the existing tools already built.

Comment: "Get Help From A Mentor" = get someone to answer your question. This is how it will be read.

Comment: Can you think of alternative wording @Alex? The intent was to get someone to help compose the question.

Comment: Maybe "Get advice on improving this post".

Comment: I like that. Although it doesn't really mention the word "mentor".

Comment: Suppose you have a site moderation problem. You think to yourself, "I know! I'll use a review queue." Well, now you have two problems.

Comment: Can you explain what moderation problem you are referencing, and how using a review queue in this circumstance would not be beneficial @JoshCaswell?

Answer (score 7):

One of the challenges the community has (and one of the reasons why Meta exists) is that the community as a whole doesn't agree 100% on what constitutes a good question.  In some cases the differences are minor, but there are some can be polar opposites (code vs no code, what is a resource request, what is considered opinion based, are code review questions acceptable, any many more). *

So I see 2 possible issues arising due to this problem

- A mentor, believing one set of guidelines, helps a new user to ask a question in a certain way or give the impression the question is on-topic and acceptable.  But the community downvotes the question and the new user is still discouraged and is now mad at the mentor.
- 2 (or more) different mentors in the same room feel differently about a specific user's question and provide conflicting guidance.  The new user is still discouraged and is also confused.

This may be another scenario that you just have to wait and see how often this happens (the first bullet is almost guaranteed to happen, and the 2nd may be a problem as well, just less of an issue).  But I think it is something you need to be prepared to handle with guidance for the user on how to handle conflicting info or mentors who are just wrong about how to ask a good question.

Comment: Is "are code review questions acceptable" something that is actually debated? We have [CodeReview.se] for that.

Comment: @Scott Thank you for proving my point.. As someone witha close vote powers, i hope you are aware that just because a question is on topic onthe another site doesn't make out off topic here?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but my understanding was that code review questions were off-topic for SO. Do you have any links to discussion about this?

Answer (score 7):

I think I'm mentoring already for a very long time.

Often I comment on questions being new, kind of not very good but showing some potential instead of downvoting or closevoting them right away.

My comments aim at improving the question and/or making it acceptable. Quite often (say in ~50% of the cases) I get a response which (again in ~50% of these cases) results in an improvement of the question kind of making it acceptable. In other cases I may downvote the question later on.

Now this is much less effort than talking with every one before a question is posed because:

- I can decide which question has potential
- The comment system does not require me to be there the whole time (unlike a chat)

I would prefer that this avenue is explored more (more kind of reviewing with feedback instead of chat support) instead of the proposed feature. Maybe newly posed questions of new users or users with a bad track record should get into a special area first (think of quarantine) where the questions are scrutinized for validity instead of letting them free on the world the second the user clicks on "post my question".

In general I foresee a lack of available chat mentors. A human powered (for free) helpdesk for posing questions.. might not be possible.

Comment: Also the proposal reminded me a bit of the area 51 idea of Stackoverflow Academy.

Answer (score 6):

I like this idea in principle, but there's one thing that has me concerned about its long-term viability:

## Moving targets.

Stack Overflow is *complex*.  It's very much the case that moderation of question quality is not consistent or is very much [in a state of flux](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/352390/1079354) across disciplines.  Worse, it's applied unevenly; if you get a user asking for feedback on a question of type A *without* a "foo", you may get users who are accustomed to questions of type B which *very much mandates* a "foo".

I'd consider myself a high-rep user, and I'd consider myself capable of being a mentor to others.  I'm already a Comp-Sci tutor, and I have already mentored others on revolutionary career changes into software engineering.  However, I'm just not sure that I'd be able to mentor Stack Overflow beginners very well, because unlike tutoring or career mentoring, what's "best" for the protege or what the protege needs to do in order to be successful *here* often changes **by the hour**.

Either one of two things needs to happen before I'd say that this could work well:

- We need to shore up our moderation of questions *in general*, and have an easier-to-digest flow of what kinds of questions we think are good and which kinds we think are bad; or
- We need to have mentors who have *explicitly* demonstrated the capability of understanding the multifariousness of Stack Overflow's questions, and what barometer of quality is being expected of the protege at any given time.

One of these things needs to be stable for a new user to find lots of success on Stack Overflow, and I have my doubts for either.  I will remain optimistic for the latter, though.

Comment: We definitely have no illusions that this is long-term viable... it's meant to be a small and brief test through which we will hopefully gather lots of useful data. I like both of your suggestions a lot - we should definitely have clear definitions of questions that are good and not good, and we should make sure that mentors have the know-how to guide others. To be honest, I think this test may inevitably feel a bit wild-west-y. But thanks for sharing ways that we can try to avoid that feel.

Comment: This is essentially what I was trying to convey in my [2nd answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/353857/250725), but this is expressed so much better than my attempt.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with many of the concerns expressed, particularly those of a noisy chat room, new users not bothering to click a link, and untrained mentors.

Here are some I'm not seeing addressed:

- This sounds like a "done deal". As in even if someone [links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page) to a much better idea - even acknowledged by the OP in the comments - it won't stop this potential train wreck from falling off the cliff.

You have a problem. We have a problem. We *all* have a problem. Why implement a solution in a tunnel? If you want our feedback, at least don't make it sound like it doesn't matter.

- How will you define the success or failure of this? By participation in this single chat room? By the number of down votes on a new user's question?

Before implementation of a new feature, it's normal to define this.

- This isn't a repeat of my first point, instead it's asking why you haven't decided to *revamp* this "wall of text" into something more usable.

If there's something we all agree on, it's that it *is* a wall of text. You yourself used this as your first argument in your question! Now there's something you can do in a tunnel.

- My last concern is the lack of using rep in any way.

*"When we see a first-time asker in the Ask a Question page...people who volunteer to mentor (there are no rep minimums for this room)."*

This cuts both ways. I don't have much rep (compared to many here) but I have learned what makes a good question. While I can appreciated someone giving me constructive criticism when I eventually ask my first question, it's nice to know I'll be treated like some student who created their account today. (Not.) Even more, this student who may not know how to properly ask a question can work the chat room. (Ouch.) I did see something to suggest the question was edited on this - but I'm just quoting what I currently see.

My conclusion? You, we, all of us know there's a problem. I don't believe this will help much. But if it does or doesn't - can you tell me how you'll know? (Point #2.)

Comment: The concern about being "treated like some student who created their account today" seems unwarranted. If you don't want to ask for help formulating your question, then don't ask. Nobody is proposing to force first-time askers into that chatroom.  And by the way, reputation is visible in chat.

Comment: Good point, and I agree. Maybe I should edit my thoughts. Let me work through that concern and edit. My concerns are making a distinction on what a bot (or some other objective way) can suggest what I *should* do with my question.

Answer (score 6):

> What do you think about this idea?

Anyone who can be bothered going to a mentoring chatroom rather than banging a question down is likely to be writing good questions even without it, with the possible exception of indirect duplicates.

Which makes it futile in my opinion

Answer (score 4):

> What do you think about this idea?

I think it is great that you're trying to improve user experience for new users.  Unfortunately, I think this approach is not a very good one.

I would much rather see a revised "newbie" question form for new users (with an option to bypass it if you are familiar with SO), that holds their hands through the entire process, and makes it difficult to submit a poorly formulated question.

I'm not sure how this would be implemented, though.  Possibly by providing additional mandatory fields that would be incorporated into the final question (e.g. a field for MCVE, individual fields for "what is the problem you're trying to solve?", "what have you tried?", etc.).

> What concerns do you have with how we’re deciding to implement this initially?

- I think that the idea of a chat room will automatically invalidate
  this option for a significant portion of new users.
- As other users have pointed out, out of those users who are
  willing/able to visit a chat room, a significant portion will want to
  ask their question in chat, and have it answered in chat.
- Participating in this chat as a mentor sounds like a thankless, frustrating job that will quickly burn out those willing to participate.

> And most importantly: are you interested in volunteering to be a
>   mentor?

Sorry, but no.  I don't have the time or patience.

Answer (score 3):

Please disable chat-wide notifications when messages are flagged - either for the duration of the experiment, forever (...worth a shot), or even just for flags originating from the mentor room(s). These notifications are already an annoyance for many, and a room full of new people who understand neither established etiquette or the system they find themselves in will make the problem worse.

People who didn't sign up for this experiment shouldn't be bothered with its side effects.

Answer (score 1):

**Your** User Experience Research is for us to mentor noobs in chat?

*Sorry, I've got REAL problems to solve, no time to tweak some 12 year old's question on how to code his/her hobby project*.

---

Since you've asked the community to mentor, *which is usually a paid gig*, can we ask something better be built based on all the solutions here? You guys are awesome devs, do it with AI or something!!

**We've had this conversation so many times.** I feel it is a major concern right now.

You can see all the links here have great "User Story" value.
[Cody Gray started a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page) and I liked [this proposal for a question "menu"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327082/5897829).

Here are your concerns:

> They are too intimidated by the wall of text (or get distracted or any number of things) and they just don’t ask it
>
> They ask a question, but it’s badly formed and it gets downvoted or deleted or snarked at
>
> They ask a question, but it’s a duplicate and gets closed right away (which is good for SO overall, but probably doesn’t feel great in-the-moment)

This is one of the best ways forward, it's an answer with a score over 300: [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/495455)

The idea is making downvotes contain a reason why. I've used the reasons at @WillSullivan's http://idownvotedbecau.se/.

[image]

Getting Downvotes and not knowing why is frustrating. This would solve that and **give people feedback straight away, which would stop noobies feeling frustrated without even knowing why they suck**. Please fix this bit first.

<sub>- I would recommend downvote reasons be confidential - only the OP can see the reasons to avoid ["Group-Think"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupthink).</sub>

<sub>- The HTML div downvote popup is a Comment Bubble, also notice how the design is an architectural door open plan.. When the OP edits their question, then one would hope the downvote reasons start to be reversed/go away...</sub>

Comment: I suggest adding 'shown', 'displayed' or 'demonstrated' to some items, eg 'No research' and 'No debugging'.   This would be a defense against the 'I searched all over the internet and could not find any help' and/or 'I tried to debug it but could not find the problem' questions.

Comment: I was thinking that Will's project is hosted at GitHub so let the community set the reasons @MartinJames

Comment: I drew the red circle myself, honest!

Comment: Sorry, no 'freehand circles' upvote for you!  It's too well-drawn, and so some evil posters might think you used an ellipse tool:(

Comment: Hey!  That's a cheat edit!   Meh - have an upboat anyway..

Comment: -1 for not being `red` enough, too orange-y. Also @MartinJames what do you mean by an "upboat"? We do have a hairboat though.

Comment: Up voted just for the first phrase. Really strange outcome for a "UX researcher".

Comment: As much as people complain about downvotes without comments, they complain *way* more emphatically when they actually get comments to go along with their downvotes, even when they're constructive.  People just don't like being informed that they've done something wrong.

Comment: Other than the -2 rep (which doesn't affect new users anyways), how would this be different from close votes?

Comment: @Servy and, if all those commenting using the current system were to be honest, instead of continually have to l... be economical with the truth, most of the regular skilled and experienced developers that answer questions on SO would join me on the 'suspended for a year' hall of infamy.  It seems that anything other than total subservience gets flagged/meta'd as 'rude and abusive'.  I have a nasty feeling that canned downvote comments, and/or the mentoring room, would/will go the same way, no matter how it is handled:(

Comment: On principle I hate this idea; it takes away a long-held convention and it also means that if I really don't think your question/answer is just any good, you now get to start a pitched debate with me explaining *why* your question about why your code doesn't compile *isn't* that trivial.  However, I don't mind the idea of piloting this during a run like this.  If nothing else, we can pilot it, get the data, and put the whole notion to rest.

Comment: @Makoto, unlike commenting why you downvoted, this would be anonymous, thank you for having the mindset to try something, I think a lot of these ideas are worthy of AB Testing :)

Comment: Interesting... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: +1 for recommending some way to show downvote reasons

Comment: @Servy why did the answer I referenced state that noob's beg for a reason?

Comment: @JeremyThompson New users both complain when they don't get a reason for downvotes that they ought to get a reason, and then when they *actually do* get a reason, they complain *even more* and get even more upset than those that didn't get a reason at all.  I'm not saying that you're wrong that new users complain when they get downvotes for no reason, just that this won't fix the problem, it will just make it worse.

Comment: @servy, I love Stackoverflow, I don't think you count the 300+ link'd with much weight, but I do. I really DO care about this site. I'm so sick of the noob's. I'd love for a Stackoverflow noobs guide. I have changed my tune since this thread started: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298936/ and want something similar to [Google Chrome cool cartoon](https://www.google.com/googlebooks/chrome/)

Comment: Question askers aren't 12-year-olds. They're just no more *sensible* than 12-year-olds re technical contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Even this is a **good idea**, I don't believe that programmers or who wants to be a programmer need a better guide. Yes it might be harsh but doing research, trying to understand things is the part of the title. By doing this there might be problems like, *Mentors don’t actually answer programming questions in chat.*

**I think they will answer**

and chat will be an easier way to find answers for newbies or people who doesn't like to research.

Answer (score -2):

I think it's good idea, but the better idea would be to improve/implement the following things.

1. Make the Ask Question page more intuitive so that the user doesn't have to go through the getting started guide. For example, in the question page suggest and auto-correct titles using machine learning and AI. In the question body show the code window, text window, exception window, etc... (may be some intuitive drag-gable components) so that there is no need to format the code; it will automatically format it. Add spelling and grammar auto-correction.
2. Add a new user tab in the questions themselves and list all the new user questions there if the user is asking a question for first time or second time so the mentors can help and guide them easily.
3. Using AI or machine learning implement an engine which will find all the possible duplicate questions, and their related questions, and put it in a queue "Possible Duplicates". Now mentors or reviewers can guide the new user and close the question if it is a duplicate, this will also save the time of other users.

Comment: Why would those in particular be "the best"?

Comment: @KevinB, yeah it will not be a best Idea, but I think better than the posted in the question

Answer (score -3):

> What do you think about this idea? We’re just starting to put this test together and would love your feedback and thoughts - we want to give it as much likelihood to succeed as we can.

I think it's a great idea that stands a chance to help people get better technically while keeping in mind the goal of SO to exist as a collection of High Quality questions and answers, all this while also keeping tempers lower. 
**WIN WIN! :)**

> What concerns do you have with how we’re deciding to implement this initially? We’re trying to go as light on the technical requirements as possible, but we want to make sure we haven’t missed anything glaring.

Selection of mentors is **crucial**. The most technically advanced may not make for the best teachers. Unfortunately, there cannot be a one-size-fits-all to this, and only time and experience will tell. How much risk is Stack Overflow willing to take, considering that it is an experimental project?

> And most importantly: are you interested in volunteering to be a mentor? A project like this would never work without knowledgeable and experienced Stack users to actually do some mentoring. As this is a test, we’d probably also want to talk to you about your experience afterwards.

Heck, yes! I've taught small children professionally before, and I'm a big fan of the [ELI5](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/) subreddit.

Answer (score -4):

I understand this is probably going to be a poorly accepted proposal, but I'd just like to say this as someone who uses SO occasionally, and every so often tries to use it like I use other stack exchange sites (i.e., using it all the time) but fails.

Thinking about it, the size of SO, and the results coming from that, is what turns me off. Majorly. An analogy: I hang out on CS Educators. It's an incredibly welcoming community. First posts by new users will sometimes have three welcome comments. Downvoting happens, but users are encouraged to pop into a chatroom. Top users devote significant amounts of time to helping them and cleaning up the site. This is true of most beta sites I've been on. On Physics.SE, the site I'm most active on, things are a little less friendly, but it's still a really welcoming site.

Size is the difference. Beta sites are small, closely knit communities, but they are ready to help others into the fold. Sites that are of medium size like PSE are still friendly, but they've lost a little bit because they don't care as much about user count. SO is a downright jungle. It's massive. No one cares about user count at all, because there's so many already. People are frantically trying to keep quality at some kind of level, and turning off many people in the process.

People aren't to be blamed. Tons of junk shows up that users have to deal with. It gets annoying, aggravating, *painful*. Just look at SO's CV queue. I head over there just to smile whenever the PSE queue gets long-ish, because there's *thousands of questions in there*.

My solution is kind of crazy, probably never going to be accepted, but - split SO up. Have a Python site, a JavaScript site. Or, rather, maybe do this: SO for general programming, and then tags split off into sites of their own as they get big enough. Or perhaps, you could have all the web-development tags under one umbrella. Whatever.

The point is, it's already been done to some extent, and worked. Look at TeX & Friends, or Mathematica.SE. They're friendly, helpful communities. Then step back into SO and look at the LaTeX and Mathematica tags. Chaos. This in fact also fits into the work you cited on gender disparity on SO. The biggest thing cited? The large, overwhelming communities turned women off disproportionately in comparison to men.

I myself would be all for it. I'd love having a dedicated Python site. I already am active on the dedicated TeX (and Mathematica, though not as much) site. Please, look at what has already worked.

Comment: Something similar has been proposed before: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253824/is-it-a-good-way-for-stack-overflow-to-split-and-distribute-topics-over-differen

FWIW, I think it's great to share opinions even when you don't think they'll be well received.

Comment: You make some interesting points, heather, but they're only tangentially related to this mentoring experiment proposal, which may explain the downvote and current lack of upvotes on this answer.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment. I hang out in the [tag:processing] tag, and it's overall a more welcoming and "fun" environment than the [tag:java] tag. So what you're talking about already happens on a tag-by-tag basis. The problem is, the large tags (where most of the questions are anyway) are already "too large" by themselves, even if you isolate them.

Comment: @PM2Ring I think it's really relevant. I think that only changes like this one will really make it more welcoming for new users, and that's why I don't think this project is the right step.

Comment: @KevinWorkman indeed, that's true, but I think that just separating things, to some extent, from the flurry of SO would begin to help. Also, I think that it would help if (I know this is a meta tag) things were tagged beginnner/intermediate/advanced questions in a queue, meaning that users less willing to deal with new users could just ignore the beginner tag. That helps subdivide large tags further, and clean up old user/new user interaction a bit.

Comment: I'm sure that I would not learn so much from SO if the questions were split up by site instead of tag.

Answer (score -4):

Mentorship sounds great.

## But why are you trying to use chat?

Chatting is the wrong tool for the job. Using the current chat system will cause a lot of problems:

- There is no good way to reuse advice from chats. It's not easily searchable for newcomers. Mentors will have to keep re-explaining the same things.
- Chats are messy. Can you really handle the load of incoming questions? Certainly not in one chat room, unless the mentorship is ineffective and new users don't take advantage of it.
- Chats don't provide an isolated place to post the actual question. To review the question, you have a few options:

  - Put the question on the site and then refer back to it. Problem: other people on the main site will deal with the question in other ways (down votes, voting to close).
  - Put a lock on the question until the mentors have approved it. This is sort of acceptable, but might seems a bit of work to get right. If the page is public but not linked from other pages, then spammers can use it and lower traffic means it might stick around longer than on the main site.

I think it would be much better if we

## Create a dedicated SE site for mentoring questions

That's right. We already have a tool that can handle mentoring, and it's not chat.

**I propose that there be a new site: Questions.SE.** In this site, users would post their questions. Instead of answering the question itself, answers would be *reformatted versions of the question*.

- The gamification built into all SE sites would mean that there would be incentives for mentors.
- Bad questions are isolated from the main site.
- Comments, chatting, votes, votes-to-close, and flags would still exist. This means that mentors would have plenty of tools to deal with questions.
- It is scalable. If you want to use it as a sandbox for other SE sites, that's fine. That's what tags are for.

**How do we deal with trash?** This site would be a magnet for a lot of low quality content.

- Lower the spam/abusive thresholds to allow questions to be deleted quickly
- Maybe give high-rep users a new hammer: the unclear hammer. This would immediately put on hold questions that nobody can understand enough to rewrite.
- Have the roomba delete all questions that are not marked [good-condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/good-condition) after 2 weeks.

**So how are we going to get the new users to use this?** Here are my thoughts:

- Don't allow users to post to SO until they have posted to Questions.SE. Maybe redirect the Ask a Question page there.
- When the question on Questions.SE has been tagged by high-rep users with [good-condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/good-condition), then the question can be (automatically) asked on SO.
- Keep requiring users to go through this process until [insert-algorithm-here] decides that they can ask good questions. It would take into account their SO posts' score and the number of questions they have posted on Questions.SE.

  - If you're following the logic, yes this means that users who ask a few good questions and then start posting bad questions will be sent back to Questions.SE. I think this would be a good thing.

**How do we get mentors to use this?**

- Gamification, gamification, gamification. Who wouldn't want to earn rep on a site for re-writing people's questions?
- The kindness of their heart. The universe needs saving and *you can help*.
- To give back to the community.

After all, why would people answer questions on SO on the first place? The same things that inspire people to answer on SO will apply on Questions.SE. All that needs to happen is to spread the word to all the mentors out there and maybe offer a badge or two.

## Cons

- If somebody has the X/Y problem, I'm not sure how that would be dealt with. The site would be targeted at improving questions. Something like X/Y might not be figured out until people try to answer it.
- Duplicates need to be closed cross-site. I'm not sure how to give users a good way to search for potential dupes and flag. Or would we *want* dupes to make it to the main site to be signposts?
- Technical questions need to be technical. I suggested that users would be willing to help, but would enough users from *every tag* be willing to help? If not, how can questions in those tags be rewritten?
- Time. It would take some amount of time and effort for a new user to finally get their question asked on SO. The benefit is that the question *would be* a good question, but it would mean that a lot of new users would never get their question asked.
- If users are patient, they may never learn to write good questions. Just post to Questions.SE and wait for somebody to make it good for them. We can only hope that the delay inspires them to learn to write good questions for themselves.

Comment: But how are we going to get them to ask good bad questions on the new site? ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver I just realized I misread your comment. What do you mean by "good bad questions"? Do you mean questions that have the potential to be good? If so, the answer is you don't. Unsalvageable questions will always be asked. My ideas for dealing with them are in the "How do we deal with trash" part.

Comment: I was being funny.  If the OP has problems asking a good question here and then we want them to go to a different site to ask a question on how to ask a question here, how do we get them to ask a good question there?  So a good (for the new site) bad (for this site) question.

Comment: Ah. Well, the question the ask on the other site would not be a "how to ask" sort of question. They would post their SO question, in their words, and answers would be improved versions of the question. So _any_ question would be a good question there, as long as people can turn it into something that makes sense.

Comment: "So any question would be a good question there, as long as people can turn it into something that makes sense" So then, like, 10% of the questions, max.

Comment: If the OP only posts a nonsense and leaves, yes. Their feedback would be vital. Without the OP giving clarification of what they _mean_, the question will go to the great roomba in the sky.

Comment: This seems like too many steps/too much effort. The goal here is to improve the new user experience. Right now they come to a site and ask a question, and endure some level of obstacles before they get an answer. You want to introduce an entire extra website into that mix? They have to ask their question on multiple sites? Register multiple times? etc.? Integrating a toolset and workflow into Stack Overflow is a much better solution. Otherwise we will just see people flagging posts as "crappy, move to SOQuestions.SE" and no one bothering to answer questions on another site.

Comment: Question posters would just use it as an excuse to post even less-effort questions. I honestly would not know what to do about questions that are in worse shape than many on SO main - it's bad enough there.  Telling posters that they need to provide inputs, outputs, error-messages, test details and debugging info just gets you flagged or libelled on meta as a jerk/troll. It would be even worse on a 'Good bad question' site:(

Comment: @MartinJames At the same time, though, all that sort of commenting might be a good thing on this other site, even one of the main points. If you don't add all the necessary details, somebody needs to prompt you to. Of course, this means that new users can still get offended...

Answer (score -5):

My impression is that the principal problem is that new members of StackOverflow are able to ask a question from the moment of joining.

It is not uncommon to see just-arrived members asking fairly complex questions. My reaction is often: *what on earth are you doing asking others to help you with a question of that complexity when you've not helped a single other member with anything...?*

But of course, this isn't the new member's fault. The setup allows for it.

I'd be tempted instead to suggest that you can only ask a question when you have answered 5 or 10 yourself. (No matter whether your answers or accepted or not or even good or bad... what matters is that you at least show willing to want to try to help others before asking others to help you).

The process of answering 5 or 10 questions would give new members exposure to well-formed questions. Thus, by the time they asked their first question, they would already have an idea of how questions ought to be presented.

Comment: I think your idea has merit, but the implementation would lead to a whole lot more low-quality answers to low-quality questions.  The new user is burning to ask their question, and they'll rush through to answer the 5 easiest questions they find, which are likely duplicates or low-quality.

Comment: I wonder how much crap a simple time delay would cut out, e.g. not being able to ask a question within 24 hours of registering.

Comment: I take your point @silencedmessage, it's a good one - but it reinforces the idea that SO is a place where new users primarily sign up to have their questions answered. An alternative perspective - though not one that prevails at present - is that SO is a place where new users primarily sign up to share knowledge, teach, educate and help others. Guided by this perspective... the point where you need a question answered is really not the point to suddenly decide to become a new member of SO.

Comment: Perhaps the way to deter a barrage of low quality answers would be to require 5 upvotes on answers before granting question- asking permissions. That could be 5 upvotes on a single answer or one upvote on 5 separate answers (or anything inbetween)?

Answer (score -7):

**I keep going back to this idea ...**

A problem is defined by the root cause, therefore we need to examine the root cause ...

The problem isn't the number of questions or the quality of question.
The problem is that users aren't able to get the answers they need.
The symptom is the number of questions and flow of new users generating them.
You solve the issues the users are having & you solve everyone's problem.

*Note, it's not just new users, though they are the biggest group of those who suffer - also fixing that problem will probably remove the sockpuppet effect of people not staying with one user.*

I like that mentorship is on the ball!  I think there's two paths to this one.  First, exactly what you're doing.  Second, some reworks on the side bar - which is extremely helpful but doesn't honor the search bar preferences.

**Part 1:  Chatroom**

A chatroom with bot tools ...

- Make the first chat room they enter an interactive tutorial, allow them to try typing question & then give them alternative synonyms to use for those words - draw from the S/O db.  Then dump them into a moderated room if they are unhappy.
- Augment the mods with "quick replies"
- Cover any shortage by having the bot go into answering mode when all mods are idle or a question goes unanswered too long

**Part 2:  Sidebars**

Also, really would help reduce the work if there was some improvements to "Linked", or "Related" questions on the side bar.  If there's a better place to chat this one up - let me know too!

*Please note this scope only deals with the side bars linked/related questions section*

- Control of what a user thinks is important to be shown (perhaps re implement or apply the same search bar to the sidebars - doesn't have to be on by default - infact as working now, but the option to control if desired please!
- Ability to order the sidebar suggestions
- If possible track links followed already and either UI shows or auto-hide till user clicks unhide previously viewed option?
- Ability to go to a hierarchical tree (generated by categories or whatever metric you want?)...maybe cloud words of both subjects / synonyms or just lists by common phrasing.

Answer (score -12):

I think having a chat-bot kind of interface would be great like Siri. Of-course there will be lots of challenges. It should ask lots of trouble shooting kind of questions to the user and capture what they are looking for. If user is still not satisfied with the bot's answer, draft a SO kind of questions based on the communication and show it to the user if that is what they are really looking for. If yes then publish the same. Any ways SO has so many active members who will quickly look into the problem and possibly answer the same.

Interaction example would be

- **Bot**: How can I help you?
- **U1**: How to do xyz?
- **Bot**: What have you tried? ( or asks a better question)
- **U1**: I have tried xxx in python
- **Bot**: Which version of python?
- **U1**: 2.0
- **Bot**: It may not work as per my knowledge, try 3.6 version
- **U1**: It is a production system I cannot go to version 3.6
- **Bot**: Ok I will check if there are some good solution/workaround. If I understand your problem correctly this is your problem >>
  Problem detail <<  Please confirm
- **U1**: Yes, I would like to add that I am using windows 2000
- **Bot**: Oh! I missed asking that, will add that and post it in SO. Hope some expert will help you. Thank you.

Comment: Wow!! Down voters care to comment? @Kristina Lustig: Down-voting is also one of the thing that puts people off answering or raising a question. I guess you will have to dig into the huge data of SO and then come up with statistics such as what are the types of questions people ask or answer, understand the frustration shown in the comments etc. It will be a good data mining problem. You will be able to come up with lots of answer to improve SO. I still think my answer is good, unless somebody correct me.

Comment: Developing an artificial intelligence engine of a sufficiently high quality to be useful in this context is ***far*** outside of Stack Overflow's core mission. So while what you describe *might* be useful, it is far too theoretical to consider at this point, unless you happen to have some working code available in a GitHub repository. Apple spent many years and billions of dollars on Siri, and that's *after* they purchased her from her Norwegian parents. And then there's the fact that chat is a better way to present this type of AI than an interactive wizard on the Ask page.

Comment: Also, complaints about downvotes are one of the things that puts people off commenting on Meta answers.

Comment: Thank you Cody, these comments helps rather than simply getting downvotes. So it will be a good idea to have downvotes should strictly have a comment or it should reduce big point from the downvoters.

Comment: BTW having a bot, to start with a simple one, may not be difficult. I am sure there are lots of SO members who are proficient and willing to work on it. Let me see if I can also come up with something.

Comment: I'm not going to explain why I don't like this idea, beyond the idea of I work in voice recognition and text recognition - and I hate using Siri. I just wanted to point out that people downvote on meta without commenting [because they mean something different here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/meaning-of-downvotes-in-meta-vs-main-sites).  Also, [there has been a bit of discussion on requiring downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261173/how-do-we-avoid-downvotes-without-a-comment?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score -28):

I think those are great ideas. But here's something else that could work in combination of the chat.

I think that the best way to avoid bad questions would be a "forced to watch" video of 2-3 minutes before they can ask a question. The video should look a lot like those at lynda.com. A warm welcome with a bubbly personality and a quick explanation of what we expect from them. After watching the video, the user should have the choice to go a head and ask the question or go to the next video explaining the inner works of the website.

---

**EDIT**
In the light of all the downvotes I think I need to explain the idea a little more, LOL.

https://www.singlegrain.com/video-marketing/just-stats-science-video-engagement/

https://www.wyzowl.com/video-marketing-statistics-2016.html

There are a lot of online marketers research available explaining that.

> Before reading any text, 60% of site visitors will watch a video if available.

A video is a lot more effective as a tool than a wall of text. The idea is to call a lightbox upon clicking the ask button for the first time. The video starts right away with a welcome and a quick guide on how to ask a question. If the spoke person has a great personality he should be able to keep them all to the end. The research says that longer the video and fewer chances to keep them all the way to the end. So keep it short and fun all the way.

---

The reason I am pointing to lynda.com is that below their videos there's a line by line script highlighting what the video says. So somebody that can't hear or does not have any speakers can still follow what's going on.

The forced to watch feature ensures the user knows how to ask a question and what is expected from him in order to get answers. This feature can work with other suggestions here and should help a lot in the educational success rate.

If after watching the video the user still asks his question in a bad way, I am afraid nothing else will ever work to educate them. Only a closed question might get his attention on him doing something bad and want to learn what in order to get his answers.

Just my two cents ;-)

Comment: To the down voters, please comment on why you think this is a bad idea. Just curious. I really think a video tutorial with a warm welcome and basic guidelines would work great. It's also a good way to point out the mentor chat at the same time.

Comment: If you force people to watch a video they will just mute the videos sound, switch tabs to do other work and continue with the question after the video ends all without ever watching it.

Comment: Sure but if a user does that, he will also skip reading the rules and not click on the chat ... A user like that will ask his question no matter what.

Comment: @JoeW Or just leave and not ask their question.  Lots and lots of that one.

Comment: Just open a modal on the ask button with an auto play on the video and once it's finished give the choice to post or view the next tutorial. The first video would be a welcome and a quick guide on how to ask. User gets a great experience and results in a better rate of good questions no?

Comment: @PatrickSimard So you're saying that the people that skip reading the rules are going to skip reading the video, meaning the only people who'd actually benefit from the video are the ones already reading the rules.  So then, why bother with a video?

Comment: No I dont think so. Take a look at this marketing research https://www.singlegrain.com/video-marketing/just-stats-science-video-engagement/

Comment: "They also found that, before reading any text, 60% of site visitors will watch a video if available."

Comment: An average consumer wanting to buy a product may not be 1 on 1 comparable to a programmer wanting to ask others to help solve their problem. I also don't believe a video marketing company boasting that video marketing works. But luckily I've got nothing to do with marketing, so I may be wrong.

Comment: @PatrickSimard You're basically showing research that video ads get people's attention more than text ads.  That's certainly true.  It annoys people to no end to see them, but they will instinctively *react* to them, making them effective advertisements.  And note that those stats aren't saying that people are watching the video to the end, only that they're noticing that the video exists and seeing a few seconds of it before they're able to turn it off or tune it out.  That's...not what we're going for here.

Comment: Well if the "force" is the issue, I think we would still have a higher rate of educational success with a video upon first click. The chat can be introduced and the rules explained very quickly. There's a way to do this in a none intrusive way and still get a good benefit with no loss.

Comment: @PatrickSimard There are already lots of tutorials on how to use SO on youtube, for people that specifically want to get the new user information in video form, rather than text form, so that benefit *already exists*.

Comment: I agree but the video is not included in the flow process of a new user. The current flow looks a lot like this. The user has a question, goes on google and finds SO. The landing page is most likely a similar question but the user does not see how the answer can apply to his situation so he goes ahead and clicks "ASK". From there, they have a form and just fills it up. If we can insert a little education in this flow, it would be on the click of the ASK.

Comment: @PatrickSimard As you can see from this question here, that's not true.  When the go to ask a question they're shown information on how to ask a question. But people don't care, they just want to ask their question, so they ignore the information shown.  They're going to do the same with a video, for the same reasons.  If you try to force them to watch it, they'll just get annoyed and either leave, or have a strong dislike to the site for making them sit through it.

Comment: `Before reading any text, 60% of site visitors will watch a video if available.`  I must be one of the 40%.  I would much rather read about something than have to sit through a video to explain it to me.  I often skip video based stories or tutorials, opting for something written.  Only advantage video has in my eyes is you show "actions" better.  But anything else is just a waste of my time.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm getting old, but I'm also allergic to sites that force me to watch videos. Also, not everyone around the world has unlimited downloads, some people don't like their precious megabytes being chewed up by videos.

Comment: I think making a video available is a good idea. I often prefer to watch a video than read a page of text. However, if a website tries to *force* me to watch a video, I'm gone. You won't be able to effectively force users to watch your video, but you will effectively annoy a large percentage of those who hit the page.

Comment: @Servy I don't think you can argue that the existence of advice on how to use SO on YouTube creates the kind of value that an (optional) video on the "How to Ask" page could potentially provide.

Comment: said statistic (60% prefer video if available) may not be representative of the audience that SO has. (or maybe it is, who knows. it hasn't been measured tmk.) I much prefer something i can ctrl+f. I do know that there is an audience here for video content, but, i disagree with forcing it being at all useful.

Comment: While video content and help is likely useful, we have absolutely no plans to force users to watch a video to participate.

Comment: Well with out forcing them you can still put one in. Anyway, I still think 1 video will have more impact than a link on the side for a chat room. Not that it won't make an impact but most of them might not even notice it. Their main focus will be on the form it self and the submit button.That's why I was suggesting the ask button.Perhaps add a button "Don't watch and post my question" under it?

Comment: I think this is a terrible idea, but it also points out the problems of the original idea. If people don't want to read a wall-of-text, and don't want to watch a video- why do we think they'd want to enter a chat room and discuss how to improve their question? I'm upvoting you just for pointing this out.

Comment: Forced to watch video sounds a great way to reduce cases 1-3, with the unfortunate side effect  of reducing 4 as well

Comment: If a site starts auto-playing a video (especially with sound) my immediate reaction is to close it as quickly as possible and never return.