# Add a "preview and review my question" option to the ask question page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, mentoring

With the idea of mentors and chatrooms for mentoring ([Stack Overflow Mentorship Research Project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353845/stack-overflow-mentorship-research-project)) I stumbled upon the idea of having a "preview and review" mode for questions.

The idea is, that a new user (or any user even) can first put his question into a "get help" or "get your question reviewed and improved" queue (I don't have a good name yet) where the question is automatically posted in a chatroom for mentors, linking to a new chatroom with his question.

The mentors can then join that chatroom, and the user asking the question can seek guidance and tips from the mentors that check his post out. The post can the be improved before even being shown to the queue and getting destroyed by downvotes for simple, silly mistakes or bad formatting/tagging/etc.

The user can then decide to "really" post the question and the question gets publicly visible and into the new page.

What do you think?

This would obviously be a big chunk of work to do for SO, but I think it would improve the original mentorship idea a *lot!*

---

This would probably reduce the time needed to be a mentor, since the question is already there, and can be directly improved with little redundant interaction (or atleast you can mark them, that would also be an idea).

When you have a chatroom, I fear many people would just post their questions in chat, instead of expressing their questions, and ask for tips. With a already existing question, much noise gets removed from the chatroom and the help can be more direct and rewarding.

Comment: I don't think it should be a question audition, just guidance - you can't predict what will happen to the question once it has been posted

Comment: You're right, maybe the direct audition with edits isn't that helpful.

I still think direct access to the (not yet publicly posted) question would greatly improve efficiency for mentors

Comment: If this includes a direct communication between a mentor and a asker, we should make sure that this feature is not misused to get direct answers for bad questions. The communication should only be about the quality of the question, not about the actual problem the user asks.