# Ability to comment without 50 points given previous engagement with tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, comments

I have checked similar posts and haven't ran across the exact same thought, so hopefully this question/thought won't get flagged as a duplicate.

Is it possible to loosen constraints on new users so they may comment on topics with matching tags to questions said new users have previously asked? If so, would it be worth it?

It may be beneficial to all users users involved if they had the capability to assess how correctly or incorrectly new members were learning and set them straight before they form bad habits or thought patterns.  This would provide the new users with more reward in up-votes and the ability to exercise fresh knowledge.

Experienced users could also gain the novel opportunity to observe the early development of the newest members in topics relevant to their avenues of study.  I am all for people paying their dues, and look forward to earning 50+ points soon myself.

What are your thoughts, comments, and criticisms of this idea?

Comment: You might be interested in this: [Stack Overflow Mentorship Research Project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353845/stack-overflow-mentorship-research-project)

Comment: But 50 rep to comment is more about preventing spam than paying dues. Comments can only be moderated by diamond moderators and they aren't rate limited like questions posts.

Comment: @BSMP Thank you. The link you shared is quite interesting and I will definitely be spending some time there.  I can imagine being involved in keeping a site this size spam free would be a daunting task.

Comment: There is no rep requirement for answering. And I don't see how being able to comment helps anything you've listed above.

Comment: A lot of experienced users already have the novel opportunity to observe early development of the newest members. It's called the [/review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) queue .... many have given up on those (see the close vote queue as a grim excess)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand precisely what you're proposing. You think we should modify the commenting privilege so that users with <50 reputation can comment on questions with certain tags? What, exactly, would determine "previous engagement" with those tags?

I have an idea—perhaps we could go by posting well-received questions or answers with those tags. Quality of reception could be determined, as is our usual practice, by upvotes. Say, 5 upvotes and you are given the ability to comment.

Oh wait…that's exactly what we already do! 5 upvotes == 10 reputation × 5 == 50 reputation == commenting privileges. And those are commenting privileges *everywhere*, rather than just on certain tags.

A bit less sardonically, what I'm saying is that the system really considers 50 reputation to be a minimum bar. Prior to 50 reputation, it's likely that you aren't really accustomed to how Stack Overflow works and how/why it's different from other sites on the Internet, so you might be tempted to use comments inappropriately. We have a strong desire to channel users (new and old) towards the answer box. Comments are really only there to provide an escape hatch in the event that something goes wrong—a question is unclear, more information is needed, etc. I don't think we're losing that much by restricting the escape hatch only to those users who have been around a while.

> It may be beneficial to all users users involved if they had the capability to assess how correctly or incorrectly new members were learning and set them straight before they form bad habits or thought patterns.

Except that, new users who have <50 reputation aren't really the ones we want to be guiding *other* new users, since, as I stated above, they probably haven't been around long enough to really understand our model and what makes us different.

There are probably a few exceptions—longtime lurkers, for example—but I don't feel this is a case we need to optimize for. It isn't that difficult to post a handful of well-received answers and get full commenting privileges. You can do that within a single day of activity.

> This would provide the new users with more reward in up-votes and the ability to exercise fresh knowledge.

Upvotes on comments don't get you anything. Well, maybe a badge, but not any reputation.

And we'd prefer that you exercise your knowledge by providing answers.

> Experienced users could also gain the novel opportunity to observe the early development of the newest members in topics relevant to their avenues of study.

I don't understand what this means. Why do I need the opportunity to observe this development through your leaving of comments?

Comment: "You must have at least 5 reputation on Stack Overflow to answer a question on meta."  One hour after I posted this question someone found my tumbleweed question on the regular end of Stack Overflow and downvoted it, causing me to loose 2 of my measly 6 reputation points.  "Observe the early development of the newest members."  You said you don't understand what that means.  I think I just figured it out.  I will take your advice.  I will answer questions and hope I don't have any that haven't been asked yet.

Answer (score 0):

If they have been asking a ton of crap questions on a specific tag, why should they be allowed to comment? If they have been asking some quality questions (in one tag or over a range of tags) they should already have gained 50 reputation from upvotes and be able to comment.