# How to better handle the current flood of VLQ questions?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, quality-improvement

There were already a few very good related posts, which have asked why the quality of posts is dropping and why high rep users post fewer answers (which I think are related to each other):

- [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/3933332)
- [Question quality is dropping on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252506/3933332)
- [Are high-reputation users answering fewer questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252756/3933332)
- [The Stack Overflow homepage is over-emphasizing bad questions (and a proposed solution)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258699/3933332)

All of these posts are now over a year old and my question(s) are:

- What progress did we made with handling VLQ questions?
- Did we even start doing something?
- What are we going to do in the future to handle VLQ questions?

All of the linked posts above are, from my perspective, ***yelling* to do something**, but I have to say I didn't see much that has drastically changed. I still have the feeling this problem is as big as, if not bigger than, it was a year ago.

Comment: *"do more stuff to keep users who care about the site here"* - sounds good, but: *how?*

Comment: I absolutely agree that some of the moderation tools should be improved to be able being match about that overwhelming, and growing VLQ flood arriving.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's what's the question about IMHO. Getting ideas, what could be improved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Stack Overflow homepage is over-emphasizing bad questions (and a proposed solution)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258699/the-stack-overflow-homepage-is-over-emphasizing-bad-questions-and-a-proposed-so)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes it is difficult, but I think a good start would be to  try to show them only "good" questions, which they are interested in and give them more power to handle LQ questions. So they can spend more time on interesting questions instead of cleaning up the crap.

Comment: And how do you determine which are good, without also looking at the bad ones? You've posted quite a lot of text, but frankly not much in the way of new, practical suggestions.

Comment: Hey, this is a blog post in disguise, not a meta-question. Shoo.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's intended. I know it is hard to define if a question is good or not. But I wanted to get some input from other users, which are maybe a bit long on SO than I am. That is also not my main nor my only question here. So I wouldn't ask here if I knew the perfect solution here..

Comment: *"not my main nor my only question"* - what is? This is meta, but a focused, answerable question is still helpful!

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I can't agree with you, since I don't see how this should be a blog post. I'm asking here a question about Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is a lot of opinion and very little actual information. As it's written now, it reads basically like a bit of a rant and a lot of statements without facts, doesn't really seek any specific input ("give me some input about maybe changing some things to fix this really broad list of things I think might be wrong but can't really prove"). There's really nothing specific in this post to discuss that hasn't been discussed before.

Comment: @jonrsharpe My question is if we made any progress or what we changed, since the related questions, which are over a year old. I'm also asking for which group Stack Overflow is going to choose/wants to keep, since sometimes I have the feeling SO doesn't do much to keep users who care about the site. And the direct question is: (If I'm not the only one who sees things this way) **What are we going to do here and now against these problems?**

Comment: That's *three questions*, which makes it a little difficult to answer. Could you pick one, and edit the question accordingly?

Comment: @KenWhite *been discussed before* Yes, but **did anything happened since then?** As from my perspective not much or am I missing something, the problem(s) are still there

Comment: @Rizier123 Well both the H&I and Triage were both implemented after those posts as a way to stem the low quality items from clogging up the home page.

Comment: @bluefeet Yes, but sadly I don't feel much to any improvement of quality. If I would have to describe my current situation here on this site: *"I'm feeling like a warrior fighting with the last breath against LQ, before I'm dying and drown in the hill of LQ questions!"*

Comment: Nothing has happened, because a) there's no evidence of an actual problem, and b) like you, no one has provided either factual data to indicate there is a problem to fix or suggestions on how to fix these *problems*. The solution to bad questions:  1) vote to close them, and 2) downvote them to speed their removal from the site. We're bound to get more and more bad questions; more and more people are discovering the site, students are still going to class and expecting us to do their homework, and there are tons of copy/paste programmers out there that have no actual knowledge.

Comment: @KenWhite a) Well that is kinda disappointing, but also shows that maybe I'm the only one who sees this.. b) I think it is hard to get "real" data about this, as hard as it is to decide if a question is good or not. But http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252757/3933332 This has some real data in it. 1 + 2) Well that is the 1:5 which I mentioned in my question. AND getting all these comments *against* my question clears also some things for me: 1. Maybe I'm the only one with this perspective 2. I see for which group SO has decided

Comment: @Rizier123 The volume is an issue, and over time very few high-rep users continue answering in the same volume as their early careers if only because they become busier with moderation and "soft contribution." I noticed  you quickly after you started here because the PHP tag has a very long history of new users bursting onto the scene with tons of answers, but either being chased off by zealous closers or or burning out on posting mediocre answers to weak questions. But you post _good answers_ and _have not burned out yet_. ...cont'd...

Comment: So please keep doing what you are doing, posting consistently good answers, and don't feel bad when you reach a point that you begin to answer less because your moderation is probably more valuable even if less visible. Taking myself as an example, of late I may answer just 1-2 times per week, but I spend loads of time commenting to draw better questions out of the OP.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yeah I think the keyword is: *yet* ... I watched the last 60k PHP questions and didn't missed a single one(<- literally). And since a few months I'm also in the [top 30](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/topusers). But the amount of good questions is just going down.

Comment: Are the amount of good questions going down, or, are the amount of bad questions going up.

Comment: _@Rizier123_ At some point I have too agree with @MichaelBerkowski's comment. The tags you're participating may be especially exposed to this experience. But as being here a bit longer, and almost solely participating the [tag:c++] tag, I also experience increasing crap posts and it's getting more work to handle these, instead of giving answers.

Comment: @KevinB Sadly I think both are going in the wrong direction. The bad questions are going up like twice as fast as the good questions are going down.

Comment: Please stop adding to the end of the post and **edit it down**. If the key question is what's changed in the last year, then just cover that!

Comment: @Rizier123 I understand your frustration because was in the exact same position you're in back in 2012, answering very frequently, and at the top of the PHP 30 day list, beginning to feel crushed under the load. There is always typically just 2-3 really active (and _good_) answerers in PHP, and over time they move more toward moderation as someone new comes in to answer as you have this past year. Your contributions in either side context will add lots of value -- at some point you have to allow yourself to step away from the tag's feed though :)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I always try to fight against these: "How to do this" questions and get the asker of the question to show his work and some effort. To make sure I'm not just doing his work and we don't mutate 100% to a code writing service on SO. Also with seeing the code from the asker I can better see where he got stuck and maybe what I have to explain a bit more than other things. But I can't win this fight, since sadly there will always be someone which just post a code only answer.

Comment: I had this same sort of.. issue before when i used to follow the jQuery and javascript tags. I solved it by not following those two tags, and instead specializing in related sub tags such as loopbackjs nodejs and ajax.

Comment: @KevinB I'm kinda doing something similar already, by searching interesting and well asked question with the search page. To get a little "challenge" for myself and so I don't forget how a good question looks like. But this always takes a long time to dig out/find and most of the times the posts are already pretty old and I rarely get response from OP. (Just a little example, where the post isn't so old and I even got response from OP: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30055004/3933332 , to see what I mean with this) (But I still read *every* PHP tagged question :)

Comment: The point of dropping javascript and jquery from my favorites tags was so that i **wouldn't** read through every jquery and javascript tagged question, that's always going to result in seeing an awful lot more VLQ questions than good questions. that can't be fixed other than by removing the ask question button.

Comment: I told you that was a blog post. Just look at the number of comments and the lack of answers. What do you mean, we closed it? Of course we did.

Comment: What "current" flood? It has been on full blast for years now. The trick is making sure that you don't stick your head in it too deep.

Comment: @TravisJ *Wups* I think I jumped into it. *The trick is making sure that you don't stick your head in it too deep* Well that kinda worries me and shows, that we can't do anything against it and just have to watch out, that we don't get drowned by it?!

Comment: @Rizier123 - In all honesty, yes, that is what you have to do. There are so many reasons why it can't be stopped, but a very large one is that the site is driven by being able to ask questions so there needs to be an easy path towards doing that and the assumption is that in good faith good questions will be posted. Clearly this isn't always the case :) But restricting that aspect of the site risks going to far in the other direction and preventing good questions. I think it is really impressive what you have done in the past 9 months, just try to stay positive and optimistic. Ignore the cruft

Comment: @TravisJ Seems like I have to fight in this endless fight which I will lose over and over again. It's just like live, (*but I thought programming was different*.) And as from the comments above I think I guessed wrong. So the end result would then be to stay alive until you drown in the LQ questions. (Good thing I can swim well)

Comment: @Rizier123 Well, I have been comfortising myself having a good shot of whiskey before looking at the incoming questions, to leverage my frustration. I'm trigger happy with down, close and delete votes for crappy quesitons, and pick a corn to swallow and answer some times.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well I would really like to do the same and it's a good idea :) But to legally drink whiskey I'm too young..

Comment: @Rizier123 You could use marihuana (cannabis) instead (I don't know the actual age recommendations). It's less intruding your health (I'm doing both ;-)  ). Anyway using drugs to get onto higher barriers of frustration level, certainly isn't good advice (especially for youngsters). I personally need both to keep up a reasonably calm communication level at VLQ posts.

Comment: So now the discussion has devolved to discussing whether to drink whiskey or smoke weed before reviewing questions... I'd reiterate my comment from before about this post having no relevance here, but apparently it would be less well received than before through the haze. :-)

Comment: While I have to say that the previous edit was a bit extreme, you may want to consider cutting down the fluff a bit. The question in it's current form is hard to read, unclear and seemingly unfocused. Perhaps consider cutting it down to the essentials yourself?

Comment: @Bart Yep that was a bit extreme, but I rewrote my question, to hopefully address only the essential parts of my question. And to make it easier to read

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256657/lets-give-very-trusted-users-a-closehammer-to-go-with-their-dupehammer

Comment: @Will Thanks for posting that :) I forgot to look on meta SE, since I'm not active there. But yes that would help a lot!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ *a good shot of whiskey* Well now I finally understand why this guy asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30513195/3933332

Comment: @Rizier123 Thank god I don't program PHP. That would increase my stress level seriously ;-) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well I think the end result of this question is just *Deal with it* I guess. There won't be much change, so that you can easily fight against VLQ questions. But I will still fight against it and won't look away :)!

Comment: @KenWhite *Nothing has happened, because a) there's no evidence of an actual problem, and b) like you, no one has provided either factual data to indicate there is a problem* - if lots of people saying there's a problem, repeatedly over lots of time, and the linked posts saying there is a problem get >2,500 upvotes combined and in your own comment you *yourself* describe the problems - all that *is* evidence, even if it's not a peer reviewed study.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I think I finally know what you mean with *"new users bursting onto the scene with tons of answers, ...chased off by zealous closers"*. I think I have seen that now quite a few times ;) (There is always a lot to clean up after such a user) But I'm not sure if that is still the case: *"But you post good answers and have not burned out yet"* I feel like I'm contributing (posts and moderation) a lot less than I did at the start. Moderation seems to come a lot with frustration :) and I don't know what comes after that. And if I'm still at the same valuable level as at the start.

Comment: @Rizier123 Has it been a year since this discussion? I don't know what comes next either - maybe it comes & goes in waves. I answer maybe 2-3/month now and don't spend much time in /review because I don't really have the time to spend. Eventually I will have time again. Backing away a little is preferable to burning out though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the weapons we have at hand to fight VLQ posts are (in my preferred order)

- Close vote the question/delete the answer
- Down vote the question/answer
- Find an appropriate duplicate question and close the question
- Delete the question/answer if it's not valuable for future research

I have all of the privileges as mentioned above, and I use them.

Though I'm restricted for the number of

- Close votes
- Down votes
- Delete votes

I can apply every day.

Sometimes I'd wish I'd have more powers without restricted numbers of any votes, but that's actually unlikely being implemented.

You'll just need to calm down, and consider voting the next day.

With that sense in mind, it's a well implemented restriction of SO.

Comment: I rewrote my question to boil it down to the essential things. So if you want to edit your answer according to my edit, just to notice you here.

Comment: I think several people have expressed interest in a combined downvote-close-delete feature that allows you to express your opinion that the question is to be deleted without having to visit it twice. I doubt that will be implemented, though, since it may be considered too obnoxious.