# Two little things against the flood of very low quality (VLQ) questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, low-quality-posts, quality-improvement

A while ago I asked about the progress against the flood of VLQ questions: [How to better handle the current flood of VLQ questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295501/3933332)

Apparently there wasn't much changed to handle VLQ questions, or I just think it's not enough. So I thought I would bring in two little things, which could help to handle and prevent VLQ questions.

1. Can we please change the **edit** button for new users and write it in bold? I see that so many times, and I think you all know it what I mean, [when](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30918290/3933332) [a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30489003/3933332) [user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30489158/3933332) [just](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30273838/3933332) [doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30572480/3933332) [know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30687648/3933332) [how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30707088/3933332) and where to edit his own question and then posts additional question stuff as answers.

   Like just change it a little bit maybe; it doesn't have to be much:

   [image]

   So that new users see the edit button better, and they don't post question stuff as answers. (This maybe doesn't prevent VLQ questions directly, but maybe one or the other user can then edit their question and make it better instead of leaving the site frustrated because of the delete votes (DVs) and close votes (CVs), and he didn't even know how to edit his question).
2. Give users more close votes! I know this question was already discussed a few times before, but it's just reality, that the flood of VLQ questions is just getting bigger and bigger, but the people who do something against these questions still have the same small tools. So I would suggest to give more close votes to people, so that they get bigger tools to handle the bigger flood of VLQ questions. I would have two ideas:

   1. Change it like it is with the amount of flags, which you have (*you get one bonus flag per 2000 reputation points*, *up to 100 flags per day*). So you would start at 30 CVs and for every 2k reputation points you get one close vote more. Maybe not until 100, but at least up to 50, if not even higher. I think you use many more close votes than flags per day, but you can flag more posts per day than you can close.
   2. A user which has a gold badge on a tag gets like 10 close votes more for this tag per day. I think a user with a gold badge has good knowledge about the tag and also practiced for a while to get that badge. So he should know what he's doing there and with the additional votes he can help to close VLQ questions.

So are these two things something which can get implemented? And if yes, can we please implement them? I think this would be two small steps to handle the flood of VLQ questions.

---

So that we don't get too many: "Yes, I want that" or "I don't want that" comments I thought I would post two strawpoll links here to get the opinions from all users and that I get a rough idea if I'm the only one which agrees with me:

- [Edit button in bold](http://strawpoll.me/4575870)
- [More close votes](http://strawpoll.me/4575893)

Comment: My first reaction was, if someone is unable to find the edit link below their question, they probably shouldn't work with computers at all, and certainly not be programming. But then again, the links are just small grey texts, so adding a bit of visibility might help. I would choose to either underline them (like actual links) or style them as buttons. Anyway don't make them more visible per se, but make them look actionable instead of plain text.

Comment: @GolezTrol *shouldn't work with computers at all* I would love to totally agree with this, but as much as I want, it seems like soo many users just doesn't find the link. And I think we just have to underline them / make it more visible for new users. If you know where the link is or found it once you know where it is and it could be like the other links (share, flag, ...).

Comment: By the way, I often still have trouble finding the right close vote reason. Often I just want to select *"This is a VLQ question, and if you look into your own heart, you know it is, so please go away or try harder."*

Comment: @GolezTrol Yes I know exactly what you mean :) (Would be a new close vote reason: http://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats )

Comment: Maybe there could even be some hints in that area, for instance some hints and notifications for new users that says: *"You're posting a comment to your own questions, but did you know you can also edit (arrow to/highlight of edit links) your question if you want to add information?"* A hint like that could show for a limited number of times and/or disappear when a user get X points, or receives an [Editor] badge. But that would obviously be a *lot* more work than removing `text-decoration: none` from the style sheet.

Comment: I'm often posting comments, that actually contain a link to the [`edit`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/296383/edit) button, after users posted code or lengthy clarifications in comments. That's a bit tedious. I totally agree, that most of the new users, simply don't get how the game of improving their questions works.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm already at that point where I provide them with a **bold edit** link for them, so that they see it clearly. Because I already had it, even if I gave them the link, that they didn't saw it in my comment.

Comment: @Rizier123 My point is: Those _"toddlers"_ won't see or read anything we say to them. They're so deep impacted to get a solution (most probably _"urgent and asap plz"_) for their problem, that they totally oversee how the system works out with their questions, comments or even answers they'll try to use to put more (mostly useless) information. The only way, we really have at hand is give them a ["saftige Watsch'n"](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/watschen). /Continued ...

Comment: @Rizier123 ...  I'm sad about this, because I'm basically a non-violent person, but even latest studies I've heard of, seem to improve that this gains the better learning effect.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The thing which I'm worried the most right now is, that no mod will ever response here and say if it gets/can get implemented. So we would talk here all day long, but at the end nothing gets changed.. (Must aber auf passen, wenn du den eine Schelle gibst, dass du keine anderen Gehirnzellen abtötest :)

Comment: @Rizier123 _"Must aber auf passen ..."_ Ja scho, a g'scheide boarische Watsch'n haud scho ganz schee nei ;-)

Comment: @Rizier123 _"The thing which I'm worried the most right now is, that no mod will ever response here and say if it gets/can get implemented. "_ Well, they can at least set the [tag:status-declined] tag, if they totally disagree. That's most you can hope for feature-requests, as from my experience.

Comment: We need a [Haltenhammer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256657/lets-give-very-trusted-users-a-closehammer-to-go-with-their-dupehammer) to go with our closehammer.

Comment: @Will As from you post it looks like a [_Himmler_ hammer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Himmler), but nevermind, we need that, yes. (What's actually wrong with me, seemingly being thinking in these _Nazi_ categories? My generation is soo spilled :-( )

Comment: @Will Yes we need that. So do we get it :)?

Comment: @Rizier123 Probably not, and probably for good reasons.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to (also) link the number of cv's per day to the experience you have with the cv queue instead of (only) reputation?

Comment: @LisaMM Yes, that would be also something which can be taken in consideration how many CV's you then have.

Comment: Its not that they cant find it.  The problem is that they dont care.

Comment: @GolezTrol "Maybe there could even be some hints in that area..." -- this is a great idea that deserves a post of its own.

Comment: My humble suggestion for drawing attention to the edit button would be to use the `<blink>` tag.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Almost a month is over, no declined or accepted, as I thought it would be. This kinda confirms for me, that they don't bother too much to do something against VLQ and want to keep the "good" people.

Answer (score 25):

I do not think changing the edit link from edit to **EDIT** will solve the problem you have addressed.

I also would take issue with nothing being done. There are several new review queues which were created *specifically* to address editing these types of questions.

The main problem you identify is new users responding to comments in the answer box. This makes absolute sense though if you take a minute to look at a post's layout after the question was submitted. The edit button is *above* the comments so if they scroll, they may miss it entirely.  Naturally the place to respond seems like the same place they already entered their information into previously - the editor is now a little familiar to them.

While we all know that "Your Answer" is meant for you know, an actual answer, to users who may not speak English as their first language "Your Answer" could potentially read as a place for them to respond as well, especially to comments.

I think that something more significant than bolding the edit link should be done to drive new users to the edit screen. Perhaps even going so far as to simply place them in the edit interface when they post their question as opposed to bringing them to the actual question page.  Perhaps not even allowing self posted answers from new users and just showing the edit question dialogue in the space of post an answer. Perhaps something else, but if the page is going to be altered, bolding edit doesn't seem to be enough.

Comment: How about adding a "clarify post/question/answer" link next to the "add a comment" link for the poster, or maybe even for everyone?

Comment: @Deduplicator - Sounds interesting. One issue I have with comments in general for new users is that it isn't made clear at all to them that they can still comment on their own posts. I think on average new users may have already tried to post a comment somewhere before posting a question but failed due to the less than 50 reputation. This could potentially lead them to believe they cannot comment anywhere (even on their own post). So if they had an alternative route near the comment button, I think that may be a possibility to allow them to make a connection between replying and editing.

Comment: @TravisJ You mention some good points in your answer. But I think we can both agree, that a little change could help :) As you said *Perhaps something else* so I just wrote the idea for bold, but I'm also open for any change to make it more visible for new users, e.g. change the "Your answer" button to "I found the solution to my problem" button. Something like this. (What about the long discussed: "more close votes", would you agree with me or am I the only one here with this?)

Comment: @Rizier123 - I don't think the more close votes addresses this side of the coin. Which is to say we are addressing fixing these questions, preferably with the OP doing the work and not the community. Close votes addresses nixing these questions, with the community doing the work and the OP doing nothing. So, that is a different topic really. But to get into a slight tangent, I do not think more close votes will help much because I don't think a significant amount of the community uses all of theirs on a daily basis. I also do not think more close votes would hurt anything.

Comment: Keep in mind that there *is already* a pop-up when a user tries to add an answer to their own question, asking if they're sure they shouldn't hit Edit instead.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I wouldn't be aware of that. Is there really already a pop-up which asks the user if it shouldn't be an edit?

Comment: @Rizier123: Yes, there is. I think you can even try it here.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I think then we would be at that point where we have to ask if we have to change something to get it more effective or if just a group of users just doesn't understand it?!

Comment: @NathanTuggy Ah you're right I can test it (Never tried that or used it before). And now I don't really know what to say. I think the dialog is very clear! And I don't think we can change much more than that, because this is already pretty clear. (Maybe removing the `text-decoration: none` makes it a bit more clearer). But all in all I think I have to say since this dialog already exists there is just a group of users, who will never find the edit button. (And then I sadly have to say, I don't think there will be much left other than just flagging it as NAA)

Comment: @NathanTuggy - Keep in mind that any barrier that can be bypassed by a single click will be bypassed by new users. I doubt they even read the dialogue if at the end of the sentence is "Okay" ("Yes" in this case). They are after-all in a massive hurry. Maybe that link should instead say "Edit your question" for them, and if they click it without confirmation it will just take them to the edit screen.

Comment: @TravisJ *Edit your question* That would be hilarious also then to see how many users "fall for it" :) Maybe that's the way to go here.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - But the thing is users *may* figure the box out, just not quickly enough. They are still getting used to the software at this point. While we may not be able to help these users, the community spends *a lot* of time trying to and any angle available to use in order to save the entire community of time should at least be examined instead of just instantly dismissing it.

Comment: @TravisJ: I would support measures to speedily reject questions asked by such users in favor of reeducating them. "Cannot even read bolded headers, or the descriptive buttons, or *anything at all*, in a short dialog box" is a pretty good example of an unwitting help vampire; we want them accurately identified and gently-but-firmly turned away. That's someone who will make very-low-quality posts.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - Everyone starts rough. Helping them get a smoother start to the site will help reduce the amount of low quality posts. For some people they struggle with formatting, others with posting duplicates, others with posting incomplete information. All of which need edits to fix formatting, explain why it isn't a duplicate (or just get dupehammered - at least this avenue is basically fixed), or the important one *to include missing information*. As users become accustomed to the site, their post quality improves. I believe there is a strong relation between usage and quality.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - Also, you don't seem to have a lot of ground to stand on from an asking questions perspective. Your average question posted of a group of [1 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27996738/cant-get-onundo-to-run-available-macro-in-thisworkbook-module) questions is -7.

Comment: @TravisJ: I do not see a connection between "new to SO" and "borderline illiterate". Someone who can follow the most basic of instructions will manage the dialog properly; someone who can't... won't. There's many far more subtle interactions that *are* at least somewhat unique to SO: close reasons, MCVE, the meaning of votes, and so on and so forth. Those are tricky, but "do you actually want to answer or to edit"? Not.

Comment: @TravisJ: That question has been downvoted for reasons I'm not certain of; it may be because there's a root cause (as I eventually duped to) that's fairly simple, or it may be because that's the only post I have that can be downvoted without costing rep, or perhaps some other reason I can't easily determine. It is *not* because I do not understand SO UI. (It's also a terrible example of a question from a new user, since I already had a few dozen upvoted answers by that time.)

Comment: _There are several new review queues which were created specifically to address editing these types of questions_ - while there is one queue for _editing_ those questions, SE ignored tons of feedback about the triage queue (better wording / explanation of "should be improved", easier closing), which makes it rather useless. This in turn causes the HIQ to be useless as well - I just visited it again to see if anything had improved and was presented with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30724233/1110381) as the first post, immediately demotivating me from spending any more time there.

Comment: "*Perhaps not even allowing self posted answers from new users and just showing the edit question dialogue in the space of post an answer*" - this.  I would support that as a feature request.  Don't allow new users (where "new" is defined by rep or account age) to post answers to their own questions.  Possibly allowing self-answers again 24 hours after posting the question.

Comment: @jadarnel27: That used to be a thing, though IIRC the timeout was 8 hours rather than 24.

Comment: @BoltClock I remember that restriction, but I thought it applied to everyone (not just "new" users), and went away when the [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz) feature came out.  Then again, I can't remember what I had for lunch yesterday, so I am likely to be wrong.  I have also never answered my own question, so I don't have any personal experience =)

Answer (score 19):

Maybe we need an easier / faster / more consistent way to push VLQs back on the OP. Something that applies to a subset of all asked questions, but which would encompass the (perceived) source of VLQs - new users.

[image: screenshot]

Say we have a "reject" link available for users, perhaps with some appropriate criteria to restrict use. (rep, tag score?) Further restrict visibility of the link, maybe to review queues, or for display only on low-rep users.

Instead of the 5-close-vote rule, say the VLQ rejection requires just 3 votes.

A rejected question would be put on hold immediately, with the hold reason containing appropriate guidance - mainly to read "How to ask". Fine to use the "unclear what you're asking", IMHO.

### Edit - Further thoughts and musings.

I'm not surprised to see this in comments:

> Don't forget that some users can actually close questions in one click - diamond moderators, and anyone with an appropriate Gold Tag Badge.

True (with the exception noted by Andy, that the assertion applies to Dups only) - I just don't thing they can help so much. Keep in mind that the close queue is huge; 7.8K today. That's a lot of almost-but-not-quite closed questions. In the SO democracy, we require 5 votes to close. Except that some animals are more equal than others - some people have the privilege to be able to close a subset of questions with one vote. I'm proposing that we give a larger group of people somewhat less power than that.

If the Golds were broadly effective at tidying up VLQ Qs, we would have nothing to worry about. Figure there are about 6K new questions a day, and half are VLQ Q. If each of the Golds (4,260 today) closed just 1.5 of those, they'd never end up in the close-queue. Obviously, that's not happening.

Why not? I think that...

- The number of individuals with gold tag badges is significantly smaller than 4,260. I randomly chose one use who earned a gold badge in the past month, and they demonstrate this clearly, with 5 gold tag badges:

  [image: pic]

  Consequently, the number of Gold is probably half of the tags... somewhere around 2,000, just to guess. So that adjusts the previous accounting, so that 3 votes per Gold could eliminate the deficit. Still - not happening.
- The busiest tags have the most Golds. This is a corollary of the previous observation.

  Fact: More than 25% of Golds have been awarded in four tags ([c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript))

  Fully 50% are in just 11 tags (add [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net))

  Those top 11 tags average 212 Golds each, while 78% of tags with Golds have 4 or fewer.
- People tend to Review questions related to the tags they follow, which is most likely a very small subset of the whole set, even factoring in related tags.

  [image: pic]

  I've marked a grouping of the most popular tags... there is very high connectedness in that set. Given the close-to-home behaviour above, this is another factor that limits the broad influence that Golds could have on the whole VLQ problem.

***Conclusion:*** It's unrealistic to rely on Gold Tag Badgeholders to significantly reduce the preponderance of VLQ questions.

Comment: I don't get it: what is the difference between "reject" and "close" here? This suggestion seems to boil down to "make some questions easier to close than others". Adding the jargon "VLQ" doesn't seem all that useful, either.

Comment: Don't forget that some users can actually close questions in one click - diamond moderators, and anyone with an appropriate Gold Tag Badge.

Comment: @IMSoP gold users can only close dupes immediately not VLQ.

Comment: @AndyHayden Ah, OK, I stand corrected on that point. I still don't understand this suggestion though, it seems to be asking for something we already have.

Comment: Actually, @IMSoP, it sounds like you _do_ get it. The difference is precisely to make it easier & faster to close low-quality questions from new users. Suggest a better verb - I'm not married to "reject", but since I'm proposing different rules than for "close", it's got to be different. WRT those who can do one-click closes; see updated answer for full rebuttal.

Comment: @Mogsdad The verb I'd suggest is "close", since there doesn't seem to be any difference in *result* between clicking your "reject" button and "Close -> Unclear What You're Asking". The only difference seems to be the precise *accounting* of that action, in that for some unspecified set of questions, for some unspecified set of users, votes would count double (so that 3 such votes would be needed to reach a "score" of 5). Or do you really think that the *UI* of closing needs to be changed?

Comment: @IMSoP - My thought wrt a specific link was that it would streamline the close procedure, bypassing close reason selection. I do agree with the OP that there are more poor questions that we (the community at large) are able to keep up with. Or do you think that everything is just fine as it is?

Comment: @Mogsdad I'm not sure the need to click twice is a major factor preventing a larger number of Close votes. There is a potential efficiency *cost* to adding more links, because it's harder to quickly select the one you need. It would also de-emphasise other choices, such as finding a dupe or closing with some other reason. This seems to be totally orthogonal to the suggestion of being able to put certain questions On Hold with less than 5 votes, which (as the Gold Badge and Diamond special cases show) could be done perfectly well within the current UI.

Comment: How about this for a more concrete suggestion: if a question is a user's first post on the site, and 3 users with 10k rep agree on the same close reason, the question is immediately placed On Hold, rather than requiring an additional 2 votes. Or perhaps a large negative score could reduce the number of close votes needed, so that score < -10 and 4 down votes = On Hold. Both of these emphasise improvements to the current process, whereas yours would create a parallel nearly-but-not-quite-identical one (What happens if some people click "Close" and others "Reject"? How many votes would that be?)

Comment: Hey @IMSoP, I like that - better to tweak than reinvent. Should work well on high-traffic tags at least. WBN if tag score factored in (thinking of low-traffic tags where even very active answerers take years to get to 10K).

Comment: @Mogsdad Yeah, I think low-traffic tags are something that needs to be looked at in general - perhaps the threshold for a Gold tag Badge should be relative to the total score awarded in that tag (with lower and upper limits)? Then privileges could be granted along with that Badge. Maybe this has been suggested already somewhere...

Comment: My vote up for the cool interactive tag report!

Comment: @Giosco - If only I'd invented it - kudos to Sarath!

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/VCoLbVs.png