# Why do the 'Favourite Tags' and 'Related Tags' section swap around?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

A minor issue that is bugging my productivity is the swapping around of the `Favourite Tags` and `Related Tags` sections.

**First questions page:**
[image]

**And then when I select one of my Favourite Tags: (note the swapping)**

[image]

Is there a reason for this? Because I automatically go to where the Favorite Tags should be but discover Related Tags instead.

Comment: Slightly related to my question about positioning of favourite tags, which I'm guessing you use for navigation too: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251763/move-favourite-tags-above-the-community-bulletin-careers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at two conceptually different pages there even though they look similar.

In the first screenshot, you're looking at a list of all questions on the site. In that scenario, we prioritize your favourite tags.

(Come to think of it, I'm not sure why "Related Tags" is even there on that view. Seems odd. But I digress...)

In the second screenshot, you're looking at question *in a particular tag*, and from there it's more likely that a user would want to go to similar tags rather than switch over to one of their favorites (which may or may not be relevant in any way).

Comment: I'd always prefer my favourite tags consistently at the top right of every page above the community bulletin, as it's my most frequent navigation method