# Show [Watched Tags] and/or [Custom Filters] boxes on Question Pages

Tags: feature-request, questions, design, sidebar, tag-watching

If you're like me, you sometimes come here to check through questions and give back to the community. So I click on one of my Watched Tags on the side bar, say [VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) and I select a question I wish to answer. Now, when I am done with that question, I always wish that the Watched Tags box is shown on the questions page so that I can just click one my tags and go answer/check more questions. As it is, I usually have to go back to the previous tag page AND then refresh (if not, you see a cached version of that page).

It just seems to make sense that when I am logged in and on a Question, my [Watched Tags] or [Custom Filters] should be the first box on the right sidebar, not [Blog Posts], but neither of those is present. If I am on the home page and just browsing through, then the layout of boxes on the right sidebar makes sense. But on a question page, I'll rather have [Watched Tags] or [Custom Filters] than [Blog Posts] or even [Hot Network Posts].

What do you think?

Comment: Agreed, for the same reasons. I'd just like to have the tags available in the view, even if they aren't at the very top...

Comment: FWIW, I keep the Q listing open and right-click on any question I want to answer, choosing "Open in new tab" so that I can always go back to the main list. Which is fine on my main machine, but not on my tablet...

Comment: @CindyMeister instead of clicking right click and choosing "Open in new tab", you can just press the scroll wheel if you have one.

Comment: @B.Letz I don't understand how using the scroll wheel is going to open the questions I'm interested in looking at?

Comment: @CindyMeister, I do the same thing but I feel it's cumbersome. Meanwhile the last comment on [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251825/5166387) seems to indicate that tags should be viewable on all pages.